# Dealing with "ask-and-run" questioners

Tags: discussion

Here's a behavior pattern that I see often:

1. The OP posts a question
2. I come along, say, five minutes later and discover the question. It needs further information or tweaking, so I pose some crucial queries as comments.
3. Nothing. The OP has become unresponsive.

This drives me a little nuts. In my view, questioners should not "ask and run" like this; they should hang around to field comments. My current response is, after a decent interval, to vote to close on the grounds that insufficient information has been provided.

But closure takes many votes and a long time, and meanwhile the question is hanging fire, unresolved, taking up space on the front page of the site, etc. We're at a standstill: no answer is possible until the OP provides some answers, runs some tests, whatever, but the OP is missing in action, so it's a stalemate. Is there a way we can discourage this sort of discourteous "ask-and-run" behavior?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149518/are-hit-and-run-questions-acceptable

Comment: @gnat Exactly apropos, and just the sort of answer I was afraid I'd get. :)

Comment: I've read before that askers should be able to post a question and step away for some coffee. I consider that to be garbage. If we hold that users shouldn't ask a question until they've exhausted other reasonable possibilities, then said users should be at their wits' end when the actual question is posted and should be desperate for help. Staying at your computer for 5-10 minutes isn't too much to ask. If no help is forthcoming after that brief period, by all means, go get your coffee.

Comment: "Askers **should be able to** post a question and step away for some coffee" - yes, yes, 100 000 000 times yes. "Askers **should actually** post a question and step away for some coffee" - no, no, 100 000 000 times no ... and make that 30 minutes. One should aim to **ask a question that's clear enough from the start** such that no clarification is required, but still **stick around to provide clarification** is requested.

Comment: @matt, thanks for asking this!  I wanted to add that sometimes I got the feeling that a comment question or series of comments may prompt the OP to conclude that the question has been misconceived and needs more thought from their side.  Same result as what you have described, but different way of getting there.

Comment: Getting a question fixed after its first version was too poor to answer can happen.  It just doesn't happen that often.  So spend your time wisely, only provide assistance if you see a potential for a good question and you'll think it is worth your effort.

Comment: While the problem can be real, you asked this at a point in time when it was already Friday night in much of the world.  A work related question asked from such a location may see no followup until Monday morning.

Comment: Users new to Stack Overflow may be unlikely to realize just how quickly things move here. Especially if they're accustomed to posting something to a forum and maybe getting an email the following morning that that someone has replied. (this bothers me too, a lot, but I always keep this in mind)

Comment: I think @MichaelBerkowski has hit the nail squarely on the head there, the speed of SO is phenomenal compared to other Q&A sites. Based on my own personal experience, it was a complete surprise to receive a 100% correct answer within ~20 minutes of posting the first time I used the site. If it hadn't been for the fact that SO took my interest and I decided to have a lengthy browse, then I probably wouldn't have signed in again until the following day either.

Comment: My frustration is with people who ask a question and never respond in any way to comments or answers, even after days.  I would be happy to see 'proof of life' even within a day.  I would like such people to be forbidden from asking another question until they do respond to outstanding question(s), so I won't waste my time.

Answer (score 47):

If there's something significant enough wrong for it to need to be closed...

Close it. Close it quickly.

The problem, as I see it, is that everyone just sits around waiting for the question to be fixed (or perhaps just move on without voting, or ... ironically ... ignore the issue because closing takes long). Closing (new questions with fairly popular tags) only takes a long time for this reason.

There really isn't much point in waiting around for OP to fix the issues before voting to close. Closing is far from permanent - we have a reopen system largely to reopen closed questions that have been fixed. Not a lot of questions get reopened, but this is because it's fundamentally off topic (unfixable), the asker doesn't bother fixing it, or the reopen system is broken. For the first two, we should close them ASAP, the latter means we should fix the system ... then close inappropriate questions ASAP.

---

My rule of thumb is to only wait a bit (after posting a comment pointing out the problem) if I expect the user to:

1. Agree that it's a problem
2. Adequately fix the problem.

   Adequately - sometimes users incrementally try to fix a problem. Users that don't express themselves well may require quite a bit of guidance to adequately fix the problem - there isn't much point in having the question remain open while it hasn't been adequately fixed.
3. And do so in the next few minutes.

   This includes problems I think will just take too long to fix - if I expect it's going to take anyone at least around 30 minutes to fix the issue, I'm not going to wait around for 5 minutes for you to fix it.

   And I may decide to vote to close a question simply because I don't think the user will be able to fix the issue in the next few minutes, regardless of how hard they try or how much anyone helps (but they could certainly fix it *eventually*). Again, keep in mind that questions can be reopened.

I may wait a few minutes for a user with > 1k reputation, 200-1k is a bit on the fence, and I'd typically just vote to close practically straight away for someone with < 200 reputation.

I also tend to assume a top-down processing of comments - if you've responded to an unrelated comment B posted after comment A pointing out the problem, it's likely that you've already taken any action you would've in response to comment A. I realize this isn't always true, but it's just based on my experience, and is a simple rule to apply.

* I don't think reputation is the best measure here, but there isn't much else to work with that's as easy to come by.

Comment: My general rule is wait [5 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149518/are-hit-and-run-questions-acceptable#comment430161_149518) after the OP's last contact to start casting close votes. This gives enough time for a response person to "keep their question alive" or proving that the author is unresponsive.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering is: is it worth thinking / suggesting that SO itself might implement a timeout algorithm to help with this?

Comment: Is there a pop-up or other notification that an OP receives if they have accrued close votes?

Comment: @GayotFow If they have more than something like 500 reputation, they can see the close votes on their own question, but I don't think there are notifications. I think notifications (or perhaps even an auto-comment, such that all can see, or changing the close system to be work based on the comments) could be a good idea - it seems redundant to copy text from a close reason.

Comment: @matt Based on what criteria though? Automatically closing a question, for lack of either commenting when no-one's asked anything, or responding to one person's claimed ambiguity (which no-one else agrees with), will likely leave a lot of good questions closed. If a few people need to agree about the ambiguity, why not just close the question?

Comment: @Dukeling, If somebody does not have 500 rep and they cannot see what's happening, they would not know that corrective measures were needed.

Comment: @GayotFow They can see when the question gets closed. I'm not saying they shouldn't be notified, just that essentially copying the close reason into a comment is redundant as soon as the question gets closed, and why should we do this - why doesn't the system just take care keeping the asker up to date regarding the close reasons?

Comment: @Dukeling, it's a good proposal!

Comment: @GayotFow [Auto-comment close votes for all close reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256808)

Comment: I don't even wait five minutes. If the asker starts responding and gets the question cleaned up to the point where it's worth keeping, I'll retract a close vote, but everyone has access to the question standards before they post.

Answer (score 7):

Is 5 minutes that long of a wait? Some people aren't constantly refreshing the page to see if their question was answered or needs work.

Sometimes you have to take a phone call, answer a message, pick someone up, etc, etc. Remember, some users won't even see that their question has close votes (it's at 500 rep as someone [pointed out in an answer's comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256788/dealing-with-ask-and-run-questioners#comment31737_256797)).

I don't feel that 5 minutes without a response to a comment or a modification to the question is considered unresponsive. Give it 15-20 minutes, or even more, then you can start casting close votes.

I also want to point out here that while you can get questions re-opened, by design, it almost does seem like the end when it gets closed. The terminology (though pretty hard to improve), makes it seem like 'the end' of the question.

Also finally, Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange as a whole) poses itself as a Q+A website and the reality is that some people may not be looking to stay, but just to get their question answered.

Answer (score 6):

I have answered a few questions but not yet asked one. While I am pleased to find out that I *might* get a quick answer if I were to, and while I understand the frustration, I am surprised at the expectation that questioners hover on the page for 10-15 minutes. I just reread the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page and I do not see any such suggestion.

Comment: It's interesting to see that the expectation to punctually respond to comments isn't expected by new users - even though you aren't that new yourself. Perhaps the about page should be updated. IME its the rule, not the exception, that a question is lacking some information which the asker must provide. If new users were advised to check for comments after posting - perhaps some would.

Comment: It is mentioned on the [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page... "Respond to feedback after posting" header.

Answer (score -1):

From my activities on other sites on the SE network, I get to expect that it takes up to days to get a comment. There is no point to hang around after submitting the question. And I can sleep well without thinking that I'm putting off the ones trying to help me.

I did notice that on SO it seemed that comments came quickly, but until reading this question that I really get it. I can adapt a new behavior here, but I don't think most other users will know about this.

Answer (score -9):

What if they were involved in a freak car accident because they posted the question from their phone while driving in a car and can no longer elaborate? Keep in mind that not everyone has the exact same schedule and there is no requirement to return.

If it is a good question then answer it and hope that it helps the community and future users. That should be enough for you. If it isn't clear enough, mark it as such with a close vote.

Comment: Question closing is not permanent.  When the OP is well enough to check SO, they can make the changes necessary to have it reopened.  Maybe next time they won't post questions using their phone while driving.

Comment: @cimmanon Actually I do not have seen yet any question that have been open after close, even one "good" that I try to re-open it some time ago. Also the car accident is an extreme example, they can be tired and go to sleep, they can go to eat, the company close and go home, his called from his wife to go for shopping, is anxious and close it to relax. There are too many reasons that any person on this planet make a question and go to do something more important.

Comment: "Sir, you're in the hospital.  You've had a car accident and you've been in a coma for several days.  You have many broken bones, and life-threatening injuries to many internal organs.  Also, there's a bunch of comments on your Stack Overflow question that you need to answer if you don't want it to get closed".