# Auto-comment close votes for all close reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, comments

I propose auto-comments for voting to close for any close reason.

(Read the parts in bold for a longer "TL;DR")

### More details:

- Whenever someone votes to close with a reason someone hasn't already used **when voting to close, an auto-comment is posted with the corresponding reason**, perhaps in the format:

  > This question appears to be off-topic because ...

  As to easily identify them.

  Just to clarify, this would apply to **all** close reasons, except duplicates (that already get a comment). So, "too broad" might be:

  > This question appears to be off-topic because it is too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
- Whenever **someone votes to close using a reason already used, this comment will get upvoted** (as what happens with the current custom reasons, or at least happened at some point).
- **Some optional parts / ideas:**

  - Whenever **someone upvotes one of these comments, a close vote will get cast** if they have sufficient reputation and they've got a vote available.
  - Have **any such comment contain a link to a page containing an explanation of the process** (separate from the comment body, so it can't be edited out).
  - **Prevent deletion of such comments** (and perhaps editing), except through moderator intervention or something (a user shouldn't be able to delete their own auto-comment with 2 clicks).
  - **Anonymize these comments** to prevent possible revenge behaviour. We could give the comment a unique username (e.g. `anon5489689` (auto-incremented / random number) or something) to allow for responding, but that might get complicated.
  - Consider **removing the displayed close reason as it currently is**, as this information will be duplicated in the comments.
  - (As a manual step pre/post-implementation) We **enforce a "take it to Meta" policy regarding disagreement** with the reason itself (not so much whether it's applicable to the question, unless it becomes an extended discussion) (because some often don't want to get into too much detail regarding why something is off topic, perhaps because they don't think they can explain it well / at all - it's off topic because that's just the way it is).

    So someone says:

    > This question appears to be off-topic because it's about foo.

    Then if someone wants to say:

    > But foo is on-topic.

    That belongs on Meta.

    However:

    > I disagree that this is about foo because ...

    Would be an acceptable response, but more than one or two comments needs to go to Meta.

### Why:

To **tell the asker what's wrong with their question** so they can fix it - they will see as soon as the question gets closed, but why do they need to wait that long? And that might even never happen.

One can always comment, but people don't always and it would often essentially involve **copying the close reason into a comment**, which would be **redundant** as soon as the question gets closed, and **why should we** do this - why can't the system just take care it?

**To tell everyone else what's wrong with the post.** This can serve to teach newer (and older) users what's appropriate, and allow for an open debate regarding whether it's appropriate before it's closed (one can always start the debate *after* it's been closed, or if someone with sufficient reputation sees the close vote, but the earlier this discussion happens, if required, the better - more people will see it).

Tangentially applicable reason - I must admit that I myself sometimes use a less-than-ideal (but not totally inappropriate) standard reason because I don't feel like arguing about whether it's on topic or not. Having all reasons get an auto-comment should get me over that (but anonymous comments and/or clearer guidelines for how to handle disagreement would be preferred).

### Possible disadvantage:

A loss of anonymous close voting prior to close. Is that important? One already gets a comment attributed to you when using a custom reason or voting to close as a duplicate.

The anonymous comments should solve this problem.

Comment: If you think one side-effect would be notifications in the inbox, be aware that when someone VTC as dupe and an auto comment is left, there is no notification.

Comment: @KateGregory I might not be 100% following your comment, but if VTC as dupe's comment doesn't currently trigger a notification, I think it should. But, either way, you still see it because of notifications due to other comments on your post.

Comment: Let's do an experiment. I will VTC this as some sort of dupe. I'll retract that vote after you tell me whether you got notified or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions)

Comment: @KateGregory I got 2 notifications, so presumably there was a separate one for the duplicate auto-comment.

Comment: vote now retracted

Comment: I think the suggestion to make information about close votes more available merits discussion, but I'm not sure auto-comments are the way to go - seems it would clutter up the UI unnecessarily.

Comment: This proposal provides the opportunity for the OP to apply corrective measures and convert poor questions into interesting ones.

Comment: I'm honestly unsure what (if any) notifications current <3k rep users get when their Q's receive close votes. If they currently get nothing, that would certainly be a nice thing to change. Wondering if it would be possible to provide such comments in a way that they are visible only to the OP (to reduce clutter for everyone else).

Comment: If not 3k, make flags be integrated too.

Comment: I support this idea because it informs the OP that the question is under consideration for closure (something that is now secret). - Also, I would extend the suggestion: the _front page_ should also reveal that a question is under consideration for closure, so that I waste less time going there (unless I want to).

Comment: @matt It is not currently a secret that a question is under consideration for closure. The privilege of viewing close votes comes at [250 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), a pretty trivial hurdle. The only people missing out on this information are brand new users. Granted, these are the ones most likely to be submitting low-quality questions that don't conform to our guidelines. But these are also the people unlikely to rectify the problems with their question through only a rapid, minor edit, snuck in before the rest of the close votes can be cast.

Comment: @CodyGray A pretty trivial hurdle, yet there are plenty of people not there yet (and should it really be a privilege to see that someone thinks your question isn't appropriate?), and I believe you need to refresh to see the vote (I don't know about everyone else, but I don't make a habit of refreshing), and it's a pretty small indicator with no notification.

Comment: Arguably there is a *reason* the reputation threshold for that privilege was put into place. Probably to prevent retaliation from people who are unfamiliar with how the site works (community moderation, etc.). Subverting this by posting a comment seems like a mistake. Besides, it's an abuse of the purpose of comments.

Comment: @CodyGray What I'm saying is that I want the <250 rep OP to see that the question is in the close queue. The <250 rep OP is _just_ the kind of person that needs to know this. I appreciate that <250 rep cannot see that _other_ questions are in the close queue, but it is _crucial_ to the nature of closure (I'm saying) that the OP should know what's happening to the OP's own question, to give incentive to fix the issues as prompted in the comments.

Comment: I have seen a few comments today with the text of the close-vote message ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32460178/509868)). Was this actually implemented in the system, or do people add them manually?

Comment: @anatolyg I don't believe it has been (unless it happened in the last 20 minutes). People paste close reasons into comments all the time.

Answer (score 17):

I see some merit in this proposal, but it seems like it is solving the wrong problem.

The *real* central problem we should be focusing on is getting low-quality questions closed as rapidly as possible. Not only does this indicate what is wrong with the question in a clear and unambiguous manner, but it also prevents the question from accumulating answers, which is problematic for a great number of reasons.

Once the question is closed, the closure reason already appears in a giant gray box under the question. It is quite hard to miss. It also makes all of the comments about why people voted to close redundant and obsolete.

Everyone seems to have the wrong idea about closing. The attempt to fix this by changing the name to "put on hold" didn't seem to work. You get the impression from reading questions and comments on Meta that people think it is desirable that the asker hurry and fix the question's problems *before* it gets closed. I don't understand why that is important. It is not a race; the closure process is designed as it is for a reason. If and when the problem gets fixed, the question can and will be re-opened.

Moreover, the idyllic basis for this proposal is at odds with reality. Since I vote to close a lot of questions, I can offer plenty of anecdotal evidence on this front. I frequently leave detailed comments, explaining problems *specific* to the question and some *operable* suggestions on how to fix them. These comments go simply ignored (or worse, retaliated against) until the question actually gets closed. As long as people can continue to receive answers to their question, they conclude I'm just some sort of jackass, bent on antagonizing them. They don't bother to fix any of the problems, and they certainly don't get in any hurry to do so.

And yeah, if we did what you're proposing, we'd have to anonymize the comments. Users who are active in moderating the site are already all-too-frequent targets of retribution and the recipients of boatloads of inbox spam as it is. As we currently don't have a mechanism for anonymous comments, implementing this would introduce additional complexity into the system, and all for what gain?

Comment: i'm totally against anonymous comments.... i'm not even sure why we need anonymous close votes... if i want to close a question, i should be ready to do so openly....

Comment: @Swapnil Close votes are not anonymous as soon as a community consensus is reached.

Comment: I think your assumptions are more idyllic than mine. I don't think we'll ever be able to convince the general public to close quickly, and not everything that needs to manages to get closed at all. I agree that comments pointing out problems are often ignored, but they aren't always (and we really want to focus on the users that won't ignore it, not the users that would), and even if they are, it's pretty good evidence that OP just doesn't care (if that's needed).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old request, but I would like to endorse the suggestion at least as far as “belongs on another site” goes.  If it really belongs on another site, presumably the reason why it wasn’t posted there is simply the poster didn’t think of it.  Telling them where it goes would give them the option to self close with the same reason, which would automatically migrate it.  Comment could include that fact, making it clear what the poster should do.

Answer (score -1):

Canned auto-comments clutter commentspace. Are they worth it?

**Duplicates**: Duplicateness isn't immediately obvious; there is no generic sign of duplicateness*. You have to have personally seen the duplicate in order to mark the question as such. A question might be a total duplicate, but not everyone might be aware.

The auto-comment for "close as duplicate" addresses this problem: it points to a specific duplicate, as evidence that this question is indeed a duplicate, thus bringing its duplicateness to the attention of other putative close-voters. The auto-comment clutters commentspace, but the benefits outweigh this cost.

**Others**: This logic does not apply to the other close reasons. If a question is closeworthy for any of those other reasons, then that should be apparent to the reviewers from the question itself. No references needed, and no need to spell it out.

### Conclusion

I don't think it is necessary nor desirable to auto-comment close votes other than close-as-duplicate.

<sup>*<sub>("please help me parse HTML using regex" notwithstanding)</sub></sup>

Comment: Most / all of what I've said under "Why" in my question still holds. "Should be apparent to the reviewers" assumes that this information might only be relevant to the reviewers (as opposed to ... I don't know ... everyone who might ever ask a question, and OP) and all reviewers have an essentially perfect knowledge of when exactly to use each of the reasons (which definitely isn't the case).