# Why can't I vote to close with a different reason after retracting my vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions, retracted-close-votes

I had voted to close a question, but has selected the wrong reason. So I have retracted my vote, and wanted to vote again with the right reason. But it's not possible to vote for a close again.

Is there any reason for this behavior, or a better way to do this?

Comment: And/or [Should we allow voting to change the close vote reason of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262761)

Comment: A possible better way: You can always hop in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask  for assistance, for example if some see fit to close vote for your intended reason. We do have a [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq).