# Is it a dupe if answers address the problem but not the code in question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128796/how-to-convert-my-input-field-number-to-words) as a dupe since it asks about the exact same goal as the dupe target.  However, I was a bit in doubt about this situation because the asker may be interested in resolving *their specific approach* to the problem and I'm not sure the dupe really provides an answer to that.

In other words, if someone is looking for an answer about problems with the code they wrote, should it be considered a dupe of a question about how to solve the same problem?

While the answers in the dupe may be helpful to their situation, they don't actually teach the asker about why their code doesn't work.

Comment: I wish I could understand what downvotes mean in the context of an open ended discussion question.  Is it like... "-1, you shouldn't have vtc".. or "-1, you *should* vtc these"? or maybe, "**no**, you shouldn't discuss this. don't ask this!"?

Comment: Usually downvotes on discussion questions mean "this isn't useful", "I disagree with the premise", "you've re-asked an obvious dupe", "the answer should be obvious", etc.  In this case...well, I'm not sure.  Seems fine to me, as the 3 upvotes appear to reflect.  I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: "*they don't actually teach the asker about why their code doesn't work.*" and is that a bad thing?

Comment: @VLAZ - I guess I'd ask, *Bad for who?* If someone arrives at the question through a Google search looking for solutions to the same problem, I guess the OP's code isn't much of a concern.  But for the OP's benefit I think finding the issue in their code is potentially the most useful. And for that matter, a casual browser of the site may happen upon the question and learn more from a code revision than from the dupe target.  In fact, the dupe target is mostly only good for people seeking copy/paste solutions to a similar problem. I think an argument can be made for the usefulness of both.

Comment: Also, I think it depends what the OP is actually asking. Questions can be (a) I'm trying to do XYZ, how do I do XYZ? or (b) I wrote this code to do XYZ but it doesn't work.  What's wrong with my code? Those are two very different questions but typically they get treated the same. This is where I'm a bit doubtful.

Comment: I'm getting really tired of the millions of debugging questions that are useless to anybody else but OP for nobody else will have the exact same code. "Why doesn't my <non-trivial application> have a problem?" is not a question about the application. That's just a red herring. It's a non-narrowed down other issue. They might have mistyped something, or did a loop wrong, or otherwise the issue code is smaller. It's mostly debugging offloaded to internet strangers for free. It rarely reveals deep insights other than probably 80% of the code being dressing around the problem. I'd say it's useless

Comment: The actual problem of using `!= 0` instead of `!= "0"` looks typo'ish. Closing as dupe probably helps them more than closing as typo.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's also a different question than "why doesn't my application work". It's "why is comparison of string and integer not the same as comparison between string and string". Which is a more useful question. But also one that is a dupe.

Comment: @VLAZ - Ok, I can see your point of view.  It wouldn't necessarily be useless to the OP but for the broader community that's probably true. So to be clear, questions asking "what's wrong with my code which should be doing XYZ", should be closed as dupes of questions asking about to how to do XYZ?

Comment: "*It wouldn't necessarily be useless to the OP*" I don't care about OP. SO shouldn't be the place you dump your code for internet strangers to fix it and you to contribute nothing in the process.

Comment: If anything a question should lead many visitors that have the same issue to (an) answer(s). If the fundamental problem the question  describes is answered by a duplicate then closing the question as such is correct. The quirks the now closed question has, either in wording or use of code, even typos, can help in leading the many visitors to the best canonical duplicate where all knowledge for that specific problem is curated.

Comment: It depends. ;) The OP needs to write a clear focused question, and provide a relevant MRE. Eg, "I'm trying to do XYZ, so I wrote this code C, which should work as follows. But when I run it on this data D I get this output Z, instead of the expected X. What's wrong with C?". Then an answer needs to explain why C doesn't do what they expect, and such an answer may be helpful to future readers. However, if the posted code looks like it was cobbled together by random cargo-culting, explaining it is probably a hopeless task. ;)

Comment: OTOH, many OPs aren't that concerned with why their current code doesn't do what they expect, and will happily toss it when they're shown a way to do XYZ that actually works.

Comment: @VLAZ ""why is comparison of string and integer not the same as comparison between string and string". Which is a more useful question. But also one that is a dupe." I don't suppose you have that link handy?

Comment: It seems people are notoriously bad at asking questions well, and just as bad or worse at recognizing the general underlying issues in their own code. I tend to try to view questions more abstractly where I can and if the problem is the same and resolved by an already existing answer then I VTC as a duplicate. If there's some "grey area" then I'll also leave a comment to the OP what little bit is "grey" between their code and the answer's code. This is all to nudge them in the correct direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### That question definitely should be closed for one reason or another.

There is some precedent ([although I do not really agree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419837/523612)) for the idea that the close reason doesn't really matter. I would rather see a question closed as a duplicate than for some other reason, because that way at least directly gives OP a link to useful information for the task at hand, and not just guidance on asking better questions (which might well be ignored anyway). Also, as long as the title is somewhat representative, duplicates also help search engine users to find the canonical. They also serve as a secondary voting system: the really important questions aren't simply the ones with the highest score, but also the ones that get used the most often to close duplicates.

#### Debugging questions are rarely any good, anyway

We don't *say* that we don't accept them, but we might as well not be accepting them per policy. (Of course, tons of them get through anyway). Consider what needs to be done to avoid the "needs debugging details" closure reason:

> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

The M in MRE (or MCVE, if you prefer) is really important. When someone has really put in the effort to [*check what is going on* in the code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) error messages, only then does it become possible to write a really proper MRE.

When OP does that work and provides the MRE, sometimes the question is very good. However, here is the trick: it is **not a question about debugging any more**. Instead, it's really a "why" question about the behaviour of a specific step in the code:

- ["Why do these nested lists reflect changes made to the others?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/)
- ["Why can't I use a Numpy array (or the result of an operation on them, like `==`) in boolean logic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954)
- ["Why did `print "hi"` stop working in 3.x?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/)

Those aren't the actual titles - hence the quotation marks. They're phrased as what remains of the debugging process *after actually, you know, debugging*. But they're really "why" questions.

#### Asking for debugging help makes the question ambiguous

A huge fraction of questions ask for help debugging the code to implement some common task. This introduces an ambiguity: is the question about the bug? Or is it about the **task**? If both, the question needs more focus; if only one, it needs (details or) clarity (which one?). In many cases (thanks to PM 2Ring for pointing this out) OP *hasn't actually thought about this yet*.

To avoid making the discussion ambiguous as well, I like to reserve the word *task* for the task (what the code is supposed to do), and *problem* for the cause of the failure (the bug; i.e., that which is found by debugging, and would also be fixed by debugging in the cases where OP acknowledges that it was a typo).

So, **your** question here on meta seems to be: should we close as duplicate if we have a canonical for the task, if it seems like OP might be more concerned with the problem? Well... questions that merit closure, should be closed as quickly as possible. The FGITWs are **really** fast, and this site has **way** too many open questions. But there's still that annoying issue about the closure reason and trying to be accurate and helpful....

#### "Okay, but is that really an appropriate duplicate target?"

If the question is a debugging question of the sort I described above, it should normally be deleted, too. The ambiguity means it isn't helpful, and it will usually have a useless or misleading title.

Closing the question as a duplicate doesn't [allow for rapid automatic deletion by the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba); **but** it's [potentially faster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/), which is crucial for avoiding FGITW and also allows for getting to the *manual* deletion process that much faster.

Finally: keep in mind that we **do curate canonicals for common simple syntax and logic errors**. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it). I've [written some myself, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298). While it's tempting to treat these as typos, that's a) slower and b) **often wrong** - since many people who ask will genuinely not understand the problem, even after it is highlighted for them.

After closing a debugging question as a duplicate of a canonical for the task, the duplicates list can be edited to add a canonical for the problem. Or vice-versa. Getting that part wrong initially is not that big of a deal. Better yet, a question that has both kinds of dupe links is a big screaming delete-me red flag, which helps advise later curators. Rather than simply saying "this question needs more focus", it **directly shows why** the question is lacking in focus.

Comment: I'm on the fence about the dupe closure. Essentially the way people can learn to use Stack Overflow properly is through self-education. They need to read the rules, scour meta and keep their eyes wide open at all times to interpret the signals the site sends at them. If we close these kind of things as a dupe, that essentially sends out the signal that it's alright to ask low quality questions. We'll guide you to answers anyway. That's self-sabotage which we then endorse, in my opinion.

Comment: @Gimby it's a no-win situation. Either the question is closed, or it's not and then it attracts answers which are usually much worse than the canonical. Or if they aren't, they aren't *worse*, they repeat information. And the worse case scenario is that they provide new and useful information which means that the good answers for the common problem are scattered all around and hard to find.