# The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated

Tags: discussion, questions, announcement, ask-question-wizard

**Update:** This feature launched on 2022-10-25.

---

**TL:DR:** Back in March, we [announced an experiment of the Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/ask-wizard-for-new-users-feature-test-is-complete), and in June we [shared the results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418491/ask-wizard-test-results-and-next-steps). Later this month, we are graduating the experiment and releasing the Ask Wizard on Stack Overflow. It will be required for users with no previous questions asked on the site (questions on other network sites are not counted) and have an opt-in for more experienced askers.

For details on the Ask Wizard experience, please see these two previous posts: [#1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416322/feature-test-ask-wizard-for-new-users-trial-has-completed) and [#2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/ask-wizard-for-new-users-feature-test-is-complete). At a high level, the Ask Wizard walks the user through each step of asking a question one-by-one, provides specific guidance for each step, moves the Similar Posts widget to take Tags into account, and breaks the body into two sections: (1) What are the details of your problem? and (2) What did you try and what were you expecting?

### Changes since the results announcement

The only change we are making to the Ask Wizard itself is adding the option for experienced askers to opt in to using it. We also made improvements to the Stacks Editor in preparation for this launch, which you can read more about [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode-is-now-available).

For users with at least one previous well-received question asked on the site, or three previous questions asked, there will be a toggle above the Title section allowing the user to toggle between the Ask Wizard and the existing Ask experience. By default, users will see the existing experience, but the user’s choice is preserved for future questions. If you toggle between the two experiences after writing content, that content will be migrated between the experiences. Title and tags content will be migrated to the same section. For the body, which is either one or two sections depending on the experience, all content will be preserved in the first body section on the page. If you toggle Ask Wizard > existing experience > Ask Wizard, all the content is preserved except for where the body broke to the second section.

[image: The Ask Wizard toggle shown above the Title field and toggled off]

### FAQ

#### Why are first-time askers not allowed to opt out of the Ask Wizard?

Since we saw positive results in the experiment with first-time askers when the Ask Wizard was required, we believe this is an improved experience for first-time askers in aggregate. We also think there is generally value in having first-time askers learn how to write good questions. Based on the earlier test, we are confident that this will be a net benefit to new users, and thus are only going to offer the toggle once users have some experience asking questions on the site.

#### How can I see if a question was created using the Ask Wizard?

Questions created using the Ask Wizard will include a "created from wizard" notation in the Comment column of the Timeline for the post.

#### Will this be offered on other sites in the future?

The experience was built with Stack Overflow in mind. We don’t have any near-term plans to expand the Ask Wizard to other sites, though we do hope to adapt the Ask Wizard for other sites in the future. At that time, we will try to determine what adaptations and customizations will be needed to allow the instructions to be relevant across different sites on the network.

#### Is this related to the Staging Ground?

Not explicitly. While the goals of both features is to improve the first-time asker experience and the quality of first questions, the Ask Wizard is not dependent on the Staging Ground. However, once the Staging Ground launches the Ask Wizard will be a gateway to it. All Staging Ground questions will go through the Ask Wizard first, though not all Ask Wizard questions will go through the Staging Ground.

---

This feature has launched on Stack Overflow. For two weeks following launch (up to and including November 7, 2022) please report any Ask Wizard issues as answers in this post.

Comment: "Since we saw positive results in the experiment with first-time askers when the Ask Wizard was required..." It wasn't clear to me from what data was presented at the time that this was statistically a confident conclusion. Are you relying on any other data such as user feedback or reviewer feedback? (I think that is positive if you are, but am wondering...)

Comment: We are going to try to avoid responding to questions being posed in comments on this post, as it leads to discussions that are very hard to follow. So if you are asking a question in a comment and aren't getting an answer, this may be the reason why.

Comment: I'm seeing instances of [Punctuation characters being escaped in code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416802/punctuation-characters-being-escaped-in-code) now.

Comment: I would opt for more stringent requirements for making the wizard required until the new user Rep reaches 50 -- **on questions asked**. Meaning until the user receives 5 upvotes on questions asked, the wizard is required. Far too many low-quality questions come from 2nd and 3rd questions on the site. (By the way -- nice job...)

Comment: this user just repeated their bad question to get past both forms in the wizard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410235/using-the-while-construct-develop-asequence-ofinstructions-that-add-the-byte-si

Comment: @chiliNUT - that looks a lot like an account created for the sole purpose of making a point. The username is "vampire" and they've posted a help vampire question - could that be a coincidence?

Comment: @david-c-rankin Do you truly believe that this thing called "wizard," is a nice job? I see loads of poor questions and wished there was a means to have askers do a better job.  This so called wizard will not help a bit with this issue. If anything, it may only make it worse, as comments suggest.

Comment: I have to ask because this has been driving me nuts... is the question author shown a preview before they post the question? I see so many questions every day where the code is a garbled mess because it's not markdown-formatted or in the case of HTML, completely invisible. If there is a preview, I think it might not be prominent enough

Comment: @Phil if the author is working in markdown mode and does not have preview on, then they won't see a preview

Answer (score 52):

Why is the title first again? The 2018 wizard improved on that situation by putting it after choosing tags, but we're back to first again. Titles should not be written first. Authors choose their title after they know what their body of work encompasses, and having to spend effort explaining your question helps you discover a more accurate, descriptive way to entitle said question.

Comment: Related: *[Should the "title" field be at the bottom when asking a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215548/should-the-title-field-be-at-the-bottom-when-asking-a-question)*. But it can't be the only one.

Comment: The [2018 wizard announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-2018-is-live).

Answer (score 37):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that this feature is graduated (and thus, releasing which questions are created with the wizard no longer has a chance of muddling experiment results, as a staff member noted in my original request), [**can we *please* add enough information to SEDE for public users to analyze how effective this is?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378070/1079354)

[I've previously expressed concern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381794/1079354) about adding the Ask Wizard with no way to tell if it's helping or not.  Without any ability to see the data, [we remain unable to form an informed opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418529/1079354), and I'd like to see that change by releasing these metrics.

Comment: I thought I could make use of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/931244), but apparently, the PostHistory records on SEDE don't include the "created from wizard" comment.

Comment: Hasn't this been analysed over and over during several years? The post you linked to is from 2018. Lots of features have been released live upon SO with little to no research and testing in advances, but that surely can't be the case here. I've lost count about the number of announcements, beta tests and meta discussions (also including the mentorship experiment). Also, this is a feature that many veteran SO users have been asking for during a very long time... how often do you see a new feature release on SO with a positive score of 683(!!!)?

Comment: eh, this same thing was released years ago and then replaced shortly after without much fanfare. I think people are just excited to see anything that might have some improvement on the deluge of bad questions; unfortunately this isn't it.

Comment: @Lundin:  Yes, *they* have analyzed it, but all they have said is "positive improvement", when I have actively seen the kind of crap that still gets posted to Java and Python questions.  So I want to dive into the numbers myself and see if there really is an improvement, and if there isn't, I want to have a constructive, data-backed discussion about *where* I see the gap.  Can't do any of that if I don't have numbers, so I just get to look like a grumpy old man who's shouting at kids on my front lawn. :/

Comment: @Makoto thanks for your request. We are now planning to include `PostHistoryTypeId 66 = CreatedFromWizard` in SEDE data and site exports moving forward. The data will be retroactive to the beginning of the test earlier this year (but will not include data from the 2018 wizard).

Comment: The data has now been in the public SEDE data for a couple of weeks. Looking forward to seeing your analysis @Makoto.

Comment: @YaakovEllis:  I look forward to digging into this.  Thanks!

Comment: @Makoto were you able to draw any conclusions with this data?

Comment: @cody:  I haven't pulled data yet.  A lot of crap has happened between then and now.

Comment: @Makoto Is it ok if I quote you on this in the future as a reason why I missed on delivering some things promised on meta? Hope all is well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis:  I'd prefer not?  I mean, there's a difference between a passing interest in performing data analysis versus product delivery and customer relations, I'd say...and while any news could be construed as good news, the last time that could've been leveraged in good faith was probably mid-2018.

Comment: @Makoto was trying to make a joke. I'll see myself out.

Comment: @YaakovEllis:  I recognize that but it'd have landed better if you hadn't told it to the guy who'd been left waiting in the past for staff to follow up on stuff - not you specifically, just SE staff - for *years*.  Joke's only funny if there's something left to laugh about.

Answer (score 33):

Can the wizard be improved to prevent questions that contain repeated sentences like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74202522/1)?

[image: screenshot of a post from the wizard that has three copies of the same exact sentence]

Personally, that seems like a pretty important thing for a new-asker wizard to check for.

Comment: Assuming this can be detected in a sensitive and specific way, why should whether the question is in or out of the wizard have any effect on whether it is bumped back for a rewrite?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ideally it would be caught outside the wizard as well, but I found this on a wizard-generated post and a wizard that targets a subset of users is a better place to debut such new code than the general editor that most users will see, arguably.

Comment: same goes for questions with a bit of text followed by code/error in an image

Comment: It's 2022 - detecting easy patterns like this is a walk in the park for todays AI's. We've got plenty of training data; no need to handcraft logic to detect this or other patterns common in low-voted questions.

Comment: It doesn't need complicated AI systems, it's a simple string check. The wizard has two textarea inputs for "What are the details of your problem?" and "What did you try and what were you expecting?". They are required to fill the textarea with text. When the question is generated these two inputs are concatenated into the question by the wizard. But when the OP don't know any difference to write (or my guess it they are just lazy), they simply copy&paste one content into the other. The wizard should check at some point in the process if these two textarea inputs are the same.

Comment: That's 2022 for you. "Just use an AI, problem solved". That's how we get to feel smug about ourselves, such a brilliant idea. Now the programmers just need to bend over backwards and spend months re-educating themselves to make this a "walk in the park".

Answer (score 30):

I have > 100K rep but I've never asked a question. If I ever do get around to asking one, would I be forced to use the Ask Wizard to do so?

I suggest there should be some privilege that makes it optional, maybe [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) or [access review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), but certainly [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) at 20k should be more than enough.

[Access review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) maybe makes the most sense - because if you trust me to review a question, you trust me to write one, no?

Alternatively, although more complicated and presumably overkill, access to review queues together with review badges to show I've experience reviewing questions.

Comment: As of now, the only criteria is having asked at least 3 questions, or at least one positive question, so you would get it. Sorry bout that. In the test from half a year ago, exactly 1 user out of 35K who got the ask wizard met this description, so we didn't special-case it due to the low occurrence. If it comes up more often, we can look into a trusted user exception.

Comment: "*I have > 100K rep but I've never asked a question. If I ever do get around to asking one, would I be forced to use the Ask Wizard to do so?*" I sincerely hope so. 'never asked a question before' is a far stronger signal here than 'has lots of rep'

Comment: @TylerH I've also reviewed lots of questions. I have gold badges in most review queues. You're happy for me to review questions as to whether they are any good but not write one without extra help?

Comment: @RobertLongson In short, yes. Remember that this is the _ask_ question wizard, not the _review_ question wizard. You state you have _asked_ no questions, so why should I expect other activities to teach you how to _ask_ a question? It's easier, in many ways, to review existing content than it is to generate new good content in the first place. Though reviewing questions is a point in your favor; perhaps if that had been your argument rather than 'I have lots of rep' I may have responded differently.

Comment: OK, sure but that seems much more complicated to demand review badges. I've added it as an alternative. They already said that asking questions on other sites wouldn't count and I guess that includes this Meta so rep and badges are all that's left.

Comment: A strong counterpoint to the suggestion for a trusted user exception is that some very high rep users, including diamond moderators, regularly 'misuse' the site by answering common/nth duplicate questions instead of voting to close them. The ask question wizard should not be that much of a burden to someone who knows how to ask a good question, and they only have to deal with it once. I'd rather it be put in folks' face at least that one time so they are forced to see, first-hand, how to do this interaction properly.

Comment: @RobertLongson "so rep and badges are all that's left" Well, and the obvious candidate: _asking actual questions_... which is the point of the whole thing: show users how to ask good questions until they have _proven_ they know how to do it. You should not get a pass because you know how to answer or review, because those are different knowledge/skill sets. And there's lots of noise on Meta already, including by CMs, to try and move away from rep-gating things toward more sensible/contextual gates.

Comment: Knowledge from practical personal experience is different from knowledge from watching someone else's experience. Even if you have a sea of knowledge about swimming, gathered over decades, but if you've never done it once successfully, I would still recommend you have some help, when you do it first time.

Comment: _There's a difference between knowing the path and walking the path._ -- Morpheus (to Neo), The Matrix.

Comment: I dunno, Robert Longson, sure, 114k Rep is good and all, but how can we be sure you won't suddenly go and ask a question like "How I mine 4 fish???" or something like that? ;)

Answer (score 19):

Learning the asking skill is hard, and providing a guiding tool sounds like a good idea. I appreciate that developing such a tool is tricky. What I do not appreciate, however, is the title "Introducing the Ask Wizard: Your guide to crafting high-quality questions."

I just tried the wizard, and all it does is it places a few light barriers, which are more like inconveniences. It splits the single "body" field from the standard form into two sections and prevents the user from working on individual parts in random order.

Perhaps the most straightforward part of the question is adding the tags, and I do not see any reason not to do it first. With tags defined, the wizard could provide additional specialized guidance. I cannot imagine a universal and, at the same time, profoundly helpful guide. At the very least, when the user enters SO tags, the wizard can display links to specialized guides and high-quality question samples specific to the specified tags (rather than providing a few lines of wisdom, which may not be particularly helpful for an inexperienced user). And this information should be presented at the beginning so that those who want to improve their questions have resources readily available before they start working on their question.

The title should generally be done **last** when the body of the question is ready.

The wizard will probably improve over time, and it would be unreasonable to expect something stellar from the initial release. My problem is with the title formula. The SO, I guess, strives to be a learning resource, a source of objective knowledge, not a sales place, where marketing puff is normal, and all the seller cares about is sales, not the truth/objectivity. Well, either that or the SO standard for "crafting high-quality questions" is quite low, which I doubt. I apologize for being harsh and forthright, but, IMHO, the current ask wizard has absolutely nothing to do with "crafting high-quality questions." This thing has nothing to do with a "wizard" either. And it should not be sold as either.

Comment: Yeah that salesspeak is really annoying & really wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the current people making decisions in the company believe that quality requirements are discriminatory.

Comment: Hm... discriminatory with respect to what? Do they want SO to turn into trash? Do they pay people to answer bad question? Providing more than references to guidelines or, perhaps, good questions, when the OP obviously did not bother to invest efforts in the question, is IMHO a bad practice.

Comment: @philipxy Just like most of their communications -- plenty of hot air, and SNR approaching zero. It's sad.

Comment: I used to do spectroscopy, so I know what SNR stands for:)

Comment: From my experience as a curator, questions asked via the Wizard have been **notably worse** than usual. It seems like new users resent the barriers and seek to work around them.

Answer (score 17):

I have seen several questions were the user *blatantly ignored* the Ask Wizard guidance. The questions I'm referring to were posted on October 25 and 26 and the question history show "created from wizard".

One of the OPs posted a question here in Meta ->  [Reopen closed questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421115/1595451).

- Is the Ask Wizard really used on all questions labeled as "created from wizard"?
- Is it possible for the Ask Wizard team to automatically identify these questions<sup>1</sup> ?
- Are these questions<sup>1</sup> being considered a "layer 8 problem" (user error)?

Notes:

1: author blatantly ignored the Ask Wizard guidance

---

Meta questions about recent posts were apparently something is wrong with Ask Wizard (are the [quality-filter](/questions/tagged/quality-filter) and [warning-message](/questions/tagged/warning-message) still in place? is there something on the end-user side besides ignoring the Ask Wizard guidance causing this?)

- [How was a new user under 10 reputation able to post an inline image?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421079/1595451)
- [Multiple issues when adding images in new Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421177/1595451)

Answer (score 13):

Not all questions are debugging questions that benefit from an attempt or code sample... yet the new wizard doesn't let you get past that section without putting in a minimum amount of text.

Comment: Even if you are asking a non-debugging question, I would personally like to see some whiff of programming effort.  I think this is a healthy step in the right direction.  The more programmatical effort the asker writes into the body, the narrower the question potentially becomes.  Narrow questions are far easier to close as duplicates and, let's face it, a very high percentage of all new questions are duplicates (have been "Resolved Elsewhere").

Comment: Forcing some amount of code, an attempt, very well can make a question not a duplicate when it otherwise may have been... due to it becoming a debugging question. It transitions from "How do i foo the bar" to "What's wrong with my attempt to foo the bar"... when what is likely to be the most useful is an experts demonstration of how to foo the bar ;)

Comment: I reject the idea that only "debugging questions" need the support of code. Even if you're just asking about concepts (which are narrow enough in scope) then the question will almost always be far easier to understand and reason about when they display some sort of attempt at a solution.

Comment: I don't think that a code sample is always necessary, but I think it's reasonable to expect _everyone_ to write a minimum amount about how they tried to answer their own question. For _every single question_ that is on-topic for SO, it would be valid to say "I spent 3 minutes googling but found no relevant results" -- and if that isn't true, that means they _need to_ spend 3 minutes googling.

Comment: @KevinB - FWIW, [I recently asked about just that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420953/is-it-a-dupe-if-answers-address-the-problem-but-not-the-code-in-question) and was more or less told that *"What's wrong with my attempt to foo the bar"* questions should still be closed as dupes of *"How do i foo the bar""*.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue That may be true for some subset of them, but it's certainly not something that applies to all questions.

Comment: @KevinB - I agree with you but that sentiment wasn't really expressed by anyone on my question. The overwhelming response is that both should be treated the same - closed as dupes.  I would encourage you to comment or add an answer if you disagree.  It could be helpful to have another perspective there...

Comment: I disagree with the way that question was handled (and voted accordingly at the time,) but don't see any reason to do anything about it today

Comment: The wizard **should start** by trying to *identify the kind of question*. Debugging questions work notably differently from conceptual questions.

Answer (score 8):

Even though [my answer on the feature test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416327/6045800) about images was the top-voted one, we still get stuff like:

[image]

I simulated the process of asking a question (with a dummy 1-rep user, just in case), and indeed the only mention about images was this *easily avoidable* warning:

[image]

The only thing that will really help is something which is not *"easily avoidable"*. Like a pop-up. To quote myself from the linked answer:

> I think that at least a more visible pop-up with a warning should be activated when new users try to add images. I mean, one that you actually have to ***actively dismiss*** in order to continue.

It is marked as [status-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-review) in the original answer, but in that case I really think it should get higher priority for review considering 8 months had passed and we still get this kind of questions.

---

Another recent example:
[image]

And yet another fantastic example:
[image]

Comment: We are [now blocking new users from being able to post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421462/51) using the Ask Wizard, the same as on the old editor.

Comment: @YaakovEllis That's nice, but why only block inline images that way? The above imaged question is also useless (even more so) with a markdown link. My proposal is to add a pop-up asking the user if the image is of code and if so to turn it into text instead. This way, new users will still be able to add images for valid cases, but if it's an image of code we will know the user was made aware it is not appropriate and chose to ignore it

Comment: @Tomerikoo what if they manually type markdown link syntax and link to an image?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I guess it is not so hard to detect and have the same pop-up if they were just adding an image? And anyway in such case we would just have to close that question. The majority of cases will still be filtered (at least the second example above is done through the editor and not a manual link judging by the "enter image description")

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I don't think there's currently any built-in functionality (with or without the Ask Wizard) to prevent image-uploading entirely - even without the Ask Wizard, the site setting that controls this sort of thing only disables the inline embedding of uploaded images by a new user.

Comment: @V2Blast So the same code that's preventing inline images couldn't raise a pop-up to the screen? Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I'm not asking to prevent images completely (that was already established in my answer to the feature test). I just the previous and current image onboarding is not enough. By having a clear pop-up that needs to be actively dismissed we know that whoever posted images of code simply doesn't care. They were warned sufficiently. I hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 7):

I was slightly confused when I saw the post and went to a non-SO site's Help Center and found /help/stackexchange (and /help/askwizard) articles that describe a feature that's not live on the site yet.

Given:

> The experience was built with Stack Overflow in mind. We don’t have any near-term plans to expand the Ask Wizard to other sites, though we do hope to adapt the Ask Wizard for other sites in the future.

Could we please remove the Help Center articles until the feature is rolled out to those sites?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It should be SO only now.

Answer (score 6):

If after selecting tags you decide to scroll up and check your work before clicking next and actually make changes elsewhere, you lose the ability to move forward and there's no indication that you need to re-focus the tags input to make the go next button reappear.

(It should probably just not go away on blur, or not be hidden to begin with)

Comment: Probably it should appear or disappear based on matching a proper number of existing tags.

Answer (score 4):

Is still in place the question ban warning? If so, what is the current ban warning text for question ban warning?

---

From [Adam Lear's  answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/289691) to [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179087/289691)

> As of May 26<sup>th</sup> 2014, we are showing a warning to folks who are about to post a question or an answer when they already have a track record of ... suboptimal
>
> #### questions:
>
> > [image: question warning]

---

I just went to [What is the Ask Wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard).

I think that many users have earned the privilege of getting an early warning (I would like to calle it *an emphatic invitation to take the guidance seriously* but that might not be *nice*), preferily using an alternative way presenting the Ask Wizard guidance because the first time that it was presented didn't work.

Regarding the above liked article using traditonal text based style, please add the big blue box included on top of the Ask Wizard. It could have a description / caption like "It's so important for us that we put the following advice in a big blue box"

[image: Writing a good question blue box]

---

> ### Writing a good question
>
> You’re ready to ask a programming-related question and this form will help guide you through the process.
>
> Looking to ask a non-programming question? See the topics here to find a relevant site.
>
> **Steps**
>
> - Summarize your problem in a one-line title.
> - Describe your problem in more detail.
> - Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen.
> - Add “tags” which help surface your question to members of the community.
> - Review your question and post it to the site.

Comment: Should we also be encouraging the inclusion of "List related Stack Overflow pages that did not resolve your question." ?  This would go a long way to reducing the total number of duplicates asked.  And it would help the Linked list (in the side panel; or bottom on mobile) grow with helpful links and push out the useless Related list

Answer (score 2):

Can that robot and those balloons be removed now? As an experienced user (1K+ questions) I had requested that a couple of years ago when it came out.

Comment: Clown and balloons? Also, did you really start typing this request, go look, find it was already handled, add the last line, and then post the answer? Or did you add the last line during the edit grace period? If the former I'm not sure why you even posted it. If the latter, I'm not sure why you didn't just delete it when you found it was already handled.

Comment: @TylerH   Clown and ballons were there for a couple of _years_  and that was the case at least as of _yesterday_ . I want to recognize/appreciate that this was added - _possibly as a result of my comment_ !

Comment: I think that you are talking about the robot and the conversation bubbles (see the first screenshot at [Feature Test: Ask Wizard for New Users (trial has completed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416322/1595451)) . You were tricked by the responsive design... they are still there in large windows, they disappear on smaeller windows.

Comment: @ruben ah I see. I updated the "answer" to `robot` since yea that's what it is.  They take up real estate on the page.

Comment: i mean... they're not gonna put anything useful there, so it's not taking up space that otherwise would have been useful.

Comment: @KevinB  If it's *not* there that leaves more visible space for creating/editing the question.

Comment: it... doesn't though. It's on a line of the page that is already being used for a layout header that isn't going to go away with the robot + chat bubbles. That's like saying making a div green instead of blue will allow it to fit more content.

Comment: The header was narrower before those bubbles etc were added. I'm saying, let's revert/get rid of them.  I ask many questions and clearly remember the loss of real estate, that's not imagined.

Answer (score -3):

How come it doesn't even try and get an idea of the operating system being used, or available, or acceptable?

Or the language being used, or available, or acceptable?

Surely the asker of a programming question must know these things.

How about asking if a debugger has been used?

Comment: I think the tags are used to describe the things you mentioned.

Comment: IMX in the Python tag, the operating system, exact Python version, etc. etc. are **usually not** relevant in cases where OP volunteered the information. There was a period where it was at least important to distinguish 2.x from 3.x in a fair fraction of questions; but nowadays 2.x is the rare exception.