# Could we ask about Ask Wizard / Staging Ground studies details?

Tags: support, staging-ground, ask-question-wizard

[The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/1595451) mentions that the Ask Wizard is shown to people based on how many questions they have posted, so the reputation/privileges aren't considered in any way. Several comments to that question were pruned, very likely for the usual reasons. That's ok.

There are some stuff that I would like to know about the studies being conducted that I was not able to find, I have posted a comment on some questions/answers but they might be posted too late or were not clear, so I think that the best is to post a question, like

- Is the Ask Wizard / Staging Ground team classifying new users some way? , i.e. experienced coder vs completely new to coding
- Does the study include how long it takes a user whose first question was closed to post a well received question? Or how many users come back after their first question was closed?

Is it OK to ask this kind of stuff at this time? Have that already included in the [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground) posts so the best to reread all of them?