# Reopen closed questions?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

Recently, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153534/installing-mac-os-monterey-on-virtual-box-it-reboot-and-message-show-karnal-pa), which is very similar to an issue I'm working on.

Unfortunately, the information in that post wasn't enough to resolve my issue. My reputation isn't high enough to add comments and ask for further information, so I started a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211269/system-panic-while-upgrading-virtualbox-vm-from-osx-12-to-osx-13).  As you can see, my post was closed rather quickly.

The comments suggest that my post isn't appropriate for the site, but that doesn't make sense based on the post I originally found (which is less than a year old).  Is it possible to get questions reopened in these situations?

Comment: eh, i'm having a hard time seeing where either question is programming related. I mean, is installing an IDE programming related? Is creating the OS environment the IDE requires programming related? Maybe if either were being done programatically,

Comment: Installing or configuring a host to run a VM is not a unique programming problem. That is more of a general computing issue and those type of questions are off-topic on SO, as explained in the [help]. Those questions might be on-topic elsewhere.

Comment: You might try [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) instead.

Comment: @KevinB users must configure certain VirtualBox settings programmatically - the "other settings" mentioned in my post are actually commands executed in a command prompt

Comment: does, the configuration and execution being done via a terminal make it programming? I mean, that's what a program would do if it were being done programmatically, but the two aren't necessarily the same,

Comment: @KevinB "Program: a series of coded software instructions to control the operation of a computer or other machine."  The problem appears to be that a VM is no longer coded properly after running updates, and the solution might be to run additional programs (albeit simple ones) to fix said coding.  Sounds like a programming problem to me ;)

Comment: Is clicking a series of buttons on a GUI programming? such as installing chrome and linking it to your google account? Would doing it by instead pasting commands into a terminal make it programming?

Comment: Thanks @rene - I now see #6 in the on-topic page.

Comment: @KevinB the fact that the GUI programming wasn't done by the end user doesn't mean that misbehaving GUI clicks aren't a programming problem.  At the very least, the fact that the end user can (potentially) resolve the problem by running basic programs makes the solution programmatic.  That's what I was asking for in my post - a programmatic solution.

Comment: So, if a seat belt fails, even though it's not code, or a program, it can be "programming related" because code was used to evaluate/design/produce it?

Comment: @KevinB it depends on the nature of the failure, and how loosely you define "related".  In the actual issue at hand, we're talking about software with faulty programming/coding, and I was asking if there was a programmatic solution to it.

Comment: The Help Center [says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"...if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers...then you’re in the right place to ask your question"*

Comment: You shouldn't completely change questions after they've been answered, like you've just done here. It's not fair to Rubén, who took the time and effort to answer the question that you originally asked. You should revert your edit and post it instead as a separate question, though I can tell you now that yes, moderators *can* migrate questions to other sites, though it's not always used. It depends on whether the target site is willing to accept the question, and/or whether the moderator believes it's good enough to warrant it.

Comment: I rolled back the question to the previous revision, not only because in this case the last changes invalidate my answer, but also because there are others participating on this question. As was mentioned by F1Krazy, and because you have rep > 5, if you have a follow-up question the appropriate way to proceed is to post a new question

Comment: I tried to leave enough of the original content to keep the current comments and answers relevant, but I guess I changed too much - thanks for rolling it back.

Comment: and yes @gnat, that thread does address the alternative question I had.  I wonder why it didn't turn up in my searches of things like "move question"?

Answer (score 5):

Well received old questions doesn't warrant that a "similar" new question will be well received too. Some possible reasons

- The site scope have changed over the time,

  - In this case the old question was posted in February. Aparently there isn't a scope change during this year.
- Moderation is done by volunteers without a specific assignation. This means that the reviewers of new questions very likely were not the same of the old ones. Also it's worthy to note there are no records of the judments made by the reviewers, there is no formal training to designate reviewers, it's privilege earned by participating in the site. Considering this, there is no warrant that both groups of reviewers aplied the same criteria.

Regarding the referred pair of quetions:

- Old question

  - It is now closed. See [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/1595451)
- New question

  - The original opening statement looks to be very unfortunate to me. Instead of droping data describe the problem; the best is to make it clear from the very first line that the question is about an unique programming problem.
    By the way, it looks that you used the Ask Wizard. Have you read the guidance provided on it?

Comment: (the old question in this case isn't old enough for that to apply)

Comment: The old question also wasn't well received and currently closed. Of course I suspect that is because the community now knows about it and acted accordingly.

Comment: @SecurityHound correct, it was closed yesterday.  Interestingly, despite several downvotes (which may have also been recent - I didn't notice them yesterday), it received 2 useful answers.

Comment: @mathlete - It received answers that were upvoted.  One was more of a two sentence comment about VirtualBox.  The other appears to be based on [this](https://github.com/myspaghetti/macos-virtualbox/issues/484), if that is the case, it wasn't properly cited.

Comment: @SecurityHound that command is referenced on multiple sites, so not sure if the lack of citation is an issue.  For instance, [this thread from Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435574/monterey-vm-reboot-loop-and-kernel-panic-in-virtualbox-6-1-32-on-apple-host-har) mentions the same fix in almost the exact same manner.  In fact, both solutions are referenced - the two threads are practically duplicates.

Comment: @mathlete - There are other elements that make it believe that answer isn't 100% written by the author.