# How can I view previous Stack Overflow initiatives?

Tags: support, meta, stack-exchange

I recently came across this post: [The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421038/the-ask-wizard-2022-has-graduated?cb=1), and it reminded me of all the other initiatives that Stack Overflow has been testing out.

The problem is that I have no idea how to view their status. I remember there was a UI refresh initiative that I would be very interested in.

So is there a standard way to view these initiatives that I am unaware of? The Overflow Blog seems to be the best place for items that have graduated, but it also seems to have a lot of "noise" that requires a lot of searching.

Comment: No ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/announcement?tab=Newest, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcement?tab=Newest,

Comment: You could, however, have a browse through the [[meta-tag:announcement]]s.

Comment: Oh, the tags! For some reason I didn't think the would link all together that way, but it's probably the method with the least noise

Answer (score 11):

Checkout

[announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements)

Also you could take a look in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags. More specifically look for "red" tags and at the tag excerpts. Here are some that I think that could be include information about initiatives:

current
[collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives), [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery), [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads),[staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground),[featured](/questions/tagged/featured),[content-discovery](/questions/tagged/content-discovery),

old
[new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav),
[welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming),
[dark-mode](/questions/tagged/dark-mode),
[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility),
[tag-tips](/questions/tagged/tag-tips),
[open-source-advertising](/questions/tagged/open-source-advertising),
[navigation-arrows](/questions/tagged/navigation-arrows),
[trends](/questions/tagged/trends),
[reactions](/questions/tagged/reactions),
[events](/questions/tagged/events),
[mentoring](/questions/tagged/mentoring),
[ux-research-time](/questions/tagged/ux-research-time),

phased-out / discontinued

[documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation),
[developer-story](/questions/tagged/developer-story),
[old-teams](/questions/tagged/old-teams),
[10m-questions-milestone](/questions/tagged/10m-questions-milestone)

related
[a-b-testing](/questions/tagged/a-b-testing)

P.S. The emerging tag excerpt on inline tags looks to not be working at this time on normal mode, but on editing mode it's working.