# Where is the "Answer your own question" button?

Tags: support, asking-questions, instant-self-answer, ask-question-wizard

I just found the solution to a problem that had me bugging out for weeks and had me scraping the entire Stack Overflow website. I thought it would be useful to share it with other people, so I went and tried to write a question and check the "Answer your own question" button, but it is simply nowhere to be found on the page. Why is that? I definitely have more than 15 reputation and I've never been banned.

[image: screenshot of the 'ask a question' page without the button in question]

Comment: Just for the record the button is [still present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw27R.png) when not using the question ask wizard.

Comment: It appears that the question ask wizard does not support immediate self-answering. A comment from staff: "[We intentionally decided not to include self-answers as a feature of the wizard.](/posts/comments/901030)"

Comment: @HenryEcker interesting, and how exactly do I get to that page?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can. IIRC, the wizard is obligatory for users up to a certain rep threshold that I do not remember. However, [it's painfully obvious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrcLN.png) where the switch is so if you're not seeing it there, the simple answer is that you can't. Instead, you'll have to post the answer separately after you post the question.

Comment: @Zoe Unless the rules mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/8967612) have changed at some point, I don't think it's based on rep: _"For users with at least one previous well-received question asked on the site, or three previous questions asked, there will be a toggle above the Title section allowing the user to toggle between the Ask Wizard and the existing Ask experience."_