# Unable to answer own question in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, self-answer, ask-question-wizard

In site like Mathematics Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, I am able to find the checkbox

[image]

But the option is missing in Stack Overflow

[image]

I do have more than 15 reputation, which is required for answering your own question

[image]

Edit:

I can't find an option to disable the Ask-Wizard. Perhaps I need a certain amount of reputation for that?

[image]

Previous mentions of this: [Where is the "Answer your own question" button?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421437/14139068)

Comment: Don't use the Ask Wizard! You can toggle this off at the top of the Ask Question page.

Comment: You don't  get that option if you use the wizard. You don't need it though. Write the answer in your favourite text editor, post the question, and click the answer button after posting

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike I can't find an option to disable the Ask-Wizard (screenshot attached to question). Perhaps I need a certain amount of reputation for that?

Comment: @AndhavarapuBalu I think so, but I don't remember how much. You can still answer manually by posting the question first and using the answer box afterwards as a workaround

Comment: I've marked this as by design. The [self-answer feature was intentionally disabled](/posts/comments/901030) for the ask wizard. [Not being able to opt out from the wizard the "first" time](/q/421038/15497888) is also by design. If you'd like, you could put together a [meta-tag:feature-request] with some justification for why this should be changed. However, please take a look through the posts here on MSO first to ensure it hasn't already been proposed

Answer (score 7):

1. OP is using Ask-Wizard, and the wizard does not allow you to answer your question
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/901030
2. 1. Even without the Ask-Wizard, you need a minimum of 15 reputation to answer your own question at the time of posting the question
   2. The Ask-Wizard is sometimes not allowed to be turned off. The Help Center says that using the wizard is only compulsory for your first question, but that wasn't the case for me (the OP)

[https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20a%20first,you%20when%20asking%20a%20question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20a%20first,you%20when%20asking%20a%20question).

3. You can still answer your question after posting it ( <strike>if you have more than 15 reputation</strike> )
   (you can answer any question, including your own questions after posting, irrespective of your reputation)
   [https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time).

Request to update Help Center article on this topic: [Update Help Center: Answering your own question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429439/update-help-center-answering-your-own-question)

I (the OP) still consider this behaviour a bug though. It was a resultant behaviour of two choices by design. But it's not like it was specifically targeted to make answering your own question unavailable to new comers. Particularly because the help center explicitly mentions that users over 15 rep should be able to answer their own questions while posting the question itself. This behaviour was changed without an explicit discussion on this (as far as I know), when implementing the Ask-Wizard

Comment: The "Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question at any time." doesn't have a reputation requirement. You can have any reputation and still answer your own question after posting it. The 15 reputation is only required to display self-answer checkbox on the non-question-ask-wizard version of the ask page. You're not (nor is any user) prevented from answering their own question (assuming it's not closed) as evidenced by this self-answer. The only thing that was removed was being able to automatically post your question and answer in the same moment.

Comment: I do agree with you the help centre document is out of date given the question ask wizard's addition. However, that page appears to be a network-wide document and as far as I am aware Stack Overflow is the only site with the ask wizard. I'm unsure what options are available for making changes to just SO.

Comment: @HenryEcker Although the topics covered on the Stock Overflow Help Center benefit the entirety of the network, the Help Center seems to not extend its scope beyond Stack Overflow. If you look at the [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), it only mentions itself as a Help Center for Stack Overflow. Further, it explicitly promoted Meta Stack Overflow with no mention of Meta Stack Exchange or even the existence of other sites on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @HenryEcker (I think discussions regarding the Help Center update should be on [my other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429439/update-help-center-answering-your-own-question) instead )