# Update Help Center: Answering your own question

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Help Center article: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time).

It says:

> If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the check
> box that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask
> Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and
> answer together.
>
> Alternatively, you may go back and add an answer to your own question
> at any time.

But:

1. answering your own question with the checkbox is not possible with the Ask-Wizard
2. the option to disable the Ask-Wizard is not always provided, even when users have more than 15 rep mentioned in the help page
3. users have the option available to them on other Stack Exchange sites, it causes a confusion onto why it isn't available on Stack Overflow alone
4. trying to Google this only results in you being an overwhelming amount of people saying "Yes, answering your own question is encouraged, you can use the checkbox for it!"

Reference: [Unable to answer own question in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429426/unable-to-answer-own-question-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Just don't think it will help many people after the documentation is changed ;) To be helped by documentation, you first need to want to read it.

Comment: @Gimby Well, I did. Even if not from its index page, I read it via Google. And it cost me more time because it said the feature was supposed to be there, yet it wasn't, so I had to research further and eventually write 3 meta questions because of this