# Stack Overflow "tutorial" shows up every time I ask a question

Tags: bug, new-users, ask-question-wizard

Consider:

[image: "Tutorial"]

I've already asked numerous questions on the site, but Stack Overflow still assumes that this is my first question.

Comment: You've been a member for only 45 days and have less than 100 reputation points. How is the site wrong? It can take literal months to become somewhat familiar with how NOT to use the site, depending on how willing you are to study documentation, the faq and popular meta posts.

Comment: @Gimby listen I'm sorry I'm new to SO and SO Meta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At this time, you only have three visible questions, and none of them have a positive score yet. It's very likely that you will continue seeing the tutorial until you achieve a certain positive score.

Related

- [The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/1595451)