# Should there be a Stack Overflow/Wikipedia comparision in the tutorial?

Tags: discussion, new-users, tour-page

Basically, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a library of questions and answers where authors ask questions other people may have too in the future, and other users answer these questions. So its purpose is not to help those who ask the questions, but to help those who may have these questions later.

In my opinion, this is similar to Wikipedia, where authors create pages and write content that might be useful to other people who seek knowledge about these topics in the future.

Concerning this similarity, wouldn't it make sense to notify new users about this already in the tutorial? Many people sign up to ask dozens of questions not useful to anyone because they need the answer to their individual problems. In my opinion they should be already warned in the tutorial about it, like this:

> Before asking questions, be aware that Stack Overflow is not a help site for individual questions. It's a library comparable to a Q&A version of Wikipedia, where authors write content other people might need in the future. Please do not ask questions for which no one but you will ever need the answer. These questions will be deleted very quickly.

I know the tutorial says something like:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow, a site where we collect questions and answers to create a large library for people!

(I don't remember the exact text, I signed up more than a year ago), but many people obviously don't understand the true meaning of this text. Otherwise, there wouldn't be so many off-topic or not helpful questions asked by new contributors. And who would ever read all the Stack Overflow info pages when they just sign up to get the answers to some questions? I think that adding the Wikipedia comparision to the tutorial would prevent many bad questions.

Comment: Fun fact: [**there used to be one**](//i.stack.imgur.com/ghvr8.png), a pseudo-Venn diagram showing the relationship between Stack Overflow and other services with which users are generally more familiar, such as wikis, blogs, forums, and Digg/Reddit. Stack Overflow was that asterisk right in the center of all those. And, yeah, your Wikipedia comparison is totally apt. I use exactly that same analogy all the time: SO is like Wikipedia, except that instead of long-form articles, we break the content up into bite-sized questions asking about specific tasks. BTW, here's the link to it: [tour].

Comment: To be clear, by "the tutorial" you mean [tour]? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Perhaps. As already stated, it has been more than a year since I signed up, so I don't remember anymore if there has been an interactive beginner's tutorial like "click on this symbol to show the most recent messages to your questions and answers \ next"; "click on this symbol to show your achievements and reputation changes \ next" and so on. If not, it's probably the tour.

Comment: I don't think there's been an interactive tutorial on Stack Overflow/Exchange though. There's a quick introduction to the site with [tour], and [an old interstitial page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) when asking a question, and Ask Question Wizard in [2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/2821954), which was replaced with Ask Wizard in [2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/2821954), which then might be replaced with [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/2821954) sooner or later (currently on testing)...

Comment: It doesn't seem like the SG is supposed to replace the ask wizard in any way.

Comment: Huh. Stack Overflow should have a tutorial and by that I mean something specifically named a "tutorial". The lingo on this site just doesn't fit with modern devs. "the tour", who would click on that. I don't want a tour, I want to go straight to the cookie jar.

Comment: @dan1st You could make a drinking game out of SO using unrelated features as an excuse to get rid of other features. It's not far-fetched that the Wizard is removed again in favour of the SG, even though they aim to achieve two different goals (the wizard is supposed to improve question quality and reduce the amount of manual labour, the SG is meant to improve _public_ question quality and allow for a mentor-like manual improvement system; management at SO could probably see "both improve question quality", and yeet the wizard, in spite of it having other goals that suddenly become uncovered)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine the current wizard offers effectively no benefit while actively introducing entire new failure modes for question quality, though.

Comment: (SG = [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info). *[yeet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yeet#Verb)*: *"2. To throw an object a long distance or with a sudden or forceful motion."*)