# For asking if a general case is correct, what should "What did you try" fill?

Tags: discussion

For example, I want to ask if something is correct, like this question:

[Floating-point number multiplication: a * 1.0 == a guaranteed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941182/floating-point-number-multiplication-a-1-0-a-guaranteed)

What I actually want to ask:

For float point numbers a,b and c, if a/b exactly equals to c in decimal, and a, b, c are all representable with float numbers without rounding errors, eg:7/2==3.5, would there be any case that cause a/b not equal to c in float point calculations (eg:7/2 becomes 3.49999999 incorrectly...)?

what should I fill in the "What did you try"?

Comment: Nothing.  You don't have to say what you tried.

Comment: @Dharman While that agrees with policy for what questions should look like, currently new users are (to my understanding) subjected to the Ask Wizard, which has a separate box prompting for that information with a 20 character minimum (which it will then blindly concatenate with the *actual* question entry box).

Comment: "if a/b exactly equals to c in decimal, and a, b, c are all representable with float numbers without rounding errors" - there are quite few cases that this actually describes.

Comment: @karl Are you sure it's mandatory? That seems like a terrible design.

Comment: Well, what *did* you try? Did you try running a program that iterated over a large quantity of numbers and validate the result is not rounded incorrectly? Do you need help producing such a program? That would be a question I would ask...

Comment: @Dharman see *"Why are first-time askers not allowed to opt out of the Ask Wizard?"* in [The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/208273).

Answer (score 3):

What you tried for general cases could include tests for *specific* cases that hold for the inquired general case. Using [Floating-point number multiplication: a * 1.0 == a guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58941182/16217248) as an example, what one might try while [attempting to answer the question themselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/16217248) could be attempting to multiply many different numbers of many different magnitudes with `1.0` and testing if they are the same, and doing so on specific implementation(s). Doing so will either:

- Result in a case where the general case/guarantee fails, thus answering the question. (i.e. *No*)
- All attempted tests *appear* to follow a general case, thus warranting asking the question to get an answer.