# What should I do when the duplicate target depends on additional context?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77140658/10352740) and (as I said in my comment) it could be either a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69433546/10352740) (if the `Socket` in the question is a reference type) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690866/10352740) (if the `Socket` in the question is a value type).

After my comment, I'd flag the question but that's where my problem comes, what's the good course of action? Flagging as Needs improvement then flagging as a duplicate and picking the duplicate target based on the context added? Or flagging as duplicate already but risking a coinflip for the duplicate target?

Comment: Given that Socket is a [default class of .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-7.0), you could also check the docs if it's a reference or value type.

Comment: If I was to take the "coinflip", I'd probably rely on that to choose the target but so far nothing tells me it's not a type the OP created or a type from something else than .Net like a NuGet package

Comment: In general, curation must be done with certainty. If you're not certain, do what you did. Go to meta :) Or a chat room if there is one with a matching subject, that'll probably have a faster return. Asking or doing nothing at all are better choices than guessing and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cynically: it depends how much power Stack Overflow has afforded you and how willing you are to deal with the consequences of your actions.

### With community influence

See if you can convince the community of other "regulars" to find or prepare a more general duplicate that sidesteps the problem. Does it really make sense that questions about nullable value types and nullable reference types need to be answered separately? Yes, there are different consequences, at a technical level, to how the nulling is implemented. But if the question is being asked *about the syntax*, then the answer is clearly the same either way: it indicates that the type is nullable, which has the same *semantic* meaning. The information about both arguably should be in the same place, along with any necessary details about how it's implemented for value vs reference types.

### With [Mjollnir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/)

Strictly by the book: leave a comment with the two duplicate links you have in mind, something like "This is either a duplicate of {link to X} or {link to Y}, depending on {Z}". Vote to close the question as unclear; more information is needed in order to understand it properly.

More practically: **do not** vote to close the question as unclear because [**you will permanently lose**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419837) your dupe-hammer privileges for that question.

Pragmatically and cynically: Close the question as a duplicate of one, ASAP, before the [FGITW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302)s can get in. (Although they effectively get a head-start built into the system, due to the editing grace period, so it may be in vain.) Then, click the Edit link at the top-right of the closure dialog, and add the link to the other question. Finally, write a comment to explain to OP how to choose which duplicate link to visit.

**However**, if the system has granted you this privilege, you are also supposed to have a certain amount of subject matter expertise. Feel free to use it, if it helps.

**Before asking for context, consider what's most likely**. While OP should have clarified which socket definition is being used, questions like this are often asked by people who lack the general cluefulness to explain that clearly, or perhaps even to realize that `Socket` in the code could potentially mean anything different from what they think it means.

Apply Occam's Razor: if there is a massively popular third-party library that uses the type names and has documentation that proposes variable names that match the question, proceed as if the OP had explicitly said the type comes from that library. (For example, a Python question with code that says `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` should usually have the `[pandas]` tag added, and an answer chosen as if OP had explicitly mentioned using Pandas, even if that didn't happen.)

Otherwise, if there's a standard library option that otherwise meet that description, assume that's what's in use. If the language has a well-known naming convention that could imply the missing information, assume that this convention has been used.

In the current case, `Socket` is overwhelmingly likely to mean [`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket), because it's rare that anything else should be called a "socket". And that's a reference type.

### With 3000 reputation

If you can already see a system comment proposing one of the questions (or an equivalent) as a duplicate link, propose the other one. Otherwise, choose and propose one of the duplicates according to your best guess, or vote to close as unclear. In the latter case, leave a comment to explain which duplicates you think might apply - this helps others who are reviewing the question, and also directly offers the possible duplicate links to the OP who can consider those answers immediately.

### With 50 reputation

Please feel free to leave a comment as long as you're able to. I don't think you'll be able to raise both flags, unless the first one gets declined in the interim. It doesn't really matter which flagging approach you take if there isn't a clear preference; everything will come to the attention of people who have access to the review queues, and a good fraction of them will have 3000+ reputation and will be able to exercise their discretion in close votes.

### With 15 reputation

Don't feel bad about not being able to comment. As long as you flag questions that should be closed (and make no mistake: the question you describe **should be closed no matter what the additional context is**), with a flag that can reasonably be justified, you are doing your part.

Answer (score 10):

Well, the right action might be leaving another comment to ask the OP for clarification.
I don't see any harm been done there so far.

Also another c# gold badge user could decide to edit the duplicate list, and add that other link.

Comment: I didn't know that gold badge users could add that other link, it'd probably be the best outcome here I guess