# More vote-to-close autocomments

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-close

If I vote to close a question as a duplicate, an auto comment is placed on the question along the lines of

> Possible duplicate of {question link}

This is a great feature!

1. It immediately gives the question author some feedback that there may already be an answer to their question
2. It saves multiple people commenting along those lines
3. It hints that the question *may* not be worth answering at this time, until it is confirmed or denied that this is an actual duplicate

If I vote to close a question as "Off topic > Questions seeking debugging help [snip] should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).", the question asker does not see this useful information and link until more people have voted. This gets frustrating - I wish the user could see the link to a MCVE earlier, I'm fairly sure it would help more people get an answer to their question quicker.

---

I propose that the first time somebody votes to close with this reason

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

It should immediately generate a comment with a shorter version of the above reason:

> This question is missing a [Minimal, Complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may get a quicker answer if you update your question with this information

(Or something more succinct, but along those lines.)

Comment: Cool idea.  But are you fine with implicitly raising the reputation requirement to 50 (for comments) instead of just 15 to flag?

Comment: I wasnt aware it would have any side effect? How is this different from "VtC>Duplicate"?

Comment: It's the same.  Flagging for duplicate closure currently requires 50 reputation (because of the auto-comment).  The others only require 15 rep because they don't (currently) leave any comment.

Comment: I mean I'm not sure how much closure flagging 15-49 rep users do, but it's just a consideration we have to make.

Comment: In that case i'd be in favour of the same treatment for this. Low rep users probably dont get the need for MCVE any more than they would get the need for dupe flagging /opinion

Comment: dup? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256808/auto-comment-close-votes-for-all-close-reasons

Comment: @CRABOLO - yep, pretty much. Although I dont agree with the need to anonymize, and I don't agree its necessary for *every* close reason.  This one specific case has a great deal of benefit, in my opinion. There are a few others - but, at least in the tags I frequent, this one makes most sense.

Comment: Totally support this. Here is an almost identical request I made on MSE: [All close votes should add an auto-generated comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214931/all-close-votes-should-add-an-auto-generated-comment) (shameless self-plug)

Comment: I don't know how I feel about this.  It seems convenient in some cases, but sometimes I just don't want to get involved, just vote to close and move on.  Now I'd have to remember to refresh the page and delete the autocomment.

Comment: I probably leave a comment along the lines of "Please [edit] to include a [mcve]." more often than I don't, but I'd still like to be in control of that comment.

Comment: @davidism I think you're on to something! Personalized auto-comments for close votes! /s

Comment: @Trobbins not sure what you're trying to say.  I didn't say I wanted personalized comments, I said I wasn't sure if I wanted auto comments.

Comment: @davidism so how do you feel about the autocomment for dupes? Do you go back and delete these?

Comment: @davidism The "/s" indicates sarcasm :) I was implying we have a block in our profile for each close vote-auto-comment, either leave blank or add a string to be auto-comment with. Ludicrous at best.

Comment: I thought that poster of question with close votes already getting some UI feedback like "you post is about to be closed due ..." - can't verify, but I seem to remember people complaining about such UI when there are only 1-3 votes...

Comment: @Jamiec Sometimes I do, or I'll edit it to say "exact duplicate", etc.  I think that comment serves the purpose of allowing the op to decide if it is a dupe, and also linking related questions even if they don't turn out to be duplicates.

Comment: For dupe flags/votes this is easy to deal with because it will only leave an auto-comment if there isn't an existing comment that contains a link to the dupe target. For most of the other close reasons this won't work, resulting in possible duplicate comments due to the close vote adding an additional comment when one is already there on the issue. It's easy to deal with multiple auto-comments because those can be tested for via exact match, but anything else would be missed.

Comment: Note that users must [earn the privilege to see close votes on their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).  So, to be consistent, we'd only leave these autocomments for users with at least 250 rep.  (Personally I think all users should be able to see close votes, but that's been debated several times.)

Comment: No, I think we should show the comments to *everyone* - 1-rep users especially fail to post MVCEs. Restricting it to 250+ would make it useless.

Comment: Dupe closures are a little different to other closures, though, so it's natural that they get slightly different handling. Being closed as a dupe doesn't mean the question itself is _necessarily_ bad (although I admit that it does often mean that the OP didn't make an adequate search before asking). Dupe questions act as alternative portals to the dupe target, which can be handy. It's the _answers_ to dupe questions that are the problem, since they get scattered all over the place, which is why dupes should be closed (with an _appropriate_ target) ASAP.

Comment: It's easy enough to add a manual MCVE comment, since `[mcve]` is a magic link. FWIW, sometimes when I vtc, I copy & paste a line or two from the relevant paragraph in the `Closing>Off-Topic` dialog box, hoping it'll nudge the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @Jamiec Are you familiar with [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and [cv-pls](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js)?

Comment: Another great thing: it accumulates upvotes from people who think like you, while up to 4 votes to close may be thrown away if the close vote times out.

Comment: This is a great feature request. Every time I vote to close or flag, I need to type _yet another_ canned response of mine to alert the asker. Especially for those new to SO, I think these automated messages are helpful. I think @Jamiec first example is a bit long, while the second is great.  Maybe to expand on that, comments that are autogenerated should include comment votes towards the vote-to-close count.

Answer (score -7):

**No, I don't think so.**

I've seen a few people posting these copy/pastaen of closure reasons as comments, and I consider it noise. If enough people agree with the commenter's opinion of off-topicness, the question will be put on hold and *the reason will be automatically displayed*.

I see no reason to spam the same text in the comments, especially *before* such consensus is reached.

---

> 1. It immediately gives the question author some feedback that there may already be an answer to their question

They get that the very *moment* consensus is reached. The OP can wait another two bloody minutes, surely? Why is everyone in such a rush nowadays, gees.

> 2. It saves multiple people commenting along those lines

Not really; nobody should be doing it.

> 3. It hints that the question may not be worth answering at this time, until it is confirmed or denied that this is an actual duplicate

That's silly. If you, as a potential answerer, believe that the question is on-topic, *answer it*. If you don't, *don't*. If you're making decisions on whether to answer based solely on what some other person thinks, then you're just a sheep and frankly shouldn't be making any decisions at all.

Comment: Wait...what? You've commented on 3 bullet points that were not part of this proposal. Those three points were me opinionating on why I think the *existing* functionality is a good thing. They're opinion at most. The bit below all that is where I proposed a similar thing for *another* close reason

Comment: @Jamiec: I realise that. It's an addendum. Feel free to ignore everything underneath the horizontal separator if you can't mentally distinguish the points. :)

Comment: So... you flag the `Possible duplicate of..` comments as `To Chatty` (aka 'Noise')?

Comment: @cybermonkey: No. (a) Moderators have much more important things to do. (b) Here we are talking about _adding loads more such messages_, not removing the trickle that are already there, notwithstanding your attempt at a slippery slope argument. (c) I would probably support a proposal to remove the feature that generates them, though.

Comment: Well, if someone's already flagged a question, then another message doesn't need to be generated. I support this proposal, but also agree that without modification it will clutter up the chat.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Comments are explicitly _not_ a "chat". Anyway I honestly don't see why anyone would support this. I don't get it. There is already a big closure banner. Why do we need _the same text again_, in a _manual_ form, _not controlled by the state of the post_ (they'll still be there after reopening!) and _displayed before consensus_? It's obviously nonsense, from where I'm sitting.

Comment: This is for *voting* (before it's closed). Users without the CV privilege such as myself cannot see close votes on questions (that are not my own), thus such a feature would be helpful to correctly judge the question. Of cause (as with the `Duplicate of..` comment), the comments will be automatically purged if the question is closed.

Comment: @cybermonkey: "Judge" it how? Judge that other people have voted to close it? What does that achieve? If you do not have the CV privilege then I see absolutely no reason why you should see that some people are voting to close until a consensus has been reached and the question is actually closed, at which point the banner goes up. It really sounds like you are trying to "judge" a question based on whether some other random people have cast a so-far-uncorroborated vote on it, which I find to be extraordinarily dangerous behaviour. Why can't you make up your own mind?

Comment: Actually it sounds like you're trying to "workaround" your lack of CV privileges so that you can see vote counts (where at present you can't), but you're suggesting a messy, hacky, texty, noisy workaround be implemented in order to accomplish that. Not good :(

Comment: It wouldn't be that noisy IMHO.

Comment: More noisy than no comments at all, and _serving absolutely no good purpose whatsoever_. To me, this is an example of a self-evidently bad idea, but apparently I'm in the minority there, which I simply cannot understand. I've addressed and debunked all the "arguments" put forth so far in its favour, but still the downvotes come roaring in. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I actually do find them to be noise as well. They really irritate me.

Comment: Interesting voting score on this question +16/-21

Comment: I agree that this adds noise which need not be there until the question is actually closed. Quite often, proposed duplicates are not actually duplicates at all, as the person who dropped the comment either didn't read the question, or didn't read the duplicate. Meaning the comment is not just noise, it is also incorrect. I am all for removing "possible duplicate" comments until the post is actually closed.