# Capitalize "possible duplicate of <x>" properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, duplicate-questions, design

So, there's this *serious* issue on SO.
Frankly, this could risk the integrity of SO's servers:

The *"possible duplicate of <x>"* automated message lacks any and all capitalization.

Can some strings be pulled to change the first *"p"* to *"P"*?

At least then I can safely continue with my everyday business, no longer afraid of unintentionally posting sub-par, uncapitalized sentences...

---

On a more serious note:

The problem is that the messages are posted as if the user marking the post as duplicate wrote the message. This implies that that user doesn't care about capitalization.

As [@ryanyuyu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu) pointed out, other automated flag comments *are* capitalized.
The fact that the duplicate message isn't, is an inconsistency.

The same feature request has been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) back in [2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl), but since that's quite a while ago, and a lot of the close-voting has been changed since then, the "issue" should be reviewed.

The [reason it's been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47209/203057) back then is:

> *"It's not a complete sentence, so it doesn't need to be capitalized. We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example.. or, heck, even here on the question page itself."*

In my opinion, this reasoning is outdated, and since the message is posted as if it's been submitted by the user, it should be held at the highest standards of quality, or just be removed altogether.

<sub>(I probably made some typos in this post though)</sub>

Comment: I agree.  It's terribly inconsistent with other autocomments.  Like the VLQ deletion comments.

Comment: Wow, this is a serious security risk. I can't believe they've let it persist for so long! +1

Comment: Oh look, a downvote :D I'm curious why. In the unlikely case the downvoter sees this, care to comment?

Comment: I don't think anyone's claiming that it's "unacceptable", just that it would be better with a leading capital letter, as would every other comment on the site. We have quite enough "i haz problem can u fix 4 me plz sir" already.

Comment: I know they don't have to comment, @davidism. I was just trying to convince people to explain downvotes. On meta, downvotes usually mean: "I disagree". I'd love to see why some disagree. Heck, they could have very convincing reasons for it.

Comment: @davidism: Doesn't change the fact that I don't see why it doesn't need to start with a capital letter. Improving part of the message is better than not improving anything at all.

Comment: @davidism: _"Style choice"_:That's your _opinion_. In my opinion, it's inconsistent and incorrect. We're not going to agree on this, so I see no point discussing this further.

Comment: @MrLister: That other question has now been closed as a duplicate of this one. Would you consider retracting the close vote?

Comment: _"when your side is opinion based as well."_ I agree: _"In my opinion, it's <...>" [*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307037/capitalize-possible-duplicate-of-x-properly#comment252994_307037)_

Comment: @Cerbrus I can't do anything about the other close votes though.

Comment: Oh, might as well get it over with, closed, and re-opened -.- Seriously though, CV-ing a [meta-tag:status-completed] bugreport as _"Can't be reproduced"_? _\*Facedesk\*_

Comment: But .... I want to be in the top close vote reviewers on meta as well.... I have to close all the things...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will be fixed as of build 3735 (on MSE/MSO) and build 2858 (on other sites).

Comment: You might just have saved lives with this fix ;-)

Comment: It still doesn't add a full stop at the end of the comment; that seemed more work than was worthwhile. ;-)

Comment: That may be a good thing, if the link in the comment ends with punctuation.

Comment: Out of interest, does this mean MSE/MSO specifically are branched from the rest of the codebase?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The MSE/MSO build is called "meta", and the other sites build is called "prod". Occasionally, we test stuff on the "meta" build first, so the build number is higher. But they both build off of the master branch (manually; we have another build that builds automatically off of master for internal testing; _that_ one is on build 17072 ;-)).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: could you please change the [tag:status-declined] tag on the [Meta.SE feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl)?

Comment: @Cerbrus Done. (Also, this has now been deployed.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: How do you guys decide those build numbers, 3735 in this case?  o_O

Comment: @BhargavRao Build numbers are sequential. I just look at what the currently deployed build number is and add 1.

Comment: So *rev 2015.9.30.3735* implies *3735th revision since the start of SO which took place on 30/9/15*?

Comment: @BhargavRao 3735th time we hit "Run" for the given build since we switched to using TeamCity for our build server.

Comment: Ah, that's explains it. Sounds good, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your arguments.

However, that the capitalisation style reflects (in this case, poorly) on the alleged/false author of the comment, I consider this further evidence that the message should be outright removed.

> I don't think these comments should be generated anyway. It's semantically the wrong system to use to present that information. That you can arbitrarily write, edit and delete such comments is just one example of that. ([src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306989/is-it-intended-that-i-can-delete-my-comment-that-resulted-from-a-duplicate-vote#comment252318_306989))
>
> I consider it noise. If enough people agree with the commenter's opinion of off-topicness, the question will be put on hold and *the reason will be automatically displayed*. I see no reason to spam the same text in the comments, especially *before* such consensus is reached. ([src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306867/560648))

Take them away and the whole problem disappears.

Comment: That works, too!

Comment: I find this autocomment to be very useful.  It sometimes helps me avoid spending lots of time answering a question when I don't realize that it's a duplicate.  Other times, it saves me the effort of hunting down the duplicate myself.  I would imagine that making this change would significantly reduce the number of identified duplicates (this is obviously testable).

Comment: @Joel: If you have the CV privilege, _you can already do all of those things_ with a proper, semantically-appropriate system. The "close" link has a number after it when a question is on its way to being closed, and if a question has already been suggested as a dupe, that's the first one that shows up when you go to cast your own dupe vote. And if you don't have the CV privilege, well then you don't have the CV privilege so frankly all of this should be irrelevant.

Comment: I have no idea where you got the idea that this change would reduce the number of identified duplicates: once the vote (and comment) is there, a vote has already been cast. The wheels are already spinning. Removing the comment doesn't change that.

Comment: If I see a comment suggesting something is a duplicate, I'll check.  If I agree I'll also vote to close.  Removing the comment will change that.

Comment: @Joel: (a) As I pointed out before, the question will say _"close (1)"_ if that's the case. So you will still be informed, and you can still quickly "check". Removing the comment doesn't change that. (b) You should check anyway, whether someone beat you to it or not. So the comment is leading you into a bad behaviour. Removing it will promote improved behaviour. Thank you for adding to my argument ;)

Comment: How exactly is it leading me to a bad behavior?  I hope you aren't suggesting that I check each question I glance at to see if it's a duplicate before moving on.  If I'm going to answer it, sure, then I'll check regardless.

Comment: @Joel: Perhaps not _every_ question, but certainly those you plan to answer and maybe some others that ring a bell. Yes, that is the responsibility of having the CV privilege. It seems you're just waiting for someone else to do that work first, then spotting the comment and going "oh ok let me jump into that too". That's fine ... and as I've said, you can still do it, using the _"close (1)"_ indicator as your trigger, rather than this auto-comment.

Comment: @Joel: By your logic, you are not checking close-votes if there's no comment about it. even if the close link has a number next to it. I wonder what you'd do if the close comment is drowned out in other comments, then...

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't know that it's my "logic" here...  But indeed - it's only a week ago or so that I noticed that the close link sometimes has a number next to it.      Regardless --- in the tags I follow if I were to vote to close as a duplicate and move on, it could take days before enough votes show up to actually get it closed.  In the meantime the asker doesn't have an answer to the question.  So I'd still have to put it in as a comment.

Comment: @Joel: In my opinion, the asker not getting an answer isn't that much of a problem, if it's a duplicate. At least not enough of a problem that we absolutely _must_ have those comments. You're free to comment yourself, of course.

Comment: @Joel: The OP is informed with a big banner at the top of the page (as viewed only by them) as soon as you cast that first duplicate close vote. The comment is _literally_ redundant in that scenario.

Comment: Ah - having never seen that myself, I was unaware.

Comment: @Joel: It's well-hidden :P

Comment: Gosh, you really *are* against these comments arn't you!

Comment: @Jamiec: I am firm and consistent in my convictions!