# Why do some flags generate automatic comments and some don't?

Tags: discussion

I'm pretty new to SO but I really like it and enjoy contributing to it by answering questions when I can, or by flagging questions that do not meet the requirements and are not helpful to anyone.

However, I've noticed that flagging the question as duplicate of another also automatically comments on that question, but flagging it as "too broad" does not do that. I think it would be very beneficial for people to know what their questions are being flagged on, even if no action is taken, so they can better adjust themselves and their questions next time.

So my question is, is this logic due to some reason I haven't thought of? Or is this an oversight that should be addressed?

Comment: Cross-site dupe of a question I asked on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214931/all-close-votes-should-add-an-auto-generated-comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The flags that generate a comment are precisely those where the flagger (or close voter) inputs some text of their own: a link to potential duplicate, or a custom close reason. This user-added information may be important for others to have, so it's made public.

In particular, it may save time to users who would otherwise try to answer the question. (Those under 3K reputation don't see close votes on questions.) It is also an implicit invitation for those with 3K to consider the proposed duplicate and maybe vote along (or refute it with a comment).

Finally, the OP is getting a notification about the comment (which they don't about the close votes themselves). The post itself will show the OP a  [prominent dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981) about the duplicate, but without the comment they wouldn't know to go look there.

Comment: I could understand the logic behind what you're saying, but I would expect maybe an optional check mark to *also* post a comment, if I choose to

Comment: @OferSadan When would we ever want people to *not* post the comment when proposing a duplicate?  How is that ever going to be helpful?

Comment: I meant the exact opposite of that

Comment: @OferSadan There is a feature request of that kind (without the checkbox part, as SO is generally allergic to checkboxes). [Auto-comment close votes for all close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256808)

Comment: I also [requested that the close votes get more prominence for people answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users) in the hope people might vote to close instead of answering from time to time.

Comment: Speaking of flags... how do you have so many? 7/29/16 -> 10/9/17 is 437 days. I thought there was a limit of 100 flags/day (43,700) but you have 45,456. Am I mistaken about the 100 flag cap?

Comment: @C.Helling One can cast up to 100 _post_ flags and 100 _comment_ flags.

Comment: @Desire Oh wow. Well in that case, congrats on being a super prolific flagger. Thanks for all the hard work cleaning up the site!