# Should I remove 'fluff' (like greetings, signatures, "thanks", etc.) when editing questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

When I edit questions I typically focus on style, grammar, and spelling. However, in the process I often also remove 'fluff' like:

> This may be simple but, ...

or

> Can you help me with this?

I do so when I think it will make the question more direct and readable, but I also wonder if preserving the OP's voice is important in the spirit of a more conversational style.

These edits have been approved, but I was wondering in general what the policy was.

Comment: Best practice is to treat SO as a Q&A site. I feel no remorse removing fluff such as "I got back to programming after a 10 yr hiatus and now ..."

Comment: I've never had any OP complain because I removed fluff from their post. Not once.

Comment: Most OPs may be don't even realize when they're adding fluff until someone shows them, also my personal exp ;)

Comment: Somehow related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260205/add-terms-like-i-am-new-to-i-am-a-beginner-and-variants-thereof-to-the-low

Comment: "I've just started editing questions." Could be considered as fluff as well...

Comment: @yoshi I considered that while writing the question, but decided to leave it in. It's true that 'fluff' is very subjective which is part of why I asked.

Comment: Be careful not to remove **information which is important to tailoring answers to the asker's experience level**.  If someone says they are new to a particular technology, they may need a more detailed answer than usual.

Comment: @ouflak you haven't done that many edits then :)

Comment: @ouflak example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/100003/revisions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't think *I is new to topic* is useful enough to include in a Question. If the explanation is not enough, it's may be because Asker just hasn't done basic reading on the given topic. There is also an option to ask for clarifications in Comments. I am even thinking how the Question is asked may be revealing of the level of the Asker.

Comment: @Tshepang - this kind of "if it's not enough they can ask for clarification" wastes everyone's time.  There's no justification for **meddling with the site** to remove *useful information* which was provided upfront, when it may only have to be **reposted again later** after your destructive edit.  If you aren't going to answer the question, don't remove **information** from it which may be *useful to the person who would* - and it's the person who is in a position to answer, not some drive-by-meddler who is in a position to judge what is useful information.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I hear you, but I still maintain that more often than not, it really is just fluff, and does not affect how the Question is Answered (my guess). I say keep it cold and straight-to-the-point as a general rule. *I is new to topic* does not tell me how *new* you are. The Answerer is still left guessing. A good Question should be Answerable even if the Answerer knows nothing about the background of the Asker. That should be the case at least in SO terms, where a Question should ideally be useful to those other than the OP.

Comment: Some fluff might be useful in limited contexts.  If the question includes a detail about being related to a homework question or class project, I'll answer differently.

Comment: I'm with @austin. Some things require fluff, in fact I once had a question edited by someone who was antsy to get the +2 rep in which I said `"tried searching around a bit, and haven't been able to come up with a usable answer"` and someone edited it out and I got downvotes and comments like "you should research this before asking a question" but not quite as nice as that.

Comment: @Adjit If I consider your question trivial enough to downvote for not enough research, I don't care whether you say "tried searching around a bit;" I'll downvote anyway. I suspect many other users are the same way. "Tried searching" adds nothing useful to the question, either for potential answerers or for future visitors who may have the same question.

Comment: @Adjit Given the fact that absolutely anyone can add `"tried searching around a bit, and haven't been able to come up with a usable answer"` to their question, regardless of whether they actually did or not, I put absolutely no weight on that statement (and would thus classify it as fluff).

Comment: @Adjit in such cases, user should maybe list some of the resources she looked and why they didn't work. I think that could have avoided the downvotes. It's still a bit messy, but at least it's evidence that they tried. I personally prefer Questions cleaner than that, where for example OT would list such resources in the Comments.

Comment: @Jongware I wouldn't remove something like "I just got back to programming after a 10 yr hiatus".  This tells me a great deal when I sit down to compose an answer.  It instructs me on how I might shape my answer.  The take-away here is that one person's fluff is another person's meat.  Even something as innocuous as "I know this is simple, but..." points up frame of mind.  I might be thinking, "Well, it's precisely because you think it's simple that you're having problems."

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Regarding the "level" of an answer, in order for this site to be useful it is important that an answer be understandable *to the future visitors*. The OP, in itself, is just one among many, and therefore of little significance.

Comment: I think that if we remove this "fluff" as you call it, or "hints that the entity responsible is a human being", as I would like to call it, it will render questions less interesting to read for me, and render SO a colder and less interesting place in general. Not sure of how common my feelings are.

Comment: Absolutely remove, but I prefer to call it guff.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson I agree completely. SO is getting wayy too involved with rules. Who really cares? They few 'die hards' and that's it. SO is becoming so lame that they forget we are helping out other humans. They have this perception of how we all need to be mindless robots. Too many politics, we need to tone it down...

Comment: @2cents why are you editing posts when you appear to be totally new to the site?  Could you **use caution** in cases where you are editing the posts of people who seemingly have long experience on the site?  If you're editing the post of another newbie, whatever.  (Don't you need 80 thousand points or something to edit posts?)

Comment: @JoeBlow I want to actively contribute to the site and editing is one of the activity which my reputation level does allow. Most of the time I am editing posts of other newbies. I keep my editing activities pretty conservative, only editing posts where I'm reasonably sure that editing is required. Of course, my edits enter the revue queue before they are accepted. Caution is also the reason I asked this question.

Comment: that sounds awesome, but please don't edit out my "cheers" "Hello" "rock on" etc :)  Your comment "but I also wonder if preserving the OP's voice is important in the spirit of a more conversational style" is spot on.

Comment: I also edit to remove the leading "So" in sentences like "So I have the following HTML", because it's just so **stupid**.

Comment: The canonical question is *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)* (cross-site).

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: See also *[Fluff and Meta Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuRlLjd3700&t=303)* (by our very own [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory))

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351588/can-we-have-an-official-statement-regarding-greetings-salutations-etc-please I want to hotlink it to this post

Comment: You can remove unnecessary language while preserving the voice of OP. Remove superfluous statements like "Can you help me with this" but preserve the language used in conveying the actual problem they need to solve. That's how I approach it anyways. Only time I'll remove stuff from their description of the issue or conveyance of the answer is if it's detrimental or destructive to an otherwise good question or answer.

Comment: Related: [What should I keep out of my posts and titles? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/343832)

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Yes, absolutely remove such things.

Anything that is not relevant to the post is noise and should be removed.

That includes salutations, signatures, 'thanks' and the kind of content you have highlighted.

As noted in the Help Center, [users are expected to avoid this type of fluff in their posts, and should expect it to be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> **Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you, so fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!
>
> Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and, like other chitchat, should not be included.
>
> If you use signatures, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat, they will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.

Comment: Should these sort of edits be made if this is the *only* change?

Comment: @Yule - I tend to remove salutations and signatures, even if that's the extent of it. Many posts that have the other kind of rambling off topic detail can normally use a bit of more editing though, in my experience.

Comment: I would not recommend making these changes as the *only* changes in a suggested edit (as the OP's rep would require.) If you have full editing privileges, that's different.

Comment: BTW could the OP have marked an answer other than telling "YES" as the correct answer?? hehe

Comment: I think this is to over-simplify things. What's considered as "fluff" is rather subjective. The things the OP gave as examples don't necessarily call for an edit by their own merit, and they don't necessarily sort under the same category as salutations or signatures (which both call for an edit).

Comment: @wobble why not? There is no shortage of reviewers.

Comment: In the edit I was expecting to see some joker's edit summary saying: "removed fluff", that would have made my day.

Comment: Cheers Oded, the trouble is you're encouraging Naive New Editors - the most infuriating category of human on Earth - to pointlessly edit posts by seasoned users.

Comment: It's sad that good manners are considered 'noise'.

Comment: @Ryan - we focus here on questions and answers. Anything that detracts from the question/answer or is superfluous can and should be removed. We are trying to create a lasting repository of good questions and answers that will help people in the future - if you feel the need to thank people, you are most welcome to do so in comments.

Comment: "if you feel the need to thank people, you are most welcome to do so in comments."...Why then the prefilled hint "Avoid comments like 'Thanks'"?

Comment: @Ronnie - because we discourage such comments. I am saying that if someone really really really **must** do so, then do so in comments (which are easier to remove than making edits to a post).

Comment: Fair enough. I see what SO is trying to achieve with this approach, even if I don't fully agree with it. If there are a shedload of comments saying "Thanks", is that really going to get in anyone's way? Anyhow, just a thought. Apologies to anyone offended by my "fluffy" comments.

Comment: @Ronnie - it is "noise" (or "clutter"). It detracts from the post - what we want to focus on is the question/answer - anything else is just distraction.

Comment: Ok, but please remember we are all humans.

Comment: As for shedload of "Thanks". So now, in order to get to pertinent comments, you have to scroll through a bunch of those. I'd rather not have those around in the first place... @Ronnie

Comment: You should be grateful I raised this then, as "you are most welcome to" is certainly a contradiction to "we discourage".

Comment: I’ve been a SO user for years and answered a ton of questions and I find this answer to be absolutely appalling. I’ve recently run across some edits like this and it’s so incredibly obnoxious that I’m not sure that I want to continue using a site where this attitude gets so much support. This is absolutely disgusting.

Comment: @TomHarrington What is it disgusting? SO was meant to be a place to create a repository of questions and answers, like FAQs. Such posts should be professional and neutral, because they are meant to not only help the OP, but other users as well. SO is not a social network. Did you ever see a FAQ containing fluff?

Comment: I am amazed to find that so many here support the idea that saying things like "Hello" and "I appreciate any help" or even mentioning "I've been working on this for hours and I'm stuck" constitutes "fluff" that must be excised from questions. Is it bad that people write like people? Is it the SO consensus that people must act as good little robots, that anything that makes one notice there's a person there must be ruthlessly removed?

Comment: I've used SO for nearly ten years now, but after running across this Q&A I'm giving serious thought to whether I should just delete my account. This kind of editing is terrible, obnoxious, and extremely rude. It also seems to run directly counter to the recent [SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) about the problem of SO not being welcoming.

Comment: @TomHarrington I've always taken the "assume good faith" line and assumed that everyone who's here is grateful for any help is a given.

Comment: @Flexo So do I, but I don't carry that to the point of deciding that anyone who *does* say thanks needs to be corrected for having done so.

Comment: @TomHarrington - The deal here mostly isn't about the people who ask and answer the question. Thanks on its own is mostly harmless (it can interfere with auto question summary display). If thanks is polite and useful then "thank you very much" is more so. Or a story about coursework that's due tomorrow, which is where it really starts to hurts. All of the other 999 readers over the next year, here because 1st party documentation lacks, maybe not great English speakers, pays a comprehension cost to drill down to the actual content. That's why I favour writing content like a good book always.

Comment: If you favor writing like that, then *write like that*. Why enforce your own writing style on others? Why edit other people's content in order to make it sound like something you wrote?

Comment: I've often run into problems where without a "Can someone explain this?" the question isn't even a question, it's just a series of odd symptoms. That's not fluff.

Comment: @Tom: I tend to regard it as a matter of regret when people leave (or plan to leave) Stack Overflow because of a disagreement over the guidelines, rules or culture (and I note there's folks "on the other side" who are leaving because they perceive SO is becoming too tolerant of poor quality material). For what it's worth, I am moderately supportive of the famous blog post, so it's certainly possible to be in favour of being (more) welcoming while also wanting the site to present posts in a succinct and documentation/technical style.

Comment: It's not your fault that you've only just encountered this, just very poor luck I guess - prior to your frustration with this guideline, I'd not have thought it was possible for someone to have been here for ten years and not have encountered it in (either by their own posts being edited, or seeing those edits on other folks' posts).

Comment: For what it's worth, I tend to separate "fluff" into two categories - simple politenesses like greetings and thanks, which tends to be removed, but are short and not all that bothersome. There is another category that has (unintentional) obsequious and pleading characteristics, which I think causes (some) readers to downvote and move on. Thus, I think excising it is a kindness to the author - [see my thoughts here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Comment: Yes. Fluff is a plague and should be eliminated.

Comment: I am all for removing fluff and not adding signatures. And will not add to any future posts judging by this recommendation. But if this is your only change. Go do something else. If this site is supposed to be focused on questions and answers then add something to the answer or fix an actual problem in addition to the fluff or sit down and let professionals work. I am going to check every change to my questions like a code review because it is my representation online that I curate and if I am bothered by single fluff removal edit I am going to rollback because you don't deserve that edit.

Comment: @doubleA: I think it is broadly the community's view is that if a signature is the only thing to remove, then removing it is still fine. It's expected that anyone who experiences edits to their own material will check them, but rolling back good edits may still attract moderator flags.

Comment: This answer really speaks to the idea that SO: meta users [read: SO super users] are not representative of the overall SO community. At best, "fluff" inclusion can convey more than black and white answers. When you are new, seeing that someone else has experienced immense frustration over a question can alleviate your imposter syndrome, build a sense of hope, and rebuild confidence. Seeing appreciation leads to having appreciation. We are removing that human for little to no gain. Grammar is important but fluff removal is subjective and can easily be taken too far, leaving only void UX

Comment: I'm also disappointed that some here are using these upvoted response as a means to *force* these ideals, even when unwanted. The OP's hesitation was warranted

Comment: "Should these sort of edits be made if this is the only change?" If the edit system actually worked properly (you know, like a VCS), then it would be *preferable* to use a separate edit to remove the fluff, vs. other improvements. That would allow others to be selective when making rollbacks if they dispute your changes.

Comment: "It's sad that good manners are considered 'noise'." An ideal, high quality question has one person asking, one or more - but probably very close to one - people answering, and perhaps *literally millions* of people finding the question later with a search engine, digging it up while checking that their own questions aren't duplicates, stumbling upon it while browsing the site, etc. "Thanks" directed from the asker to the answerer is a courtesy to the answerer, and *a waste of precious milliseconds of time, multiplied by potentially millions, to everyone else*.

Comment: (it's also distracting: it breaks the mental flow of people who are reading the question to verify that it matches what they wanted to ask.)

Comment: politeness is basis of a good society. Every person who post here are people with feelings and we should be polite with them. It"s not just "noise", it's respect. I'm nobody, just a lambda guy, but I will always post politness sentences in my questions and will hope will not be edited. Why annonying everybody by editing their posts and asking people to waste their time by asking them to remove politness ? Somebody will answer freely to my questions, the minimum is to have good manners with this person.

Answer (score 75):

Yes, as Oded mentioned, you should remove fluff.

---

However, with regard to:

> Can you help me with this?

Many people see it as a requirement that the question must contain a question (i.e. a sentence ending with "?").

If the above is the only question in the post, it's often better to leave it there, although it's even better to replace it with a more meaningful question.

A trivial change that can often be done is to just rephrase the most relevant sentence as a question. For example:

> I don't know why the foo is bar. Can you help me?

to:

> Why is the foo bar?

Comment: Beware: "It doesn't work" smells like a bad question. Sometimes (often?) such questions lack description of _what_ doesn't work: Are there any error messages, what is the expected behaviour, how does it behave instead and so on. Normaly you should vote to close such questions due to missing informations.

Comment: @OcasoProtal It's probably better in that situation to comment asking for more information before voting to close it. Lack of info is something that the question can come back from and end up being a good question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Changed it a bit (yeah, most, if not all, of the time, one can edit in a better question than "why doesn't it work", or it should be closed). However, I'm not saying a question always adds to a post's quality - sometimes (when editing a post) I just add a question to make a few users happy who seem to be unable to look past a missing question (while the problem is explained 100% clearly).

Comment: @Tim.DeVries You are probably right, I mostly do this on a lot of questions, but there is already a discussion on this topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256788/dealing-with-ask-and-run-questioners

Comment: -1: "Can you help me?" is _not_ a valid on-topic question.

Comment: **If after your edit there is no on-topic, clear, concise, and correctly punctuated question, your edit is too minor or invalid**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit By my perception of many users, it seems to be better to leave a bad question in a post rather than not having one at all, which is why I'd rather leave it there than remove it, but ideally I'd replace it with a more meaningful question. If it's off topic, we can close it - closing and editing aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @bjb568 In the context of editing new posts with editing privileges, I disagree. One can make changes that massively improves readability, but there's still a lot that can be improved. Fixing a few things is better than not fixing anything. You may think it's off topic, but others may not agree (thus it doesn't get closed), or it could take a while to get closed / deleted - either way, an edit improves the post while it's on the site, which I see as a good thing, and it teaches the posting user (and others) about appropriate formatting, etc.

Comment: @Dukeling: I can't find the link now, but editing posts you _know_ are about to be closed is discouraged. I appreciate that you cannot always be sure.

Comment: @Dukeling Of course. I'm talking about without edit privs, OP has 31 rep.

Answer (score 54):

Define fluff.

Your examples are not something that calls for an edit. A post needs some text to hold it together. What's considered as necessary and what's considered as superfluous is very subjective.

Edits need to be substantial and address several issues. As a rule of thumb, consider whether the specific edit you are about to do is substantial enough on its own merit, to justify a whole post edit.

Also, while lines like "can you help me with this", "thanks for any help" seem superfluous, there is nothing wrong with being polite. To edit a post just to remove a "thanks" is too minor a change.

So I would say, in most cases leave the fluff alone. Instead, focus on editing out the *garbage*.

Some examples of *garbage* that only clutter down the post and should be removed:

- Any form of salutations.
- Any form of post signatures.
- "Story of my life" rants about people's background, that aren't relevant to the question. This isn't black or white, but most of the time the amount of experience of the poster is irrelevant.
- Similarly, details about the poster's personal life and other such random chit-chat should be removed, this isn't Facebook.
- Any form of demands or begging (may also justify down votes):

  - "Urgent! I need an answer today!"
  - "Provide full source code in your answer."
  - "I'm in deep trouble, please help me please"
  - "Please don't close this question"
- Offensive language of any kind. In these cases you should also flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: *Superfluffous.

Comment: _most of the time the amount of experience of the poster is irrelevant._ Yes. But let's agree on a counterexample: _After years of VB I'm starting with C# and wonder why this won't work as expected.._

Comment: @TaW _It doesn't work, because your years of VB programming are irrelevant for C#. It turns out that C# programs must be written in the C# language_. Or are you implying that the VB experience is relevant to state just because people who've programmed in VB for a long time are damaged to the point no hope for recovery? Since I have worked briefly as a VB programmer, I might agree with that. But failing to do a minimum of research about how C# works before asking a question is not justified just because you come from another programming language.

Comment: You're right in all what you say. However __knowing__ the OP comes from a certain area may very well help identifying some problems these users tend to have. So, while it probably is irrelevant to the question it is __not__ irrelevant to the one who answers. (Unless that person doesn't know VB, anyway..) This is similar to _I want to port my app from WinForms to WPF_ in that it can provide helpful background.. (On our personal notes: My recovering from Basic happend when I could move away from it to Turbo Pascal 1.0; so I'm over it for quite some time ;-)

Comment: "Any form of demands or begging" Don't consider DV, do it. And CV and VLQ. If ranting about the system ("closers don't want others to learn"), flag as offensive. AND DON'T EDIT! Edits are supposed to make a post good. While you may be able to make crap good (more than "improved formatting" - that's too minor), it's crap and doesn't deserve your time.

Comment: @Lundin: Information about prior languages are good to keep around, because then an answer can compare and contrast with something the asker is already very familiar with.  For example, something might be easy to explain in terms of monads, but that's generally a bad idea.  If the poster says they're coming from a functional background, though, it becomes much more practical.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is always more practical way to put "coming from X language/framework" - if OP uses "In X I expect this construct to behave .... but in Y I found it ....." - showing both experience with X and good explanation of confusion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I agree, that's a better way to convey the information.  But "less than ideal" doesn't automatically mean "delete-worthy".

Comment: @Lundin how could you forget "Sorry for bad english, thanks in advanced" ?

Answer (score 22):

**If you're already editing for other reasons**, feel free to remove the greetings, thanks, etc.  They're just there mostly because someone wanted to be polite, and doesn't realize how much we value getting to the point.

But personally, I typically **don't edit a post *just* to remove them** (unless they're like half the question).  And unless the post is otherwise perfect, I'll generally reject a suggested edit as "too minor" if that's the only change.

"Fluff" -- while not ideal -- is not a problem in and of itself.  **Succintness is a preference, not a correctness issue.**  There are invariably *real* problems (grammatical errors, misspellings, atrocious formatting, etc) in that post...and any one of those problems is more significant than all the "Hello"s and "Thanks"es on the entire site.

**If all you do is remove a bit of fluff, that hasn't actually *fixed* anything.**  But if you're actually fixing the post, there's nothing wrong with streamlining it a bit as well.

Comment: I still don't understand this viewpoint. It's not as if the SO database cannot handle one more edit. Why not keep questions tidy? What on earth is lost by performing this "too minor" improvement?

Comment: @Lightness A minor edit from a high-rep user != a minor edit suggestion from a low-rep user.

Comment: @ClickRick: Granted. But cHao is high-rep and he says _he_ doesn't do it. I'm curious as to why.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't do it because in my opinion, it almost never actually *fixes* anything -- their effect on a post's actual quality is basically nil.  It's like rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic.  A post that includes them invariably has a number of real issues, and fixing a single one of those issues is IMO more productive than going through and removing every single "hello" and  "thanks" from every post on the site.  Edits should fix those real issues, and *while you're there*, remove stuff like "thanks".

Comment: @cHao: Yes, of course, but that is not the comparison we were talking about. The comparison we were talking about is not "minor edits" vs "fixing everything" (there, the preferred option is _obvious_); the comparison we were talking about is "minor edits" vs "nothing", and I fail to understand how you could honestly believe that "nothing" is better than "minor edits" when the "minor edits" correct issues that are widely acknowledged as undesirable on SO.

Comment: @Lightness: Every edit has a small chance of pissing someone off who thinks you're putting words in their mouth.  If you're going to make a change, the change might as well be substantial.  And i simply don't see removing such things on their own as worthy of an edit on their own.

Comment: @cHao: I'm certainly not going to start adjusting my edit behaviour just to avoid "pissing someone off" by editing their posts. Stack Overflow is very clear that content is freely licensed to the community and can be edited by anyone [with edit privileges]; if somebody is getting a stick up their rear about "their" posts being edited, then it is _they_ who needs the attitude adjustment! Besides, if their post was a mess and needed "fixing" in the first place then I don't really care if they think I'm "putting words in their mouth": they haven't a leg to stand on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And that's fine.  I'm not worried about pissing someone off either, *if the change is substantial*.  But some changes are so minor that on their own, they're not worth the friction they can cause.  Like it or not, people *do* get a bit defensive about *their* posts, because their name is attached to those posts.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If someone edits a post that adds nothing to the actual content, it seems to me like they did it to just get their name on the post, their +2 reputation or whatever.

Comment: @justcool393: Well, then you are under false assumptions about people's intentions. Why not instead assume good faith in the first instance? I will _always_ strive to improve a post even if it's just formatting, because improvements are improvements and I give of my time freely to effect them. It has nothing to do with "getting my name on the post" or accruing a measly +2 rep; I have little need of either, as you'll see from my profile.

Comment: @justcool393: You should spend less time/energy worrying about _why_ people are doing a thing, and focus more on _what that thing is_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And if you're honestly trying to improve the post, you're also not *just* going to remove a "hi" or "thanks" and leave the other errors in the post, are you?  (If so, i would be forced to doubt the sincerity of your intentions.)

Comment: Let me be clear. "I still don't understand this viewpoint" is not "requesting clarification" and it is not indicating that I am lacking some information or that I am not clever enough to understand the words in your answer. I understand the viewpoint just fine. I just can't understand why on earth you could possibly think it's a good thing that you hold it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Then say you don't understand *why* i would have the viewpoint.  As for why...though i'm not thrilled about them, an extra "hi" or "thanks" doesn't make a question any less comprehensible or correct.  IMO, too many people have gone absolutely rabid over "fluff", focusing on it to the exclusion of real problems.  I feel that's wrong, and if that's all someone wants to do, i refuse to support it.

Comment: I feel it is quite reasonable to expect editors to fix *at least one real problem* with the post while they're in there.  Even if it's a single typo, the post ends up more readable than it was.  Time constraints are BS -- someone who "doesn't have time" to correct a misspelling or highlight a few lines and hit Ctrl+K, doesn't have time to edit in the first place.  And the lack of *inclination* to do anything else, is *part of the problem*.

Comment: @cHao: `Time constraints are BS -- someone who "doesn't have time" to correct a misspelling or highlight a few lines and hit Ctrl+K, doesn't have time to edit in the first place` Where did anyone claim that? I said that _is_ what I have time for: what I don't necessarily care to do is spend a further ten minutes of my life significantly transforming the post to improve its content or presentation of results. You seem to have some sort of vendetta against people who do not care to give freely as much of their time as is necessary to fix every single problem with every post that they edit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And you seem to be intent on misreading my point.  I never, not even once, said you had to go and fix every problem.  What i have said all along, is that fixing even *one* real problem is worth an edit -- and *while you're fixing that problem*, if you feel like defluffing, more power to you.  But an edit solely to remove the fluff, IMO, is too minor unless the post is otherwise perfect.

Comment: @halfer I think it would do you well to read this

Answer (score 20):

Yes, please remove them!

Furthermore, I usually remove introductory sentences like: "I am totally new to ...", "I have no clue about..." or "This is extremely urgent! PLEASE HELP!!!!!".

P.S: Yes 'fluff' is an appropriate designation. I used to call it boilerplate text in my comments.

P.P.S: If the question is really crap (i.e. not salvageable), just downvote it and vote to close.

Comment: If you call it "noise" some less technical people get upset and think you're abusing them.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't mind leaving that last one in. It's a reminder to everyone to wait a couple of days before answering ;-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: If the question is otherwise bad, I wouldn't edit out "PLS. ITS URGENT"; it helps indicate that the question is downvote-worthy :)

Comment: "I am totally new to" is **important information** which **should NOT be removed** by third party editors.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Not really.  It's basically a different spelling of "use small words".  :P  A decent answer will be doing that to a reasonable extent anyway.  And if "I am totally new to..." means "Hello World is out of my league", then they need a good book, not a Q/A site.

Comment: About *"This is extremely urgent! PLEASE HELP!!!!!"*, I **downvote** those.

Comment: Chris is completely correct.  The problem is you have **two totally different categories of things** in your list of humorous examples, Burk.  Idiocy like "extremely urgent help" and "after moving back in to grandma's house I have found a community college... etc" is a social fail and should be deleted.  In contrast stating "I am at square one on this topic" as opposed to "I am a leading engineer in this topic and I am asking an arcane question" is central to the question.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Thanks for clarifying. English is not my mother tongue and I sometimes cannot express myself perfectly well.

Comment: Your English seems flawless.  95% of English native speakers have incredibly poor grammar and English; yours is perfect.

Answer (score -9):

@Cecilia is right to be weary of preserving the OP's voice and the importance of that voice in the spirit of a more conversational style. **These things are what makes this site friendly** [read: fun and engaging for new (and some old) users]. I think editing grammar, fixing spelling mistakes, and re-styling are all net positives with no downside. Subjective "fluff" moderation will definitely lead to edits being done for the purpose of editing, as exemplified by many comments in this question. The idea that @cHao makes regarding how an edit made with next to no net positive impact, a very minor change, is likely a net negative rings true. You remove the independence from the author and provide nothing in return except a removal of things that, in my opinion, are often warm-welcoming.

**I think the strong, opinionated responses in this question are skewed towards the meta user base** and I find this to be the case on many meta posts. Meta users tend to only be super-users, and thus are far removed from what it's like being a newcomer (no small portion of the overall SO user base). "Fluff" inclusion can convey more than black and white answers. When you are new, seeing that someone else has experienced immense frustration over a question can alleviate imposter syndrome, build a sense of hope, and rebuild confidence. Seeing appreciation leads to having appreciation. To me it's like an efficient back end for a web-app: it doesn't really matter how efficient it is if nobody wants to use it. Balance is key and if these things [small aforementioned humanisms] are removed for the sole sake of removing them, providing no grammatical benefit or readability improvement, then it begs the question: Why remove it at all? Why not let the user have a voice and **become** someone who wants to partake in the community. Making an edit without regards to net positive impact does nothing to enhance the user experience and likely removes from it.

Grammatical errors, spelling mistakes, readability obfuscations, *excessive* gripes... I don't think anyone here is arguing **for** keeping these... That we can all agree on, and that's where I think the line should be drawn.

Comment: Looking at the [Revision 3 (5 & 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68672773/revisions) edits to your question (which removed "fluff") as an example, the post originally began with "**I have been scouring the internet for solution...**" and ends with "**Any and all help will be supremely appreciated**". Both statements feel personal in nature and add to the voice of the author, but if you step back and look, aren't they generic statements that could be copy-pasted into any number of questions? Also note that "*[Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110)*"

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not about the user. It is about the usability and long-lasting value of the content, the questions, and the answers. It is not a social media platform.

Comment: @Nimantha yes! I think they can definitely be generic statements, as is hello, thank you, etc. It is my opinion that if this site were to truly remove *everything* like this, it would be void of something I like.  Gino Mempin brings up a good point too, that SO should be long-lasting. It's my opinion that we cannot completely ignore the user if we want that. It has the market share surely, but if newer users feel they are confined to questions and *only* questions, stripping them of any humanisms, how fun is it really to engage?

Comment: @Nimantha I'd also say that a "discussion" or "excessive" fluff is vastly different from a brief show of gratitude. It is also a rule that you look up answers before responding, which I think the first statement pertains to. Neither are excessive, they don't detract from the question in any real way, and provide a benefit to any who may have the same issue but were pulling their hair out; a feeling of comfort that they are not alone in having trouble with a specific problem. You can see how this forum was used as justification for removing stuff that lead to almost no net positive gain