# How to handle apologetic content in questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I make a conscious effort to not be (too) apologetic when asking questions; I regard it as [fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). On the other hand it may provide valuable insight into the skill level the asker has with the specific technology and affects how detailed the answer should be. A beginner may need links to specific parts of documentation or code snippets whereas a pro may only need a word.

I'm talking about things like

- I know the code is bad but I'm new to this.
- Please be patient, I'm still learning.

The exact question I have in mind is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757193/get-working-code-back-but-maintaining-a-few-changes):

> I'm still learning Git and how it works since it's a bit different from Subversion so be patiente, any advice, help

This is both fluff and information. When in doubt I err on the side of caution and don't edit. How would the community handle this?

Comment: Yes, you should edit that out. It doesn't provide any information relevant to the question.

Comment: I think I'd leave in the fact that the user is switching to Git from Subversion as someone may be able to make useful comparisons based on that fact. I'd take out "be patient, any advice, help" though.

Comment: In its most uninformative manifestations, it's a sign of a poor question, in my experience. The author substitutes the question prep work e should have done with an appeal for sympathy.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Possible. However a lot of people are simply very humble. They don't mean to be but it can be very annoying.

Comment: @ musiKk A lot of programmers are stridently logical nitpicking sticklers and this can also be annoying too! A foolish consistency often seems to win out over kinder approaches in moderation here. Not that one shouldn't trim excess fluff but maybe think American or French rather than Brazilian.

Comment: [Related thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).