# My account been banned from asking questions, how can I delete my account?

Tags: bug, post-ban

My account been banned from asking questions and I'd like to delete my account.

Can the same mail address be used on more than one Stack Overflow account? What happens if I delete my account, and then return?

Some people have high reputation, but they don't seem wiling to help me; they just make fun of me by down-voting. I think the preference of information type doesn't count as absolute wisdom.

Still, I need to use the site.

Comment: hi , Tim, thanks for re-editing , that's what exactly what i wanna to say without rage.

Comment: I can understand the frustration, and you're not the only one in this position.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I've reviewed a few of your questions. The ones I looked at seem quite sensible, but the issue is the spelling and grammar, which makes it very difficult to know what you;re asking. Is this something that's an issue for you? If so, I can relate to that.

Comment: Hi,supperluminary, the post ban have been canceled 2 month ago , i had gained the post permission right after i post my probelm here. do not worry please. i also hope i can improve grammar too.

Comment: hey, what's wrong with all my posts ? i never click the "delete account button" which in my inbox. any supper user accidentally cleared it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

***Short answer: we recommend not deleting your account, you should [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) if you feel that's your only or best option.***

I'll now go into a bit more depth.

We've recently made some changes to the question block system that *might* have prevented you from reaching the point that you did. Before, the system kicked in *after* you had asked at least a few questions that weren't very well received. Depending on how things went from there, it's possible that you found yourself in a state that couldn't be helped.

When their three most negatively-scored and deleted questions are basically *unsalvageable*, there's very little chance that folks would ever be able to pull themselves out of the block. We're different than any forum, and even other Q&A sites - it sometimes takes folks a few belly flops in order to figure that out.

Under the new system, you would have been slowed down *significantly*, starting with your second question, and shown much more comprehensive help. The system also now gives you a bit more credit for positive participation in other areas of the site, as well as comprehensive edits you make to your own posts, and this is conveyed in the new guidance that we provide.

We can't however go back in time and attempt to slow you down and give you better guidance. There's no way to make this 'retroactively' fair. These are your options:

- You *can* request account deletion, but [you will be limited to one question per week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-limiting-recidivists-to-post-one-question-per-wee/234610#234610) until you've established yourself as a solid contributor, or at least demonstrated a pattern of not making the site worse.
- You can also contact us and *show us* through your words, grammar, capitalization and punctuation that you are perfectly capable of writing a proper, coherent post *after* you're certain that you've gone back and edited your previous questions to the best of your ability. If you have a few initial questions that are just holding you back, we might be able to help.

We're a bit more sympathetic to those that are just hopelessly stuck, and we *will* do what we can to help you, *if you can show us that you've improved since your earliest questions*. I'd avoid things like 'plz', 'ur', etc - make it good. Capitalize your sentences. Use punctuation, proof read - don't hit the submit button on the contact form until you're *sure* you nailed it.

Thankfully, the system is now better optimized to not exclude those that *can* become good contributors if given a few more chances, while also not allowing folks that repeatedly get it wrong to keep throwing themselves at a wall.

Comment: will be limited to one question per week  ---- is  ok , do it .

Comment: @Johnny Go ahead and put in the delete request then. Though I'd really recommend just contacting us and asking us to review your history. You've got some good questions to your credit.

Comment: and that don't stop User "Dick" down-vote to banned me , i think it is the question content a little bit complex, and the format do have problem,  but mainly the content that piss him off that make he down-vote to ban.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at the votes on your account, as you keep mentioning this. If someone serially down-voted you into a block, I can certainly fix that, and have a few words with them in private.

Comment: Okay. Nothing really _irregular_ there, but some attention on your better questions seems to have lifted your block. Just try your best to capitalize your sentences, use code formatting and be as clear as you can, and you should be fine.

Comment: not at all , master, i make false allegation to make attentions. i have no attendtion to pollute stackoverflow, it is already overflowed isn't it , i am not a attacker, i am most timely reading-only user, a lot question been solved by only google stackoverflow.com. however there are subtle problems that don't find match , then i post a question(may not well described) in good hope someone happened to encounter also. the format can only be improved by several rounds of exchange  of opinions

Comment: , and who don't care about it can leave it alone, google can do it by only focus on real information. people can do either.

Comment: @Johnny Leaving bad questions alone is not an option. Over time bad questions would contribute to watering down the quality of this site. There's a reason why stackoverflow is a useful resource and it's because bad questions are not allowed to persist on the site. Much like a garden will no longer be nice if the weeds are not removed, stackoverflow would no longer be useful if bad questions were allowed to stay around.

Comment: @Johnny OK, I'm saying this with all due respect. You need to improve your English, especially your sentence structure and order. This would help you both on Stack Overflow, and in life. Even some of the free online courses could help. Try http://www.talkenglish.com/

Comment: message received , your honor.

Comment: so how to show respect without honorifics? i don't mean sarcasm.

Comment: Also, if you need to make 7 edits on a question within an hour, you should probably think it out a little more before asking

Comment: don't get it wrong , i mean you are really helpful. i don't think i cursing online is good(but with right emotion, it kind of within context at least), and the admin despite that and recover my posting rights,and helping me re-editing my wrong formatted posts, it is some moral quality i cherished about.

Comment: i count stackoverflow as a thinking device, unavoidably it recorded some of my thinking process/footprint.

Comment: @Daedalus give him some chances. Not all people are really adequate in English, especially in Eastern Asia.

Comment: @Johnny I hope you understand that StackOverflow is an English-speaking site. As for current, some of your English can be considered as weird, like the honorifics. In English culture, using Sir/Mam is the norm than your honor/master. I don't mean to offend your English, but this is really my humble advice.

Comment: @Johnny I'd also add that on StackOverflow, as long as you are polite those honorific words are not needed. For example, it's not considered useful to have "thanks" at the end of questions. We know you are thankful already :)

Comment: @DavidG In some cultures "as long as you are polite" translates as "as long as you are using honorifics" (among other signs of politeness). So what you said could be understood as "as long as you are using honorifics those honorific words are not needed." :) It is better to say that honorifics are not usually needed on SO, and that their use may be construed as being too polite and thus sarcastic.

Comment: @Louis Indeed, cultural bias is a huge part of this. Relevant MSO discussion here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/1663001

Comment: @AndrewT. Comment deleted.

Comment: @TimPost , I totally agree with andrew , i participate in alot of online forums too and often there are people who have a genuin problem , which they find hard to describe , I think there are two things you can do about this , put in a system that "identifies such users and is more lenient towards them " , so say the user post 3 consecutive questions that all get downvoted(hopefully not terribly downvoted) ... give the guy another chance . secoundly , put in a system in place that tracks and gives such users reminders , that they need to improve thier grammer/english.