# What's the procedure when I don't agree with a change made to my edit by a reviewer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28592879/revisions) and it was approved by two users while a third chose what I presume is an 'Edit' option in the suggested edit reviews and added back in 2 lines of the 'fluff' my suggested edit removed. As far as I was aware the general consensus is that [such content is noisy and should be removed from posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/3725745), I don't usually go out of my way to do so but three separate lines at the end of the question just seemed like too much.

What process should be followed when I don't agree with a reviewer's edit of my edit? Is asking a question here on Meta the end of it or is there something else I should do?

Comment: Leave a nice comment to the editor containg the noise-link.

Comment: @juergend Doesn't adding a comment that has little directly to do with the post seem just as 'noisy' as the fluff I was trying to remove?

Comment: We have to educate users on how to post, review, edit somehow. You can remove the comment later or try to get in chat with the user.

Comment: You could just suggest an edit again (you _can_ do that as <2k user, not?). I'd remove the fluff.

Comment: @cerbrus I could suggest another edit but I'd rather not run the risk of getting into an edit war, I don't _think_ that would happen in this particular situation but I was wondering if there were more general guidelines for less cut-and-dry conflicts I (or other users) might come across in future.

Comment: It's possible that the editor didn't add back in the "noise", but rather made their own separate edit out of sync to correct a different issue and simply overwrote this change. I don't think it really matters honestly. If you think the post needs an edit, despite how many times and in what ways it's already be revised, then go ahead and submit that edit.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I did mention in the question that their name was shown in the review history as "Reviewed: Edit" so they obviously saw my edit when they reviewed it.