# No Thanks, Damn It!

Tags: discussion, clean-up

- For a while this year, I was on a crusade, editing posts to remove "Thanks".

  But there were far too many of those posts.
- So I started to remove "Thanks in advance".

  But there were too many of those.
- So I started to remove "Thanks in advanced", which in addition to being inappropriate for Stack Exchange, is a corruption of the English language, and needs to be stamped out before too many people decide that it's correct English (thus making it into correct English).

  But I got bored with that and gave up.
- But now, I've seen a new outrage and I want your help cleaning it up: "Thanks in advantage". Yes, really, "Thanks in advantage"! There are 221 of those on Stack Overflow right now: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Thanks%20in%20advantage%22.

Can we please clean those up before the English language changes out from under us?

Thx 4 ur hlp.

---

> Obviously, I have trouble making myself understood. Any time I talk
> about editing one part of a post, there are many people who believe
> that I mean to *only* edit that part of the post. In fact, I *never*
> edit just one part of the post. I don't as much as cast a **close** or
> **delete** vote without editing the entire post!

---

Please take the time to read "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

---

> BTW, when I say "edit" in this question, I mean full edits, not
> suggested edits. I'm not advocating filling up the suggested edit
> queue with large numbers of "thanks" edits. And I'm *certainly* not
> suggesting suggested edits which *only* remove "thanks".

---

We're up to 6,600+ ["Thanks in advanced"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanced%22) questions! This did not work!

Comment: I cleared all comments here as they were no longer workable. If you want to discuss if *Thanks* and variations are useful, do so in [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: I removed two new "Thanks in advantage" instances today. I can't help but feel like we're at a disadvantage...

Comment: too much time to edit posts, not enough time programming

Comment: Almost as bad is: "Kindly {paste|post} the {codes|solution}."
Me: "OK, kindly accept this downvote"

Comment: Up to over 5000 "[Thanks in advanced](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanced%22)" again :(

Comment: @JohnSaunders this could be interesting for you: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333065/a-moderator-messaged-me-that-my-edits-which-only-remove-thanks-and-alike-are-d

Comment: Why doesn't stackoverflow disallow posting of such phrases?

Comment: This statement at the start *I was on a crusade, editing posts to remove "Thanks".* and this one at the end *And I'm certainly not suggesting suggested edits which only remove "thanks".* appear contradictory to me.

Comment: @JohnSaunders when you were on your crusade, did you edit posts to only remove "thanks"?

Comment: @icc97 no. I edited posts to remove "thanks" and to correct any other problems.

Comment: Also irritating: ["any help will be helpful"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22any+help+will+be+helpful%22)

Comment: Automatically removing these would make sense. Why are these phrases not blocked?

Comment: Thank god there's no [Thanks in advantaged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+advantaged%22)

Comment: Can somebody smarter than me write a script to automate this, please?

Comment: @TheMaker What's wrong with reading?

Please take the time to read "Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?

Comment: Yes, I read it. I still don't see why Thanks should be removed. This site is composed of humans, not robots. We can thank people, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @TheMaker We do read dictionaries, and they don't start with "Hello! Here's the meaning of _paperclip_:" Articles in Wikipedia also don't end with "Thanks for reading about _Carnation Day_!". While on Stack Overflow, please use the standard form of appreciating the content of a post, which is to upvote it. Fluff is not only necessary, but we also have people actively removing it from posts.

Comment: John, I can definitely [see what you mean](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51OcCsviHdL._SX312_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg).

Comment: @E_net4 stays away from Meta: Don't you mean *unnecessary*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes. It was too late for me to edit the comment when I noticed it.

Comment: Closely related: *"Any help would be appreciated."*

Comment: I have removed all 17 occurences of "Thanks in advanc"

Comment: Als removed all 2 occurences of "Thanks sirs" and 8 times "Thank in advantage"

Comment: What about the TIA variant?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer - it is strangely amiss from the lists, but it was brought up by Heretic Monkey in 2019 - yes, TIA is hilarious :)

Comment: Bringing up how ignoring a wave of bad English will convert it to proper English has given me a whole new passion for editing now. Wow.

Comment: Should we remove the "Thanks in advanced" in posts that are flagged as [duplicate] or [closed]?

Comment: @T0ny1234 - good question. I'd be inclined to say - don't bother. Some will be removed by roomba, some dealt with by SOCVR regulars, etc. Plus there is a danger of sending the post to the reopen queue with an unsubstantial edit that will waste the only chance the post gets automatically. But we have plenty to do even without the closed posts :)

Comment: Yes, @T0ny1234. It's equally important since those posts might be re-opened in the future.

Comment: We're at 4,846 [Thanks in advanced](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanced%22) and 126 [any help will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22any+help+will+be+helpful%22).

Comment: Putting English grammar mistakes aside (probably I have some as well) why the hell would you care people wants to thank for helping them. What's wrong with you people?!?!?!

Comment: I did find one ["any help will be helpfully"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22any+help+will+be+helpfully%22) post. @dushkin I think people are bothered by it because it's needless, gets in the way, and is considered "fluff" by Stack Overflow. It's not a terrible offense, but if users want to say thank you, then they can upvote and/or accept answers to their question. Stack Overflow is (trying to be) a database of helpful questions, and "thanks in advance" is not a necessary part of that. For more information, you can read the answers to this question.

Comment: Never trully got why a simple not oversized *thanks* or *hi* is a problem. Maybe we are being a bit *square minded* here? You are interacting with other humans guys, they sometimes happen to have emotions.

Comment: Actually, we are _not_ interacting with other humans. We are interacting with posterity. Posterity isn't going to tell us "you're welcome".

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with "Thanks" or "Thanks in advance". Politeness and gratitude are forbidden in SO? Moderators don't have anything much important to do?

Comment: @PetyaNaumova This question and the various answers in this page (especially [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179)) have already already laid out the arguments for why any kind of fluff is cleaned up in this platform. Please take your time reading them.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

I completely support such initiatives (and started to edit posts you indicated right now - they usually require much work unfortunately).

The only courtesy needed here is taking time to learn about our rules and guidelines - and the practice shows that just this is too much anyway.

**Adding "thank you" to a post that doesn't adhere to site's standards is false courtesy.**

In case of the minuscule number of well-written posts, adding "thank you" is of course nothing wrong, but I still tend to remove it, explaining politely why, if needed.

[MichaelT's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/288172?noredirect=1#comment166300_288172) seems to sum this up nicely:

> The politeness expressed by "hope this helps", "thank you" and "hello" is all similarly problematic in technical writing. **Stack Overflow, as a Q&A site, strives to be a technical resource akin to encyclopedias. That writing style that makes it useful as a technical resource precludes pleasantries and formalities**. Even in cultures with formalized pleasantries and courtesies, one doesn't see such pleasantries in the technical writing. The reason for removing "thank you" is exactly the same as the reason that "hope this helps" isn't at the bottom of every Wikipedia page.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

---

And of course improving the general "state" of the language is also very important (especially to non-native speakers, like me, who can pick up incorrect phrases, not being aware of that).

Comment: +1, especially for "Adding "thank you" to a post that doesn't adhere to site's standards is false courtesy." Thanks to someone who will have to clean the formatting? Or to someone who will have to fix typos? Or to someone who will have to add an umpteenth comment with request for at least some relevant info? No, such things do not look like courtesy but more like a smirk. Seeing these "Thanks" can easily remove any desire to help.

Comment: Why can't the user posting a comment that says "thank you" not automatically be shown a message explaining the site's standards and given the option to abandon posting the comment?

Comment: @DiegoDeberdt [It is too risky](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)/technically difficult to safely remove "thanks" while guaranteeing that the rest of the post is not accidentally corrupted.

Comment: it surprises me that a comment saying "Seeing these 'Thanks' can easily remove any desire to help" got any upvotes on a Stack site. i thought this was discussing "should we expend the effort to start editing posts in this way?", not "should we help people who say 'thank you in advance'?" If you're browsing posts to find the most palatable grammar to answer, you're probably not helping as many people as you could. @BartoszKP and others have a valid point, but i wouldn't extend it that far.

Comment: @Dpeif By "these "Thanks"" I meant exactly those posts where "Thanks" are surrounded by an awful mess of bad formatting, typos and completely irrelevant information.  I do not say that people who create such posts do not deserve any help(guidance, edits etc.), I say that instead of motivating or inspiring such "Thanks" just dishearten me. Editing, moderating and guiding someone takes a lot of effort - usually more than answering. I gladly edit, fix typos and ask for clarifications in posts where I can see some potential, and where I can't - I downvote or(and) close, or just move on.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I did not mention removing "thanks" in my comment. I talked about explaining the site's standards and also giving the user posting the comment the -option- of abandoning what he/she is doing.

Comment: When did StackOverlow get so anal about this kind of thing? This is a site where folks can get help and help others. I don't see how a "thank you" causes a question/answer/comment to become instantly unreadable.

Comment: Wow. You can edit it, moderate it, do whatever you want, but it's a message board and no amount of moderation will change that.  Glad you have time to waste deleting "thanks" from posts.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nick: it doesn't make it unreadable. But it's unnecessary fluff and counter to the goals of this site. By removing it (and adding a comment saying _why_ I removed it), I not only improve the site IMHO, but also educate other readers. The most important thing I can teach them is that [so] is not like other sites they've been on. They are "not in Kansas anymore".

Comment: @ssaltman: this is not a message board. It's not a forum. It's a very different site - it is a Q&A site which is not just focused on the Q and the A but also on all the future readers who will find the "A" while searching for the "Q". That's different from the purpose of a discussion forum or message board.

Comment: Agree with everything you and @MichaelT said. BUT, since it was quoted, I couldn't resist: there should be a comma after the subordinate clause, "as a Q&A site", and it should be "[...] isn't *at* the bottom of every Wikipedia page". Slight difference. (*Ducks for cover*) ;-)

Comment: I'm just going to say that while StackOverflow does strive to be a fantastic technical resource, it's also a social community. There is *some* need for courtesy. (Frankly a need for a little more than we have right now, in my opinion.) I would just remove such a note if it were bad grammar, we have bigger problems than people trying to be polite. As for "false courtesy," just close them and don't worry about whether the courtesy was false or real. The vitriol against people putting "thank you" on posts represents an enormously wrong focus on how to best spend our time improving the site.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Thanks, corrected! Feel free to just edit the post next time ;)

Comment: @jpmc26 Removing "thanks" is not just removing "thanks". It is also a way of communicating technical nature of this site - we want to have a knowledge repository, not a forum, not a discussion, not a message board. Salutations etc. are inherently related to these media, while lack of them is specific to technical resources. We have meta and chat for being more human.

Comment: @BartoszKP I think finding and closing (or salvaging) low quality questions would do more toward that goal than actively seeking out posts that say "thank you," as would a number of other activities. If you happen across one, it's fine and maybe even good to edit it out, but this is *not* serious enough to go looking for it. There is no need for crusading; that is just blowing the issue completely out of proportion and distracting us from more serious problems.

Comment: @jpmc26 You are free to go and fix problems you regard more serious :) And you can also write a call-to-action meta post describing what you think is more important. I don't have enough free time right now to go and do Great Things, but I can try to improve posts (not only removing "thanks" but doing a complete edit, where needed) from time to time, and finding "thanks" is *one of ways* I can find them.

Comment: @BartoszKP Using "thanks" as a heuristic to find questions that need addressing is fine, but that's not what's being described in this question or answer. They describe the inclusion of "thanks" as something *inherently* destructive, as a problem in and of itself that must be "crusaded" against, not in the context of the rest of the question being bad. Those are two very, very different things, and if we mean that "inclusion of thanks is a good heuristic for finding problem questions", then we should say that, not that it's some kind of blight to be stamped out with extreme prejudice.

Comment: @jpmc26 Exactly how I feel. You phrased it perfectly. It's true, a "thank you" generally indicates the user is new and the question might be low quality. However there's no reason to close or even edit a question if there's nothing actually wrong with it (besides the thank-you). I really think we're going after the wrong thing here.

Comment: @jpmc26 IMHO your interpretation of the question is a bit extreme, and while I agree that the reason I've stated in my comment is different I don't regard it as "very, very different". And anyway it's still not the point, and definitely not a point worth discussing with so many comments :) And, again, even if you don't find the other reasons important, caring about the language is still something that gives improvement and ultimately, big or small, that's what we want. Cheers!

Comment: "The only courtesy needed here is taking time to learn about our rules and guidelines". Honestly, I think this is a point where SO (and SE as a whole) has failed. It doesn't do a really good job of explaining that *EVERYTHING* is nuanced, what we should and shouldn't do. People get pissed off at new people for things that are small violations. And this is a Q&A site, people are just looking to get their questions answered. It shouldn't force you to click through all of the items in the help center and meta SE. People come for the Q&A, not the community. Oh, and thanks.

Comment: @justcool393 I, and seemingly many other people, didn't have any problem with lurking for a few weeks before writing my first post here. I do this with every other site I join, until I feel that I, at least partially, understand how things work. Rushing in into a new, unknown place, not caring about the rules and customs that are commonly accepted there is just plainly rude and stupid.

Comment: Maybe we should just block new users from asking questions completely for 2 weeks then. Because that will *surely* improve the quality of the site.. Right now, neither the 'ask question' page, the page that is before it for new users, or any direct links from these pages talks about this 'rule'. This RTFM mentality is toxic to the site and [we shouldn't expect all new users to know the rules.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) I will say though, I got a kick at how the answer acts likes it such an unpopular opinion to get rid of taglines in posts. As it is, the documentation honestly

Comment: sucks, and the new question page just reads like something to click through. But what's kind of stupid about all of this is that for all of the people complaining about a few extra words in a post, if all of them dedicated half as much time to the close vote queue rather than doing this, it would be practically empty.

Comment: @justcool393 Yeah, there were many ideas along these lines (block from asking until X rep, until N days, until whatever) but from what I recall none of this is going to happen, as the fact that anyone always can ask a question straight away is seen as one of the most important merits of SO.

Comment: "Stack Overflow, as a Q&A site, strives to be a technical resource akin to encyclopedias." seems more like a social media than an encyclopedia to me. There are so many aspects of this site that would be precluded in an akin-to-an-encyclopedia resource, like the use of "I tried this..." Even the comments feature, mostly unregulated and hardly filtered for quality, would not fit into such a category. Don't get me wrong, I agree that "thank you" detracts from the purpose of the questions but there is an undeniable aspect of this site that is _personal_ and begs for pleasantries.

Comment: @ryvantage You are right, but I believe that's why MichaelT has put "strives to be" instead of "is a" in his comment. The core idea behind the site, IMHO, should be accumulating knowledge in a form as encyclopaedic as possible. I agree that some aspects are and always will be social-media like, but if it is not absolutely necessary (like discussions in comments) social-media likeness should be IMHO, in general, avoided.

Comment: in some cultures *"thanks in advance"* is offensive as it implied that the reader has some obligation to help, it is like verbal arm bending in a way.

Comment: I had a obsession fighting against these as well, but `tagging in the title` is my new obsession!

Comment: "@JarrodRoberson, a man of many obsessions" :P

Comment: "Stack Overflow, as a Q&A site, strives to be a technical resource akin to encyclopedias"

Good luck with that. You are dealing with humans, from novice to expert level, and as a Q&A site allowing anyone to ask questions, a simple "Thanks" is quite simply a generalized formality in any Q&A session. Take any live Q&A panel as an example, where most people would end with "Thanks" or start with "Thank you for...". My point is, you will be very busy editing Q's in the future. I agree with formalities unrelated to the question to be unnessecary, but "Thanks." and/or "Hi" is not.

Comment: @OyvindAndersson That's all irrelevant. If we agree that this is the current policy, we will remove "Thanks" and "Hi", and we will need no more luck than fixing typos, commas and removing tags from titles.

Comment: @BartoszKP Nope. For you, perhaps. Still it's not agreed upon - and again, luck is on the table.

Comment: *For you, perhaps. Still it's not agreed upon* @OyvindAndersson - This is a [site rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: This seems like a petty attempt at removing a natural human element for a site that is driven by humans, i.e. it's unnecessary.  Posts that include "thanks" add about as much noise as a dog whistle.  Furthermore, the behavior model expects users to "Be nice." yet saying "Hi" and "Thanks" are prohibited - this is splitting hairs IMO.  I say lighten up and embrace the human experience.  But alas, I understand why this would be annoying, especially to developers ;)

Comment: @OyvindAndersson: It _is_ agreed upon. Bartosz is correct. You may wish  to accrue more experience with Stack Overflow before making policy comments. Thanks.

Comment: @ryvantage: A good question doesn't say "I tried this..." and list a bunch of attempts: it presents a [MCVE] and states a problem. That the closest we can get to this with some users is "I tried this..." is unfortunate but not the end goal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I don't wish that. Disagreed. Thanks.

Comment: @OyvindAndersson: Your call. Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't think that this applies when you have an extra requirement for those who respond like: "Please keep <this> in mind when you respond to my question. Thanks!" In this context the "thanks" is a tuple "please (a kind requirement) - thanks". 


The Stackoverflow seems to be "like" an enciclopedia but it's not exactly one, so in this context the "Thank you" it is so natural.

Comment: @Mario No, no, no. It's not "my question", it's a question posted on SO that belongs to everyone, with "me" being the author, but that's purely incidental. With this kind of objective perspective you really do not need to thank people for paying attention to the constraints of the problem you present.

Comment: @BartoszKP So what you say here is that if I make a technical requirement it is A MUST to sound like a COMMAND?

Why don't remove also the "please" word? It doesn't makes sense to have any words ("please" in this example) that creates a tonal expression. All questions should have only technically words and this is very bad!

Comment: @Mario No, I'm not saying that it must sound like anything. It's a requirement, it is what it is. "please" word also rarely makes sense in questions/post.

Comment: "Adding "thank you" to a post that doesn't adhere to site's standards is false courtesy."- my courtesy isn't false.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman If it's not, than surely you took time to get to know with site's standards - it's a polite thing to do, right? :)

Answer (score 85):

["Thanks in advantage"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+advantage%22) is now empty.

However, one editor in particular did not understand that when you mass clean-up posts you should be editing the *entire* post, not just removing a single line. I had to Reject and Edit quite a few suggested edits.

Comment: @Selcuk [Tanks](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q="Tanks+in+") in advancing

Comment: ["Thanks in advanced"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Thanks%20in%20advanced) will require a lot of cleaning.

Comment: @Izkata I just laughed when I found "[tanks in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966916/how-to-add-dynamically-radiobuttons-in-radiogroup-in-baseadapter)"

Comment: [Thanks in advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Thanks%20in%20advanced) has over 13k hits as of 2020-10-09

Comment: Really "[tanks in advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127391/how-to-find-and-draw-outer-line-of-image-in-opencv)". As for "Thanks in advanced", in [quoted variant](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+advanced%22) it has only 5k hits.

Comment: [Thank you in advantage](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thank+you+in+advantage%22) currently has 46 results.

Answer (score 48):

I'm glad [we fixed this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288197/2036035) specific permutation of thanks, but what about the million other combinations of thanks in advance? Thanks in advances (286), thanks advance (980) and thanks in advice (1247) are arguably just as bad or worse as advantage.  Are we really going to make a thread for each form of thanks in advance?

We've got (not even including all misspellings of *thanks!*):

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [Thanks in a advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20advance%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a dvance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20dvance%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%22%20-advance%20-dvance) | 1 |
| [Thanks in a dance and Happy new Year!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20dance%20and%20Happy%20new%20Year%21%22%20-advance%20-dvance) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a million](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20million%22%20-advance%20-dvance) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a demand](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20demand%22%20-advance%20-dvance) | 0 |
| [Thanks in adnance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20adnance%22%20-advance%20-dvance%20-part) | 0 |
| [Thanks in avdvance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20avdvance%22%20-advance%20-dvance%20-part) | 0 |
| [Thanks in adv](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+adv%22) | 592 |
| [Thanks in adva](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body%3A%22Thanks%20in%20adva*%22%20-advance%20-dvance%20-part) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advamce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advamce%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advaced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advaced%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advace](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advace%22%20) | 455 |
| [Thanks in advanvce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanvce%22%20) | 1 |
| [Thanks in advacnce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advacnce%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advantadge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advantadge%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advancee](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20Advancee%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advanca](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanca%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advacene](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advacene%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advanc](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advanc%22%20) | 3 |
| [Thanks in advaance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advaance%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advannced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advannced%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advances](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advances%22%20) | 284 |
| [Thanks in advahce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advahce%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advanve](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20Advanve%22%20) | 3 |
| [Thanks in advange](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advange%22%20) | 1 |
| [Thanks in advane](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advane%22%20) | 42 |
| [Thanks in advamnce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advamnce%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advacne](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advacne%22%20) | 5 |
| [Thanks in advandce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20advandce%22%20) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20in%20a%20advanced%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a lot advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20lot%20advance%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks in a lot in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20in%20a%20lot%20in%20advance%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20advanced%22) | 231 |
| [Thanks advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20advance%22) | 998 !!! |
| [Thanks alot in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20alot%20in%20advance%22) | 460 |
| [Thanks a lot in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20a%20lot%20in%20advance%22) | 10244 |
| [Thanks a lot in advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20a%20lot%20in%20advanced%22) | 182 |
| [Thanks a in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20a%20in%20advance%22) | 10 |
| [Thinks a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thinks%20a%20lot%22) | 8 |
| [Thinks in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thinks%20in%20advance%22) | 5 |
| [Thanks a lot in adv](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20a%20lot%20in%20adv%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks in advice](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+advice%22) | 1289 !!!!! |
| [Thanks i advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20i%20advance%22) | 52 |
| [thanks i advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20i%20advanced%22) | 0 |

If you want to go on a crusade to kill thanks, attacking only one form of a misspelling is *still* only going to be a drop in the bucket. Stack Overflow should probably give a notice to people trying to put thanks in their questions in the question wizard.

Tanks to Tiny Giant

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [Tanks in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tanks%20in%20advance%22) | 0 |

Thanxs to Oleg Valter

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [Thanx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Thanx%20in%20advance%20is%3Aquestion) | 5079 |

tx to oguz ismail

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [tx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tx%20in%20advance) | 387 |
| [thx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thx%20in%20advance) | 5590 |
| [10x in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=10x%20in%20advance) | 180 |
| [10q in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=10q%20in%20advance) | 2 |
| [tnks in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tnks%20in%20advance) | 0 |
| [thanku in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanku%20in%20advance) | 4 |
| [thank in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank%20in%20advance%22) | 4894 |

Thnaks to jps

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [Thanks for advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20for%20advanced%22) | 40 |
| [Thank for advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank%20for%20advanced%22) | 0 |
| [Thanks for the advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%20for%20the%20advance%22) | 1 |
| [thx for the advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thx%20for%20the%20advance%22) | 0 |
| [thnaks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thnaks) | 1236 |
| [Thanks by advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%20by%20advance%22) | 1095 |
| [Thx in forward](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thx%20in%20forward%22) | 4 |
| [Thanks beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+beforehand%22) | 867 |

Thnaks to [Peter Mortensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen)

| Permutation | Count |
| --- | --- |
| [Thnaks in adavance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thnaks+in+adavance%22&searchOn=3) | 0 |
| [Regards in Advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Regards+in+Advance%22&searchOn=3) | 122 |

Comment: Hard to search for, but I've also seen TIA in several posts as an abbreviation...

Comment: It's up to the 2K+ users to clean up the questions where the only problem is the (even misspelled) "thanks..." comments. A lot of reviewers will reject these edits despite the majority consensus on Meta. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24087600

Comment: And we have another candidate for the win with > 5K results: [Thanx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Thanx+in+advance+is%3Aquestion)! Isn't it beautiful how many permutations of three words can people make..?

Comment: [tx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tx+in+advance)(346), [thx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thx+in+advance)(5271), [10x in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=10x+in+advance)(171), [10q in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=10q+in+advance)(6), [tnks in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tnks+in+advance)(15), [thanku in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thanku+in+advance)(31), ["thank in advance"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+in+advance%22)(4511)

Comment: @oguzismail - oh, god... 10q in advance fixed (2 questions turned out to be valid, btw)

Comment: @Oleg yeah. I think this is a lost cause...

Comment: @oguzismail - yeah, without any (at least client-side) validation that is mostly a Sizyphian effort...

Comment: @OlegValter put the search phrase in "" to avoid false positives. Then you'll get only the full phrase and no hit if the post just contains all the words.

Comment: @jps - yeah, I know, just thought that surely there is only a negligible chance that somebody will use both 10x, q, and advance in a valid post, but apparently I was mistaken :) Also - thank you for curating the reference!

Comment: @OlegValter I see, SO never fails to surprise ;)

Comment: Maybe it is not statistically significant, but I stumbled upon the variation ["Thanks before"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61038167/revisions) (misspelled as *"Thank's before"*). Perhaps it can be used in a search.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - I would not call [thanks before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+before%22) insignificant with > 1K results :) Some are even sort of legit (Thanks! Before: ...)

Comment: Another variation encountered today (true typo, extra character): *[Thanks in advancve](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28972446/1)*

Comment: Another beauty encountered in the wild: ["Thank you ahead of time!!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984164/typescript-filter-tuple-type-by-an-arbitrary-type) :)

Comment: @OlegValter 100% indian without even looking at the profile

Comment: @10Rep - this is a risky statement even if you meant it as a joke given the modern sensibilities ;) On a more serious tone - am I missing something, or aren't they from Seattle?

Comment: @OlegValter considering sentence order and the fact that many indians (at least the ones I know) say that, I made the assumption. I could be wrong... they could be an indian from seattle, no? :)

Comment: @10Rep - won't argue, that's a possibility :)

Comment: The infestation is growing...

Comment: "Thanks advance" hmm, why no tanks advance?

Comment: Another one encountered today: *[Thnaks in adavance](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64618736/2)* (the question is less than one year old - by a 3,400-reputation-points user with more than 11 years of experience on Stack Overflow). It could either be due to typos or trying to fool filters. It is difficult to tell.

Comment: @PeterMortensen they are (were) not alone, there are (were) actually 2 more instances in the wild... Thnaks!

Comment: (I added some of it to [my list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html).)

Comment: Today's catch: "Any Help will be gretaly appreciated" (it's time we gave the "greatly appreciated" permutations their own category). I hope no one was on the receiving end of the appreciation.

Comment: Encountered today: *["Thank you for your eventually help"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406361)* (likely the same intent as *"Thanks in advance"*). The correct form is probably *"Thank you for your eventual help"*.

Comment: @OlegValter Unless the appreciator's name was Greta... ;)

Comment: I saw this one today: *"[Thanks for future answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703852/take-random-user-from-a-discord-server-in-discord-py)"* (*future* was misspelled)

Comment: Slightly related: [Corruption of another common phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66988748/1) - *"Any help would be appreciate it."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen no... now we need another table :)

Comment: Another variation: *"[Regards in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65874399/2)"* (without the weird capitalisation of words)

Comment: Another [*Thanks in advice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014047/add-client-certificate-to-net-core-httpclient/68848585#68848585) (2021-08-19. A question posted as an answer. Deleted now - only visible to 10K+ers).

Comment: An extended version: *[Thank you in advance for any future guidances.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68263038/2)*

Comment: It doesn't use the word *"advance"*, but it is the same meaning: "[Thanks for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69645020/1)" (*"Thanks"* was misspelt - deliberately? In any case, it is a variation that could be searched for. I have added it to [my list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#thanks))"

Comment: Another variation (probably by machine translation (like [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)) or manual word-for-word translation from French as it doesn't make much sense in English - other posts indicate this user is actually a French native speaker (code comments in French and the word *[ici](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ici#Adverb)*)): *[thank to answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122384/)* and *[thank to explications and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292140/)*.

Comment: Another *[thanks in adavance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228978/)* (listed here as *zero*).

Comment: Another variation: *[Thanks for advance.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27232241/2)*

Comment: An abbr. [encountered today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629818/error-importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application/48017426#48017426) (probably not that common, but there will be very few false positives if searched for): *[tnq](https://www.abbreviations.com/term/209451)* for *thank you*. (The answer is only visible with more than 10,000 reputation points.)

Comment: Does case matter? *[Thanks Advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888323/smtp-mail-issue-in-laravel-horizon-package)*

Comment: There are also abbrs: [T.I.A](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71725956/1). Though "TIA" is likely more common. "tia" is also a possibility.

Comment: Another variation: *[Thank you in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31168677/1)*

Comment: A variation of "thx in advance" (does case matter?): [Thx in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39120893/3)

Comment: Without "advance" (likely the same intent): *[Ty for the answers!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69521339/1)*, *[Thanks for the answers!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69521339/2)*, *[Ty for the help!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69846212/1)*, and *[Thanks for the help!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69846212/2)*.

Comment: Same intent (talking about the future): *[I appreciate all the following help!!](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21089/)*. I don't know if it is on Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: Another variation: *[thank you for looking at this in advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496778/retrive-objects-from-a-list-and-teleport-them-to-a-specific-location-in-unity)*

Comment: A variation: *[Regards in Advance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874399)*

Comment: The same intent: *"[\[I\] would be grateful for any intuition...](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65421161/1)"*

Comment: Another *"Thank you"* (hyphenated and exclaimed): *"[Thank-you in advance!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53104440/1)"*

Comment: Encountered today (same intent): *[Thanks in forward](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73918981/1)*

Comment: Same intent: *[Thank you upfront](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73757712/4)*

Comment: Same intent: *[Much thanks for your response!](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40409791/1)*

Comment: Another variation: *[thanks in advances](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17947380/1)*

Comment: Another variation: ***Thankx***  (*"[Thankx in advance for ur help](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35968352/1)"*)

Comment: I saw another instance of ***Thank's*** (but I lost the reference).

Comment: Possible obfuscation by a trailing "b" (a typo seems to be far-fetched): *"[Thank you in advanceb](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64467798/1)"*

Comment: Misspelling (likely typos) of "in" and "advance" at the same time: *"[Thanks un avance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77464263/creating-a-new-structure-with-the-family-object-in-fhir/77469843#77469843)"*

Comment: An abbr.: ***TYIA***, similar to *[TY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TY#Interjection)* (first observed organically outside of Stack Overflow). [A simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TYIA) indicates ***346 instances*** (I can't believe there are many false positives). Sometimes it is [even in titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76396852/looking-for-solution-to-cloudflare-cache-loading-serving-issue-tyia)!

Comment: [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60582162/1) of *Thanks beforehand*.

Comment: And a variation: *[Beforehand thank you very much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947256/is-there-any-way-to-use-biometric-sensor-to-show-your-fingerprint-ins-android-st)*

Comment: A variation: *[Thx in advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409611/fill-an-array-with-a-string-i-doknt-no-how-it-works-c-sharp)*

Comment: In the *appreciate* category (observed outside Stack Overflow): *[Any help/advice would be appretiated](https://www.reddit.com/r/Keychron/comments/1atpa1w/bought_two_keychron_k10_pros_same_brown_switches/)* (with two ***"t"*** s)

Comment: The exact same intent: *"[Thanks for the big help](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74109490/1)"*

Answer (score 47):

I agree with this strongly.

While, as others have said, it doesn't take away from the credibility of a post, it also does nothing for it.

This is not a forum, and it isn't run like one. This is a question-and-answer network whose focus is on the questions and the answers rather than the people. For that reason, "Thanks" and similar sign-offs and greetings are unnecessary noise.

---

If you're editing these posts and you need a little help  getting rid of the basic errors (including the one that is the subject of this post), the [Stack Exchange Editor's Toolkit](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) (disclaimer: I am the original author and primary maintainer) may be of interest to you.

It removes things like this:

> Thanks!
>
> THANKS!
>
> Thanks in advance.
>
> Thanks in advanced.
>
> Thanks [...]

It also corrects a lot of basic errors (`i` -> `I`, `cant` -> `can't`, etc.) and automatically generates an edit summary that reflects the changes that have been made. For example,

> 'JavaScript' is the proper capitalization; English contractions use apostrophes; 'Thanks in advance' is unnecessary noise.

Obviously, it is no substitute for *real* editing that a human can provide, and it should be used with caution, but it can help with a lot of basic errors that can be repetitive to fix, and it's expansible, so you can add rules if you wish.

Comment: Consider adding "Thank you" to that list.

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij It already is; here's the full expression: `/(thanks|pl(?:ease|z|s)\s+h[ea]lp|cheers|regards|thx|thank\s+you|my\s+first\s+question|kindly\shelp).*$/gmi`. You can test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/uG6yD7/2) to see what it'll match.

Comment: Hmmmm.....perhaps I'll try "thankss inn advvance"....

Comment: @tgm1024, Or [one of these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293655/thanks-in-advance-automatically-hint-user#comment190202_293655).

Comment: Just noticed a massive 30,691 times [Thanks in advice](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Thanks+in+advice). \*sigh\*

Comment: Nice user script. I just edited "thanks" out of about 70 questions (most of which are highly upvoted) in 20 minutes. But it would be nice if it also capitalized words at the beginning of sentences and removed signatures after "thanks".

Comment: Also, it would be nice if it worked on answers too.

Comment: I will disagree here because a "thanks" after a request is a good thing. In some context like: Please make this when answering followed by a "thanks" is natural. I totally agree with a lonely "thanks", without any requirement, this is a false "thanks", but the one with a request is more than necessary, otherwise the request will be like a command.

Comment: The toolkit button was getting displayed way off to the right for me. So far to the right it was behind the "New on Meta" sidebar. I fixed it by changing the spacing of the button from `430px` to `0`. Also the button totally breaks dark themes, so I commented out the animation. Now it still doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
    at Object.App.funcs.fixIt (<anonymous>:283:31)`

Comment: @JanSchultke unfortunately I stopped maintaining the script quite a while ago now, and I'm certain Stack Overflow has been through a number of design changes since, so I'm not surprised to hear it's no longer functioning. If you decide to investigate or fix it up, I welcome any pull requests on the GitHub repo.

Comment: [Too many of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63757271/14191957)

Comment: No matter how I tried, there is no more than 500 results in search on any of requests.

Answer (score 33):

We need a pop up that says something to the effect of

> If you want to show your appreciation to those that decide to aide
>   you, please `Up Vote` their answer(s) and select the `CheckMark` for
>   the one that answers your question the best! Rewarding a Bounty for a
>   particularly hard question or complex answer and explanation would be
>   even better!

any time someone types `Thank You` in a comment box or question box.

Comment: @Jarrod: "their answer(s)" or "useful answers"? The first can be seen as giving an A for effort, which you probably don't want...

Comment: ...But this would be using code formatting for words that are not code, which is also a Bad Thing (tm).

Comment: Why was this never implemented?

Answer (score 22):

Here's some more rather large ones to expound what @whn posted above.
Check out these *thanksters*

---

[thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks%22) (3.1 million..)

[please](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please%22) (2.4 million..)

[my question is](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=My+question+is) (419,877)

[sorry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sorry%22) (339,266)

[solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22solved+it%22) (77,582)

[yeah](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22yeah%22) (34,544)

['foo' 'bar'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22foo%22+%22bar%22) (26,128)

[thank you so much](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+you+so+much%22) (26,126)

[thank you for your time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+your+time%22) (16,163)

[thanks, everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks%2C+everyone%22) (15,127)

[lol](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22lol%22) (12,914)

[wow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22wow%22) (10,527)

[good question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22good+question%22) (8,591)

[bye](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bye%22) (6,481)

[haha](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22haha%22) (5,433)

[huh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22huh%22) (4,004)

[thanking you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanking+you%22) (2,481)

[very very very](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22very+very+very%22) (1,626)

[hehe](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hehe%22) (1,494)

[thanks please](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+please%22) (1,131)

[why are you doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22why+are+you+doing+this%22) (760)

[very good question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22very+good+question%22) (845)

[that was easy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22that+was+easy%22) (819)

[ahem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ahem%22) (818)

[thank god](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+god%22) (753)

[sure thing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sure+thing%22) (522)

[bye bye](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bye+bye%22) (483)

[thanks you so much](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+you+so+much%22) (443)

[thank so much](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+so+much%22) (499)

[oh man](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22oh+man%22) (437)

[sheesh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sheesh%22) (257)

[my pleasure](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22my+pleasure%22) (146)

[like totally](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22like+totally%22) (142)

[thanks for understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+for+understanding%22) (135)

[very very very very](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22very+very+very+very%22) (132)

[solved it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22solved+it+for+you%22) (48)

[har har](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22har+har%22) (47)

[gee thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22gee+thanks%22) (36)

[please upvote this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+upvote+this%22) (39)

[ok dude](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ok+dude%22) (24)

[I hope you like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+hope+you+like+this%22) (20)

[hohoho](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hohoho%22) (20)

[cash money](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22cash+money%22) (18)

[ooof](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ooof%22) (17)

[have to go to bed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22have+to+go+to+bed%22) (16)

[you betcha](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22you+betcha%22) (16)

[tee hee](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tee+hee%22) (15)

[I need to take a break](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+need+to+take+a+break%22) (10)

[I love your question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+love+your+question%22) (7)

[very very good question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22very+very+good+question%22) (4)

[thank you for youre time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+youre+time%22) (3)

[please downvote me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+downvote+me%22) (2)

[oofta](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22oofta%22) (1)

---

**thank yo**
[thank 'yo '](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yo+%22)​ (72)
[thank ya](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+ya%22) (32) 
[thank yoy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yoy%22) (20)
[thank ye](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+ye%22) (13) 
[thank yuo](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yuo%22) (9)
[thank yoh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yoh%22) (3)
[thank yoi](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yoi%22) (3)
[thank yor](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yor%22) (2)
[thank yot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yot%22) (1)
[thank yo0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yo0%22) (1) – hmm

---

**Hmm**
[hmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmm%22) (12,762)
[hmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmm%22) (5,066)
[hmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmm%22) (625)
[hmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmm%22) (106)
[hmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmm%22) (27)
[hmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmm%22) (18)
[hmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmm%22) (9)
[hmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmmm%22) (3)
[hmmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmmmm%22) (1)
[hmmmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmmmmm%22) (4)
[hmmmmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmmmmmm%22) (1)
[hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm%22) (2)
[hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm) (1)

---

**uhh**
[uhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uhh) (401)
[uhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhh%22) (110)
[uhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhh%22) (57)
[uhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhhh%22) (6)
[uhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhhhh%22) (7)
[uhhhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhhhhhh%22) (7)
[uhhhhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhhhhhhh%22) (1)
[uhhhhhhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22uhhhhhhhhhhh%22) (1)

**argh**
[argh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=argh) (1871) Many of these also refer to a lib of that name!
[arghh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghh) (92)
[arghhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhh) (86)
[arghhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhhh) (38)
[arghhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhhhh) (8)
[arghhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhhhhh) (1)
[arghhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhhhhhh) (4)
[arghhhhhhhhhhh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=arghhhhhhhhhhh) (1)

---

> you can only perform 30 searches in a 60 second window, please wait a moment and try again

---

We talk about 'thank you', but what about: `like, uhh, totally dude`. There's definitely many little 'daggers' that we say quite often.

I wonder why "thank you" can't be removed just like how we switched to `Common Mark`.

But I'm thinking that it might be tricky. It wouldn't be removed if enclosed in code for example: `foo = "thank you"`.

---

## July 2nd 2020

After taking a serious [poll](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bet+my%22), we've found what people on Stack Overflow bet on

Money (17)
Life (8)
House (6)
2 Cents (5)
Hat (5)
Bottom Dollar (4)
Dollars (2)
Last cent (2)
Two Balls (2)

Arm
Back
Bitcoins
Career
Coding Career
Dinner
Donkey
Families Farm
Fingers
Finger
First Born
Grandmother
Hard-Earned Money
Head
Hide
Last Dollar
Last Fiver
Left Arm
Left Shoe
Left Testicle
Lunch
Next Pay Check
Program's life
Python Teacher
Right Arm
Salary
Shirt
shoes
Teacher
Thoughts
Tiny Dollar
title
underwear

We also found things people *won't* bet on

life (19)
money (7)
business (2)
Project (2)

builds
career
Code
Computation
grades
graduation
Reputation
site
Socks
Thumbs
Robot

To our greatest surprise, some people seem to have a question when they post one:

[So I have a question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22So%20I%20have%20a%20question%22) 792 hits!

Comment: I hear "like totally" is legal in California.

Comment: How did you determine the phrases in the 1st list?

Comment: @philipxy I was thinking about random phrases similar to 'thanks' that people normally use. i.e. `lol`

Comment: We run in different crowds.

Comment: @0-1: <shock> People say "foo bar" instead of "thanks"? </shock>

Comment: [thank you for youre time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+you+for+youre+time%22) bites the dust. As does ["thank yo0"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yo0%22). And ["thank yot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thank+yot%22) too.

Comment: I laughed, laughed and laughed. Ty.

Comment: another phrase that I see almost daily but is hard to search is "So" at the begiining of a post, like in "So I have this problem...", "So I'm writing an app", "So I have a question"...

Comment: @jps - that warrants its own thread :) Bang bang, today's catch is thanks+: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+thanks%22 (in a better world this should count as serail thanking)

Comment: @OlegValter [Ok So](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22ok+so%22) you want me to create another thread, hmmmmm, [thanks a million](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thanks+a+million%22) for the idea it's [aperciated](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22aperciated%22), but no [thnaks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thnaks%22) ;-)

Comment: @jps [you are welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22you+are+welcome%22), [god bless you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22god+bless+you%22)!

Comment: @OlegValter [a lot of thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22a+lot+of+thanks%22) to you and all the [good people of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22good+people+of+Stackoverflow%22)

Comment: today's addition to the pure thanks list: [thankyou](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22thankyou%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) for treating bytes responsibly! *note that one needs to be careful as there are valid posts about Woocommerce

Answer (score -16):

IMHO, additional language like "please" and "thank you" or even the presumptuous "thanks in advance" won't detract from the credibility or usefulness of the content. Also, "thanks in advantage", while awful, is better than "I have class in 2 hrs, pls HELP!", let's keep in mind people who are new to coding, Stack Overflow, and the English language are not discouraged.

But, the proper attitude and decorum is encouraged, in an effort to maintain the credibility of Stack Exchange and its content/community.

What I feel DOES detract from credibility, and OP hit it spot on here, is the inaccuracy and in some cases stupidity (sorry) of some of the language used by posters and commenters/answerers.

If my boss asks me to show him where I found a solution, or who suggested it, I may have to forward a Stack Overflow post along. I absolutely don't want the title to have typos, or the comments to include trolling, or the proposed solutions to include "LMAO stop usin ur brackets here bro!!1!".

Considering please/thanks to be an informality is one thing, and that falls under the "environment" Stack Overflow wants to proliferate; trusting code from someone who says "kthxbai" when they address a community of peers for help is another thing entirely.

I'd say editing posts for accuracy and clarity is way more valuable to a user (at least one like me) than enforcing a "no salutation / appreciation" rule. In the worst of cases, if the informality of the language is so far below professional that it makes the poster/answerer unreliable, that should be addressed on a case by case (or user by user) basis.

*For the record: I've never edited a post on any Stack Exchange site, but I use it frequently for research and try to answer any posts I can. This is just the average user's opinion, not a habitual editor/administrator/superstacker.*

**Edit**

---

I wasn't going to include this in my original post because it seems snarky, but after following along for a while, I think it's a valid point: Everyone is linking to the other Meta discussion about "Should 'hi', 'thanks', taglines be removed...", but no one has linked to the Stack Overflow Help page titled ["How Do I Ask A Good Question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If the URL ends in "help/how-to-ask", users (new or old) should be confident that that's all they need to know before posting. Also, it says "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague..." in bold letters. I can confirm that a colleague, even if busy, appreciates a hello, a please, and a thank you.

This is turning more into a discussion over "what annoys habitual editors" rather than "is this a good procedure for Stack Overflow editors to follow".

Comment: The "busy colleague"-analogy only goes so far without elaboration. You should take the time to greet your colleague, and do the appropriate amount of additional chit-chat as well as making sure you are both up to speed on everything else you have in common (that might be quite fast, especially if you are actually busy). But when you get around to asking your question, peppering it with cajoling, self-denigration and irrelevancies will get anyone to either grit his teeth in frustration or drop you as fast as possible for something more worthwhile. Don't confuse your question with the rest.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed, completely. Extended salutations or appreciation are unproductive in almost every situation. I'm referring mainly to the "Hello all" or "Thanks a bunch" one-liners, and the minor impact they have (IMO) on the content. Completely agree though, very different from an unnecessary paragraph of ramblings.

Comment: Please also always keep in mind that the first one to three lines of a post are extremely precious space, though not quite as much as the title: They are shown as an excerpt when searching.

Comment: Also a very good point that I don't remember seeing brought up here. That just swayed me a little bit about trimming the hello line, especially if it's a `Hello,<br /><br />Here's my question:<br />` situation. Well played, @Deduplicator

Comment: This statement: "additional language like "please" and "thank you" or even the presumptuous "thanks in advance" won't detract from the credibility or usefulness of the content."  ***Correct.***  Actually, much of this would be solved by removing down votes entirely.

Comment: Let's Bring This Mother Down, lads!!
(coming from https://news.ycombinator.com/reply?id=16935949&goto=item%3Fid%3D16934942%2316935949)

Kidding, upvoting :)

Comment: Note the similarity to this answer (and it's -12 vote status yesterday) to the [blog post from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) admitting that it's not a very welcoming site

Comment: I'm actually upvoting this answer, because I think "not discouraging people" should get more attention in the usage of this site. Even though the site can do with a few less questions being asked and the questions that are asked can be better, that does not imply they should be discouraged from liking the site.

Answer (score -28):

Removing "thank you", but at the same time having the d-word in the title seems to contradict yourself. The d-word is not necessary, just as in your opinion "thank you is not necessary".

In my opinion, thank you is a basic expression of gratitude very suitable for any community.

In my opinion, if we try to cut "thank you" out of a community, we have lost something valuable.

I do agree with cleaning up excess or just a "+1" type of answer.

Comment: Fortunately, we still have "thank you" in this community. It just looks like this: ▲

Comment: Maybe so. But stackoverflow.com is not a community site; it is a community-driven site. From the outside, not from the inside. Here on meta and in the chat rooms we allow ourselves the opportunity to acknowledge each other as community members and is where some pleasantries have a place. On the main Q&A site however, we leave the community hat at the door and you put on the curator hat instead.

Comment: @CodyGray And  '⯅' is code for ...?

Comment: @Elise Uh, it's the upvote triangle: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2bc5/index.htm. Doesn't show up on the Windows 7 machine that I'm currently on, either. Sorry. I'm not usually a big fan of emojis and things that don't render universally, but I thought that one would be sufficiently universal.

Comment: Roel: Remember that this is meta.SO, not SO itself.

Comment: Thank you, but does it really matter? Are we not all civilized people who act better to each other?