# What is the preferred flag for "Thanks for your answer" comments?

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

I frequently come across comments in the form of something like this:

> Thanks for your answer. - someUser27 15 mins ago

What is the correct flag to use for these sorts of comments?

[image]

- not constructive
- too chatty
- no flag at all

Comment: I vote not constructive as they are adding nothing to the answer

Comment: I've always used "too chatty" which has always been accepted.

Comment: Why flag such a comment?

Comment: Because I'm not interested in shifting through 10 "thanks" comments on answers to find the ones that have value.

Comment: @LutzHorn Because Stack Exchange is a question & answer site, not a discussion board.  The correct way to thank someone for their answer is with an upvote or the accept check mark.  It works this way so that it is made as easy as possible for future visitors to determine which answers are considered best without having to sort through the comments.

Comment: Of course one should vote and accept good answers. But if this has been done, a nice comment by the OP doesn't hurt.

Comment: If the answer is accepted, I flag as obsolete

Comment: Well, @LutzHorn, for what it's worth, I just got three helpful flags in a row marking "Thanks for the answer" as *too chatty*.  There's not really much debate on whether or not these comments should be flagged.  I'm just curious what the best flag to use would be.

Comment: @LutzHorn since when are we nice?

Comment: "There's not really much debate" Then let's start such a debate. It is not obvious to me that such a comment must be flagged no matter what.

Comment: @rene I try to be 

Comment: @LutzHorn , See [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment). Also related: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)  and [No Thanks, Damn It!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) and many others.

Comment: related [Change "comment" to "critique or request clarification"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256967)

Comment: I usually flag "obsolete", and my flags have always been marked helpful.

Comment: The comment was _very_ offensive! It's obvious isn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For comments like that, either option is sensible from my perspective. I tend to be pretty relaxed about comment flags in general. Obsolete would even be reasonable if the comment was old and had clearly been read by the person it was intended for.

Watch out for the comments that are a mix of constructive feedback and a thanks as well though. Finally it's not worth hunting these out with SEDE queries just for the sake of finding them.

Comment: *"it's not worth hunting these out with SEDE queries just for the sake of finding them"*. But what if I did find a few and flagged them as obsolete, based on my judgement? Does that make my flags subject to be "declined"? I ask because I did try out the query thing and ended up with at least 8 of 10 flags declined. My guess is that the mods on my sites hate to deal with old stuff.

Comment: contd.. Also I think they know that I used the query because these 10 flags were timed so close to each other. I don't wish to ask on the respective meta because I fear that that will put me on a list of users they hate or something.

Comment: With the [change in comment flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352277/1497596), the appropriate flag for this situation would now simply be **"no longer needed."**