# Did comment flags just change?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

I don't see "Too chatty" or "Not constructive" any more. Is this a new thing, or did I just lose my ability to use those for some reason?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292011

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes, there has been an [open feature on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292011/drop-not-constructive-combine-noisy-reword-rude-and-other-comment-flag) to change the comment flag categories for some time. It was implemented today.

From [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/164200):

> This is the new UI for flagging comments:
>
> [image: rude or abusive, no longer needed, in need of moderator intervention]
>
> (for reference [this was the old UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHPyy.png))
>
> The first flag replaces the former "rude or offensive" flag; the last replaces "other". The middle flag - "no longer needed" - is new, and is intended to cover both "too chatty" and the non-abusive uses of "not constructive".
>
> Please [report any bugs here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug%20comments%20comment-flags), and blame Adam for pushing on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: aw, i miss having 23 bazillion radio buttons to choose from

Comment: @cat, I almost flagged your comment as "no longer needed", except it isn't obsolete and since you weren't that wordy, not chatty either. I don't feel abused nor that you were rude, so I'm guess with asking for a moderator to judge your comment! (I remember only seeing about 2 bazillion choices BTW.)

Comment: @dfd your eyes overflowed.  You need to rebuild them as 64-bit organs.

Comment: You have 100 flags!?

Comment: @programmer5000 [You get an extra flag per 2K rep or 10 net helpful flags.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/258777)

Comment: @cat Come now... changing *five* to *three* is hardly worth exaggerating to 23 bazillion...

Comment: I once came across a comment that was asking the answerer for help with a different SO question, which I flagged as "Not Constructive". How should such a comment be flagged now?

Comment: @ZacFaragher Sounds like that would fall in the 'no longer needed' category - this comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.

Comment: "No longer needed" is not an accurate description of what Shog's post says it's meant to be used for. Simply "Not needed" (or indeed "Not useful") would make a **lot** more sense. When I first ran into these, I thought a long time about what to choose for a non-abusive unconstructive comment. (According to the above, I got it right, but it was *never* needed, not *no longer* needed.)

Comment: Well, it could be argued it was needed exactly a fraction of a second, at the moment the OP wrote the comment so they can express themselves, then instantly became "no longer needed" as its purpose had been filled. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I pushed for that verbiage as well long ago and it never went anywhere :-(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We can bikeshed over the word for years, and [we did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252844/make-comment-flags-less-stupid). We purposely expanded the dialog to include a description instead of just the name of the flag to explain the purpose of it. If you feel the name of the category is wrong, then feel free to post a new feature over on MSE explaining what needs to be changed and why.

Comment: @bluefeet: That term is overused. It's not bikeshedding when something is objectively wrong. (And yes, adding the description was a good thing.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As I mentioned, we discussed the new terms for a long time going back and forth over what they should be called. Go ahead and post a feature request proposing new wording.

Comment: @bluefeet: [Okay, done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298507/new-no-longer-needed-flag-reason-title-is-incorrect).

Comment: I'm having difficulty choosing which option flag for a comment containing the infamous "RTFM". I personally don't like the newly reduced flagging options. It just leaves too much room for confusion. Which one should be used?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd suggest you [RTFMSEABS9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298507/new-no-longer-needed-flag-reason-title-is-incorrect) (read the fascinating meta stack exchange answer by Shog9) about this. I thought it was pretty enlightening as to the intent of the new simplified close reasons. I think based on that answer and the comments there I'd probably flag RTFMs as rude, where I probably would have used not constructive ("slightly desctructive") before.

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic actually I pinged him about it in another post and he responded. To which I got my answer, *cheers* Edit: Under [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292011/231583) in comments.