# How to flag everything?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-flags

Quoting from [Can the mods agree on how we should mass-flag comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911/can-the-mods-agree-on-how-we-should-mass-flag-comments):

> There are two possible ways to mass-flag obsolete (or otherwise deletion-worthy) comments on a post:
>
> - Raise an "Other" flag on the post noting that most/all of its comments are obsolete
> - Flag every single comment individually, waiting for the 5-second timeout between each one

That question links to some various different viewpoints on the right way to do it, and I think the answer there explains it pretty well.

Now that [comment flags are simpler](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352274/did-comment-flags-just-change), the repetitive nature of flagging a chain of noisy comments on a post with option 2 is much more evident. Unless there's a rude one, there's no need to try to decide which flag to use. They're all just "no longer needed". But with option 1, adding a custom mod flag that just says something like "all comments no longer needed" doesn't really seem very "custom".

I think it would be great if there was a way to select multiple (or all) comments on a post and apply the same non-custom flag to them in one request.

I don't know how comment flags work behind the scenes, so I don't really know how difficult it would be to implement something like that, even if people thought it was a good idea. Just thought I'd put the idea out there.

Also, regardless of whether or not people like the feature request, does the update to the comment flag reasons have any effect on the policy/mod preference toward which mass-flagging method we should use?

Comment: I'd rather they remove the 5 second throttle between flags. Often I want to flag only some of the comments, not all, and it feels stupid to stare at your screen and count the seconds in your head.

Comment: @Stijn Yeah, I know what you mean. Obviously my idea isn't very detailed, so something like that would probably work too, although I get why there are rate limits for things. Really just any modification that would allow us to get rid of blocks of comments more easily would be great in my opinion. I'd love to see them start getting treated more like the second-class citizens they theoretically are.

Comment: I was told by a mod, before this chance, that the break-off point to use individual flags or one flag on the post to nuke everything, is around 5.  I use a [userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/flag-comments.user.js) to cover the most common situations to get rid of all comments under a post.

Comment: @rene that script looks useful, thanks! I probably need to start using more stuff like that.

Comment: @Stijn 5-second interval is probably because anti-spam protection stuff or something.

Comment: Speaking of throttles, there was this good guy with N sock puppets (where N is a number larger than 5). I got throttled while deleting them. *You can perform this action in x seconds*. So technically, if you manage to generate sock puppets (create account, get 15 rep) at a very fast rate compared to what a moderator can delete because of the throttle, you can somehow save your reputation from being lost due to socks. (No, I'm not giving out ideas).

Comment: If the throttle would be, say, 12 flags per minute instead of 1 flag every 5 seconds, you could quickly flag a handful of comments, while still not being able script the automated flagging of everything.