# Should high-rep users be able to flag comments more often than every five seconds?

Tags: discussion

I do a lot of comment housekeeping. I've developed a routine to accommodate the five-second rule, but it's still annoying to have to wait to clean up a string of chatty, irrelevant comments from 2011.

Could/should high-rep users be given a more relaxed cadence for comment flagging?

Update: I've seen [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338911/can-the-mods-agree-on-how-we-should-mass-flag-comments) since posting, and it addresses handling long comment thread flagging to some extent. I'm not sure my question applies to that scenario. Let's assume 2-3 comments, where a post flag seems heavy-handed and cumbersome.

Comment: We don't need an exception or a different rate limit, rather the rate limiting should be "You can't cast more than X flags in Y minutes", with X and Y set such that legitimate usage rarely triggers it, but abusive usage would.

Comment: Does your routine involve the name of a US state? Just curious if it's similar to mine ;)

Comment: Also would like to mention my feature request related to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352524/how-to-flag-everything