# Why are the comment flags taking longer to be handled after the union?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

Before the great [comment rejig](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352277) my obsolete and too chatty flags used to get cleared within a day. Now I've been waiting for 2 days and they have yet to be handled.

I often flag comments left by those in the review on VLQ answers were the answer has been improved and the comment is no longer needed.

Has the new system made it harder for the moderators to clear the comments, instead of making it easier? (If yes, why, if no, then why are the flags taking longer to handle?)

I know that there's an election going on to increase mods, but this issue was never there in the run up to the elections and has only started after the rejig.

Comment: To all the people who had been complaining about being overwhelmed with choice: are you happy now?

Comment: It is also possible that the current election also adds traffic to generated flags from an overall increase in the use of moderation tools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes

Earlier there were separate queues for too-chatty (TC), obsolete (Obs) and non-constructive (NC). The NC ones needed a lot of time (around 20 seconds per flag), but the TC and Obs were easier to blow through. Hence we used to clear the TC and Obs first and then go through the NC (and used to have a lot of time for that). At the end of the day, we used to be left with around 50~100 flags.

Now, it's all in one huuuge pile (around 400 ATM). The "Thanks" and "I edited" comments are getting muddled between the other flags. Earlier they used to be in the TC and the Obs, respectively (and 5~6 seconds were enough to handle those).  When you see a list of "Thanks" in one area, you can just delete them one after the other, which is easy. Whereas now, you're seeing a "Thanks" and then another "long nonconstructive comment". So the brain's taking a harder time to parse "Thanks" in between those.

Should we revert to the old 3-tier system?

Nope, I disagree. The new single flag has its own set of advantages. It reduces the very noisy, "Possible Comment Abuse" flags which were taking a lot of time to handle. Apart from that, it's also easier on the flaggers side of stuff, so that they don't need to think a lot while flagging.

That said, I think it's just a matter of time when we get adjusted, but as of now, I feel that it's taking longer. So in the near future, once we are adjusted, we'll be handling them at the usual pace.

Apologies for the present, from our side.

Comment: "so that they don't need to think a lot" I'm scared every time I see that phrase in any context.

Comment: @Braiam, Do [edit] it and fix the sentence so that I don't need to think a lot about what's wrong with that ;)

Comment: @Braiam as a flagger you better strive to make moderators think as little as possible when handling your flags - this is better for everyone involved in the process. I once posted a comment here at MSO of how I am trying to picture to myself a moderator who is going to handle my flags and how that helps to make them work, it gained about 50 upvotes but was eventually deleted because that description was err... a bit too colorful

Comment: @gnat one thing is that both of you understand the same from the information transmitted, that allows both to not having to figure out what the other interprets from the flag, due common agreement. Another thing is that you mechanically flag stuff because that's how you do stuff, without even understanding why are you doing it.

Comment: [feature-request] use machine learning to give category hints to mods handling the comment flags. I'm sure it's possible to get a reasonable guess for a lot of the no-brainer cases.

Comment: Community user needs an upgrade.

Comment: @BoltClock so Skynet will be live in 6-8 then?

Comment: @JonClements the simplest way to stop Skynet is to submit its creation as a [meta-tag:feature-request] over here. Guarantees several years of keeping it ignored, especially if request gains lots of upvotes

Comment: Already looking into that, @Andras - that was the original motivator behind re-doing comment flags, lo these many years ago: make 'em easier to classify. Got a company that wants to make a product out of comment classification willing to help out, just need to gather data.

Comment: There's a confounding factor here too, @Bhargav: we're running an election. Whether because more folks are looking for stuff to flag, or because the flag dialog is easier to use, more comments have been flagged this week than in past weeks.