# Does Stack Overflow use machine learning for posts?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, spam, posting

I'm not exactly sure if this is appropriate for Meta but I was wondering if Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange in general uses some kind of machine learning for post classification such as spam or blatant no-effort questions. From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/332767), it doesn't seem like it. If not, are there specific reasons why not, and is it something that could be implemented in the future? The SEDE and data dumps seem like good resources for training a machine to do some basic filtering of low-quality posts.

Does Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange use machine learning for post classification and if not, are there specific reasons why?

Comment: Related in Uber Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically & in MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica.

Comment: I know a person who worked on StackOverflow to lure users into being more active by giving users (right) rewards, points based on their activity. It was done using machine learning and a person is a professor in one of top universities.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Stack Overflow doesn't do any Machine Learning as of now, but there are many projects which are on-going, like:

- The company is looking at handling the comment flags using Machine Learning

  > Already looking into that, @Andras - that was the original motivator behind re-doing comment flags, lo these many years ago: make 'em easier to classify. Got a company that wants to make a product out of comment classification willing to help out, just need to gather data. -
  >   [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352616/why-are-the-comment-flags-taking-longer-to-be-handled-after-the-union/352617#comment494962_352617)
- They are planning to work on using some technology to detect duplicates

  > We're launching an initiative with the University Of Melbourne in Australia. Some graduate studies have uncovered what (could) lead to much more precision in the detection of duplicate questions, as well as a huge improvement on what duplicates are suggested to the person asking. [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project)

Low Quality posts on Stack Overflow are detected based on a set of heuristics. When a user creates a question which is detected as low quality, they get a quality filter warning. (They can bypass it, but something ugly is going to happen after that).

Beyond this, I think only Stack Exchange can reveal more information about the projects which they're working on.

---

There are a few community driven projects which are doing almost similar to what you've mentioned in your post:

- **Spam**: The most famous of them all, [SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically) detects spam based on heuristics. You can [speak to the Charcoal Team](http://charcoal-se.org/) to know more about it. (Tanmay Bakshi, is looking into utilizing Machine Learning to detect spam. You can listen to his keynote here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAKc8QUdOOM.)
- **Low Quality Questions**: [FireAlarm](https://stackapps.com/questions/7183/firealarm-detecting-low-quality-questions-with-machine-learning) is another community based project, which uses Machine Learning (naive bayes) to detect bad questions and has been quite successful in doing so.
- **TooChatty/Obsolete Comments**: [Andy has been using Machine Learning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically), to flag nearly 100k comments. You can get more insights into his project [in his answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354723/).
- **Rude/Offensive Comments**: [Heat Detector](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat) is another project that detects rude comments based on Natural Language Processing. (Using a dataset which was [provided by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494/can-i-have-a-dump-of-rude-abusive-comments/327148#327148)). It also uses [Perspective API](https://www.perspectiveapi.com) to detect bad conversations.
- **Non-answers**: I have written [a small project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343065/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-non-answers-and-post-comments-on-them-automatica) to detect Non Answers based on heuristics. I have started to work on integrating Vowpal Wabbit, but have not made much progress.

<sup>Disclaimer: These are a very high level description of the projects which I've got a bit of knowledge about. I can't guarantee much about them. Do speak to their maintainers to know more.</sup>

As a moderator, I do see many many flags by a few users which are all of the same type. I do suspect that they're using ML as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the links! I knew about SD and Andy's projects but I was wondering if it was all probable in the future SO would actually integrate it.

Comment: @Li357, Pops, an ex-Community manager at Stack Exchange, was quite active in charcoal and had taken a lot of steps to look into integration of Smokey into the SE. For Andy's project, SE had initially planned to [run it on his account once he became a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292012/drop-noisy-comment-flags-from-the-moderator-queue-unless-an-answer-has-5-or-mo#comment948603_292060), however, the community disagreed with it . Now Shog is looking into utilizing ML, let's see how that goes!

Comment: I hope the machine learning will work out that for some questions, "Yes" and "No" are perfectly valid answers.

Comment: @MichaelKay There's an app that [writes full length answers](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-stack-exchange-posts) using Markov Chains.

Comment: "Stack Overflow doesn't do any Machine Learning as of now" Well you may believe this until we up your security clearance to a higher level >;-) What do you think makes @JonSkeet so successful?

Comment: @TylerH It's a well known fact that Jon Skeet is the only human and we're all his ML bots.