# Help center update needed for comment flagging

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, comment-flags

According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), one should be able to flag comments as:

> **Flagging a comment:**
>
> 1. rude or offensive
> 2. not constructive / off-topic
> 3. obsolete
> 4. too chatty

The options I have are:

> **I am flagging this comment as**
>
> 1. rude or abusive
> 2. no longer needed
> 3. in need of moderator intervention

Is that just my account, or does the help center need to be updated?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352274/did-comment-flags-just-change

Comment: Thanks!  I'll blame Adam.  :)  I didn't find that in Google or StackOverflow search or as a suggestion whilst I was writing this one.

Comment: Also related on Meta.SE: [One of two Help Center pages on flagging is incomplete and mostly redundant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233896/one-of-two-help-center-pages-on-flagging-is-incomplete-and-mostly-redundant/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In mid-July 2017, we updated [the comment flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352274/did-comment-flags-just-change) across the network.

We missed updating this section of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), but I've gone ahead and made the change this morning. Thanks for pointing it out.