# Add a "Not constructive" to the report method

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, comment-flags

This is mainly for the Mods.

I've noticed that the "report" on comments does not let you say "Not constructive". You have to report it to a moderator and hope they understand what you are trying to do.

This would be a nice tradeoff for both the mods and the users, as the mods do not have as much of their time wasted, and the users don't have to feel like they are wasting the mods time.

Even if there was an option that would notify the mods but not tell a user that, this would still help as users would be more inclined to report, as they do not think that they are notifying a mod.

This is different from the question [Did comment flags just change?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352274/did-comment-flags-just-change), as I am asking for a feature to be added, not confirming that something did indeed get removed.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am asking for a feature to be added, not confirming that it was removed. @Servy

Comment: Why would comments which are not constructive be needed, though?

Comment: That is the point. We are trying to remove them without the attention (or apparent attention) of the mods. We are still trying to remove them. @Makoto

Comment: great idea! I would use this "new old" flag for all comments that were posted under this question so far (including my own comment)

Comment: Um...mods are the ***only*** people around here that actually moderate comments, though.

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade Given that the duplicate explains precisely why the feature was removed, it answers your question as to why it should or should not be added.  The reason your feature won't be added is exactly the same as the reason it was removed, hence it answers your question.

Comment: What makoto is implying is that the no longer needed reason works for this. The not constructive option became... No longer needed.

Comment: Umm... Hello. Community bot. @Makoto

Comment: You misunderstand.  There are efforts to automate flagging and handling of comments, but right now, that only ever falls in the lap of moderators *period*.  If you want to support efforts or contribute to discussions in which moderators get *less* of these comments, you can start [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354719/1079354).

Comment: @Makoto Not all comment flags require moderator attention.  The comment can be auto-deleted by regular user flags, either if there are enough offensive flags, or if there are blacklisted words.  But none of that is relevant to whether or not a "not constructive" reason is added.

Comment: @Servy:  I was more attacking the motivation.  I'm more than well aware of the auto-deletion of certain comments, but if the motivation in this feature request is to somehow reduce the workload on mods by adding another flagging option...well, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me given that they intentionally *reduced* the options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you *mean* by "not constructive?"

[Merriam-Webster defines "constructive" as...](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constructive)

> 1. declared such by judicial construction or interpretation • *constructive* fraud
> 2. of or relating to construction or creation
> 3. promoting improvement or development • *constructive* criticism

Pretty sure #1 is out; we're not flagging all comments that haven't been the subject of a judicial ruling. Definition #2 seems implausible as well, unless we're gonna start flagging everything that doesn't contain *code*.

So... Number 3? You want to flag comments that don't promote improvement or development. Fine: use "no longer needed". The description - *"This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary."* - covers pretty much the same ground.

The problem with a flag *called* "not constructive" is that Merriam-Webster isn't the only source of definitions: there are other commonly-used interpretations that imply something a lot closer to "snarky, mean-spirited, destructive"... Which is a hell of a lot less benign than "fails to motivate improvement or development". So if *that's* what you're looking for, then use "rude or abusive".

Comment: Hitting my head with a book instead of a giant S...