# Edit plains my answer

Tags: discussion, edits

I created the answer below using bold for things I wanted to emphasize. Then *NobodyNada* edited my answer and made it plain and removed my personal style of the answer. (*"Hope that helps :)"*)

[image: Answer & its Edit]

Why the edit? Is it ok to rollback because his edit, except editing the *to*, *#* and *as*, feels like paternalism for me.

What do you think?

Comment: ["Thanks" and other noisy comments are preferably omitted to keep the entire post as useful as possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) .  As for the bold formatting, that's personal preference and (IMO) your formatting was fine (not excessive).

Comment: Why all the `<br>`?

Comment: I have edited some of your posts. You do have quite some fluff in your posts, like all the bold [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30813863/993547) and the repeated HTH.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah... that post is making my eyes bleed with that amount of bold text.  I'd probably actually edit that one.

Comment: Well, that is my style of formatting. It allows the reader to see the keywords in each step and quickly get through it without reading all my text. And again, all that paternalism. Can't people be at least a bit humane on here? I think *Thanks* and my *Hope that helps :)* just makes the site more friendly and it does not bother anyone.

Comment: See [this answer to "No Thanks, Damn It!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/288179#288179).  Basically, a lot of user view "thanks" as a __false courtesy__.

Comment: Use bold to emphasize. Not on a random word in every sentence. And this is what SE makes special: you can just find an answer, without going through all the fluff.

Comment: _quickly get through it_ - It's fine for the answer you have here but your answer that Patrick linked to is actually harder to read with that much bold text in it.

Comment: Thank you for being the only one that writes a constructive and friendly comment. @BSMP (Read it quickly before the others remove this comment :D)

Comment: @LinusG. This is meta, the threshold for deleting comments is much higher, so no worries :) Using bold for the names of actual menu items seems fine to me; on the other hand, the bold in things like "**Fill** in all the **data**", "**about half an hour**", and "**tap on the project file**", which don't refer to the names of menu items, I find distracting.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will take that into consideration next time :) @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: The bold is not too bad to me. It seems to bold the directions/important parts and not bold the little descriptions.