# Why was my recent question received so much worse than this very similar older question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374764/c-sharp-changing-tab-bar-icon-tint-programmatically, which was closed and downvoted. I got a lot of comments that I thought were unhelpful. I found a question a few years old with an almost identical structure, [Change tab bar tint color on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-ios-7?rq=1), that is open and highly upvoted, with favorable comments. I don't understand the difference in outcome. The asker of the other question has much more reputation than I do -- does this have an effect?

What should I have done done to elicit more respectful and meaningful responses to my question? (I am a new user and am trying to play by the rules.)

Comment: Here we go again... Please note the downvotes are likely disagreement (though this post's quality, while not terrible, leaves something to be desired).

Comment: No, it's just that new users aren't familiar with the policies and rules, and thus tend to ask less quality questions, and those get down- and close voted in turn.

Comment: In 2013 that was a question about a new technology, and the user in question might have been as new as you are now. In 2015, the situation is not the same.

Comment: For starters, you apparently did not search hard enough for the answer before you posted, since the answer was already here.  The disparity is less about new users than Time: the other question was asked almost 2 years ago.  Standards change as does the voting community.  Apparently the ios users were more tolerant.

Comment: Also note that attitudes have changed significantly over the two years between those questions being asked. The "super user" was a newb when they asked that as well.

Comment: Parker the "super user" had about 10 rep when they posted that question

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect classification of a "super user". NathanOliver, I'm so new to SO that i'm not even aware how you found that out.  And apparently I was supposed to know how drastically the standards change, I guess i'm sorry for not knowing that either... Id say most new users dont...

Comment: The majority of your other questions have gotten useful answers. This one question doesn't, and the site is discriminating against you and all new users? Chill out.

Comment: The issue of changing standards applies to this question and comparing a 2013 question to one today.  A new user need not know that, they do need to know/study/learn [Ask] if they want to participate

Comment: Josh Caswell, I am very chilled out thank you :) Yes most of my answers have gotten respectful and meaningful responses which is why I was so shocked that this one received such hate.

Comment: Thank you Plutonix for responding respectfully. I shall review the rules and guidelines before I post again!!

Comment: it is not "hate".  DVs are an indication that the post "lacks research" (it did) "or is not useful or is unclear".  Dont take it so personally.

Comment: Umm. so 'gimme teh codez' is disrepectful, but posting a bad question first and reviewing the rules and guidelines after is not?

Comment: Plutonix, what should I have done differently, how should I have phrased it differently to elicit more meaningful responses?

Comment: Incidentally, Googling your question title returns: 'About 132,000 results'.

Comment: Apologies @MartinJames I had not heard of that meme. I'm not offended and next question I will consult the rules more carefully. You said it was a bad question, what characteristics made it a bad question? i'm trying to improve lol...

Comment: A bit of a tip for your SO question, to add to what Josh commented on Makoto's answer: If you've already tried to figure out how to solve the problem yourself, tell us _what_ you've tried. Put in your question anything you've attempted so far, and why it didn't work. If you've already tried coding this yourself, you should show what you've got currently and any error messages you've gotten from it. This will help you get a better answer faster. (Also, "Thanks" is not needed in your question, and will likely be edited out by others. We thank people with accepts and upvotes here.)

Comment: Awesome thank you @Kendra . The whole purpose of this post was to find out what I was doing wrong, so thank you for helping me :)

Comment: You use non-relevant chit-chat like "Thank you in advance!!" to make your post more difficult to read and still wonder why people might downvote as unclear?

Comment: @Anthon at least it wasn't ["thanks in advanced" nor "thanks in advantage"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/839601) :)

Comment: @gnat It is amazing how removing fluff from posts often reduces the amount of spelling/grammar errors. If the posters would only write only question relevant stuff they can concentrate more on the readability of what they write.

Comment: @Anthon agree 200%. I think question in question would have much better chances to survive if it was halved to something like "How do I change the tint color of a tab bar icon image programmatically in C#? I'm using the Xamarin IDE and working on iOS." (not that it would look great mind you, but less calling for down and close votes)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compare and contrast the two questions.

The question that's massively upvoted reads:

> Does anyone know of a way to change the tint of a Tab Bar in iOS 7 from the default white with blue icons to another color tint with different color buttons?

Admittedly today it'd probably get the same visceral reaction, but if we contrast that with your question:

> How do I change the tint color of a tab bar icon image programmatically in c#? I'm using the xamarin ide and working on iOS. What code do I use and what file do I put it in? Thank you in advance!!

The difference is that the first question is asking for an approach, or a way to do it.  (It would likely be closed as "Too Broad" today, though.)  Your question is not only asking for an approach, but is also asking for source code, which is definitely not going to fly.

I would recommend against using older questions as examples of what's acceptable to ask, and focus on making your question as clear and as concise as possible.  The likelihood is that your question is just too broad, as you're asking for source code; if you could pare it down and provide what you've attempted to make this work, then it'd be a *better* question.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me respectfully and in detail. My intent wasn't to request source code, just to know what file to put it in (main.cs, appDelegate, viewcontroller.cs) as I am new to this and am a very inexperienced programmer.

Comment: Just removing "What code do I use and what file do I put it in?" would do a lot to improve the question. That to me is the key difference between these two. That makes it "What lets me configure this one bit of my UI?" -> "The method you need is `methodName:`/Use this two-line snippet" instead of "Teach me how to construct my program" -> "Uh, well, what do you know so far?". The work required of the answerers should be similar to the work expended by the asker. See also [jmac's puzzle analogy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/159251).

Comment: As bmargulies suggests in a comment above, timing played a huge role in how that original question was accepted. iOS 7 had just come out at that time, and a lot of people were struggling with this issue. I think no matter how that one was worded at the time, it would have been voted up. We're now two years from then, and the question has been answered in several places, so a little more might be needed to set your question apart from the others.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the "massive upvotes" on that question have [dribbled in over the 3 years that it's been visibile, showing up in search results](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18795117/timeline). It didn't pop into existence with a score of +46.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the titular question, no we aren't. New users just tend to post lower quality questions, and so get appropriate responses.

> How do I change the tint color of a tab bar icon image
>   programmatically in c#? I'm using the xamarin ide and working on iOS.
>   What code do I use and what file do I put it in? Thank you in
>   advance!!

That was the entirety of your question. It doesn't show any effort, and basically just asks for the entire working solution. These kinds of questions are **too broad** for Stack Overflow. We want questions that deal with programming problems, not asking for full feature implementations.

See here for more: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Also, it runs afool of [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @Deduplicator:  `:%s/afool/afoul`

Comment: @Deduplicator: Not according to any dictionaries I'm using.  Or even Oxford.