# Should I answer my own question in second person or in first person?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I was answering my own question Q&A-style ( posting both together) and ended up writing a phrase that was similar to this:

> Your problem was in X

Should I have written it as:

> My problem was in X

Or maybe in an even less personal way, like:

> The problem at hand is X

Is there any preferred or recommended form? Does it make a difference at all? I remember seeing all kinds in SO.

Comment: Depending on the question, writing an answer in the second person ("you") can be misconstrued as an attempt at using a sock puppet (e.g. "You are doing it wrong, this is how you should have done it"). We've received flags along those lines before, and back when sock puppets were merged instead of outright deleted, it really did end up creating situations like this. I'd advise against it.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, "you" may refer to the reader as opposed to the asker. [Sometimes, they mix.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for/246666#246666)

Comment: When I search for answers on SO to questions I have, I disregard answers written in first person, because they are generally highly specific and more of a hack than an actual useful answer to the problem.

Comment: I answer in the second person, mostly ironically but also to maintain the illusion. I've been monumentally bashed for doing so, by silly people.

Comment: Do I understand what's being asked here?  No, you don't, me.

Comment: He doesn't always answer his own questions, but when he does, he does it in the third person.  Stay thirsty my friends.

Comment: A similar question asked ~6 years later on MSE: [Should I say "You" to myself in self-answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363763/997587)

Answer (score 52):

This difference will hardly make the answer less understandable, so I guess that it's mostly a matter of personal preference and you shouldn't worry too much about it.

However, I would favour a second person perspective, because it doesn't matter that much who initially posted an answer, so long as it is well written and helps whoever stumbles upon it. There is some ambiguity in the sense that "you" may both refer to who asked the question and to anyone in general (e.g. "you should not divide by 0"), which may help readers to interpret what they read as general guidelines as opposed to specific ones.

You could say that it acknowledges the contributions of editors, as it removes the focus from a single person. I would also speculate that people often only notice that the OP answered his own question after they have read most of it (especially if the post is lengthy enough). So if there is some unconscious bias to like or dislike a self-answered post, it is only active after the reader has had a good basis to judge.

You might be worried that people will get distracted by someone talking to themselves (I, for one, do it: that's why I'm here). That is true, but in a worst case scenario someone might find it funny and your point will still get across.

Comment: +1 for cogent self-demonstration.

Comment: Good writeup. `You could say that it acknowledges the contributions of editors, as it removes the focus from a single person` completely agreed.

Comment: I agree, Pekka, as I always do with your highly insightful and witty comments. +1 to you, Sir.

Comment: The funny thing is I read this question and answer a couple of times before I realized it was asked and answered by the same person. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on BoltClock's comment under the question: if I answer my own question I always say so in an opening line and use the first person if I am not addressing the reader - then there is no ambiguity at all, and I can use both I or you if necessary.

*Edited to add*: On re-reading this I realize that I also put the opening comment in front as a sort of 'full disclosure', so that every reader knows what's going on.

Comment: _"I always say so in an opening line"_ That's noise and I'll edit it out if I see it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no, it clarifies why "I" is used in the answer and prevents confusion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I saw an edit in the review query that only removed that line, I would reject as No Improvement because it doesn't actually improve anything. Food for thought.

Comment: @jpmc26: It improves the signal-to-noise ratio. Food for thought.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *sigh* As evidenced by my activity on meta here, I am *strongly* opposed to rejecting edits because they "don't fix enough" as long as they represent real improvement. You have missed my point entirely: it is literally no improvement. The idea that "improving the signal to noise ratio" means obsessing over every last line of a post is equally dogmatic and absurd as insisting an edit must fix every problem in a post. I bet you would edit a post just to remove ["thank you,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288197/1394393) too. That clutters the activity queue. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26: I don't agree with your point. I'll thank you not to mistake that for me getting "confused". The review queues are not "cluttered" in the slightest. If you want to complain about something (the "sigh"), go spend some time in the close queue! In the meantime, help improve site quality. I'll never understand this "reject edits in the review queue unless they fix _all the things_ and introduce a way to solve world hunger" obsession some people have! I am not "obsessing over every last line". We are talking about removing one line that is, by definition, not required. Don't over-react.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Lines like "thank you" and "I'm answering my question" are not what signal to noise ratio is about. Signal-to-noise is about useless, poorly explained, poorly research questions that waste significant amounts of time. 500 ms skimming one of aforementioned lines is not the kind of "noise" we have to worry about. Forgive my response before; I was somewhat over the line and frustrated at being constantly misread by people who disagree with me. The response above answered something in your previous comment about edits that "don't fix enough" that has been edited out, though.

Comment: @jpmc26: Are you arguing against *ever* removing "thank you"/"I'm answering my question", or against *suggested* edits that *only* remove such verbiage? The former is solidly against resounding network consensus; the latter is generally somewhat accepted, but is in no way an argument against leaving out such noise in the first place.

Comment: Can you take this too chat?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I am arguing against removing them when that is the *only* thing that warrants an edit. In general, I would argue that if it's a edit suggestion that we should reject, then users with edit privileges shouldn't be making those edits either. (I.e., it shouldn't matter whether a user has the privilege. An edit should either be acceptable or not.) But yes, I agree that it doesn't really add anything and probably should be left out to begin with.