# Should we use “Any kind of help will be appreciable” in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, asking-questions

Many people write

> Any kind of help will be appreciable

in their questions. Is this allowable according to Stack Overflow policies and community? Should we remove this phrase from the question?

Comment: Not only is that not required, it's not grammatically correct.

Comment: It's grammatical, @jonrsharpe (aside from missing terminal punctuation), it just means something other than what's probably intended.

Comment: How did I end-up on ELU.se?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think it means that asker wants to say ["Thanks in advanced"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/839601) - if this extremely important bit is missing, any responsible editor should add it into the "question"

Comment: I'm glad the askers of these questions have a grasp of just how much work goes into answering a question. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Many people write
>
> > Any kind of help will be appreciable
>
> ...
>   Should we edit/ remove this phrase from the question?

Yes, just remove it.

It's pure noise like *"THX in advance"* or similar.

There's nothing essentially informational added to the question with this phrase.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this should be removed. [**Real questions have answers.**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) Encouraging partial answers or tips just promotes low quality off-handed responses.

Comment: That's a good aspect, though rephrasing/citing some of the essentials would make your answer better (in favor of just providing a link).