# Need option to reject Thank you edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, rejected-edits

As per:

[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)

Polite salutations are expected to be removed (edited) / rejected (as edit).

However, today in a queue I rejected an edit but, I think it would be more relevant if we had an option under reasons for rejection as "**Edit attempts to add a salutation / add a thank you note**", currently it is marked as per the screenshot below, which I reckon is the closest kin.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with "attempt to reply"?

Comment: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.".

Comment: It does not address to the author of the post.? It was an edit made *by* the OP...

Comment: _To_ another person's answer, otherwise the edit wouldn't have to be reviewed.

Comment: Oh well! I speak stats a lot and I like classifying things but if majority here thinks it is not required then I guess, be it.

Comment: Non-zero odds that it in fact *was* the OP.  Mayflies have a life-expectancy better than the average newbie SO account.

Comment: @HansPassant I ran into one of those where the person even had the [same username](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12500107)... Still waiting on my mod flag... :P

Comment: Closing this question because I see it to be an opinion based question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, this falls clearly under the category 'attempt to reply':

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post.

In my opinion, the rest of the description doesn't apply; this shouldn't even have been written as a comment. If a question/answer helps you, **upvote** it.

Comment: "If a question/answer helps you, upvote it." Please don't tell me, we are playing "why facebook doesn't have a dislike button!" We have a downvote too.