# Is there a way to prevent another user from editing your question if you disagree with their edits?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I requested that a question of mine be deleted yesterday, because another user had edited my question so much that it was no longer useful and was missing all context (although the user that did the editing swore he removed nothing of relevance).

The specific question I'm talking about is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34730649) ([<10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEnlK.jpg)) with the according [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34730649/revisions) ([<10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrK7Z.jpg)).

The question sat for almost six months before the mentioned user started editing it and removing all of what I believed to be relevant information.

As I am unfamiliar with all of the user features at Stack Overflow, I asked  the user to please restore the question to how it looked prior to his edit (I was unaware of the ability to see the revisions and rollback the edit to a previous version at this point).

He flat out refused and insisted that despite removing 680 words and including my appreciation for fellow Stack Overflow users' assistance in figuring out my issue, that he had not removed anything of value.

After feeling that my question was never going to be left alone or restored to its original content, in desperation, I submitted a request to have the entire question deleted. If I had been able to lock the question so the specific user couldn't edit it any further or even receive any additional answers, I would have done that instead to leave the original question and the best answer available for future users to see and read.

Is there any way to do that? To lock the question from not SO Admin users from editing it or to mark it as answered so no additional edits can be done?

Comment: It's basically impossible for normal users to single out specific user to block.  SO is community maintained, so being able to block people would go against the paradigm of SO.

Comment: Also, since the question has been deleted, those of us with <10k rep can't actually see what happened.

Comment: [Thanks, but no "thanks"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/603977).

Comment: @ryanyuyu [*You can give me an ice cream for that?*](http://imgur.com/DC6ekaR)

Comment: @Rizier123 you can even get a cherry on top if I can see the diff for a previous revision.

Comment: The entire "Background" section appears to be utterly irrelevant to understanding or solving the technical problem, and so removing it makes it more likely that anyone's going to actually read and try to answer your post. The section that you titled "Problem", on the other hand, seems like it should probably have been kept.

Comment: I totally agree with @JoshCaswell . We can also word this differently and say: On Stack Overflow we don't want to read a story book. We want a clear question/problem, best with some little code as possible to reproduce the problem and see the attempts which you made to try to fix it and where you are stuck now.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Can I prevent others from editing my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28005) and the FAQ [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576)

Comment: I'm very tempted to edit at least four of the five mentions of my username out of this post, but I'll try and not to edit this post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu [*You know I love cherry's.*](http://imgur.com/WG6FhlA)

Comment: My intent, @JoshCaswell was to be as thorough as possible in explaining how I had arrived at the error message. As a former Tier II Deskside Support Specialist, I hated to receive tickets that simply said, "The internet doesn't work." or similarly short descriptions of the problem with no explanation of how the user had arrived at the problem. This often meant I needed to repeat previous Technicians' steps to recreate the problem and determine which solutions may have already been tried and failed. If the question had been edited more as you suggest, I wouldn't have had a complaint about it.

Comment: Your intentions were good, no one is doubting that. And the edit was kinda harsh. But if an experienced user thinks the error message is enough to diagnose and solve the problem, maybe give it a go

Comment: @mittra Keyword here is "recreate". A question should contain everything, that everyone who comes by should be able to understand and recreate your problem fast and easy. So the question should contain everything needed for that, but also be as compact as possible, since no one likes to read 10 paragraphs.

Comment: anyways, the question should have been closed for `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.` and that would be the end of story my friends....

Comment: ETA of fix?

4 more to go

Answer (score 8):

Being the blamed one I don't really think I should be a party in this discussion, but on the other hand, I want to defend myself and explain my point of view, to save others from the hassle of finding out what the hell I did and why.

Summarized, your question came down to this:

> An external company developed an ASP.NET application (at least, I think, given the .aspx extension) for us. I messed with the database, and now when we execute a certain action in this application, we get an exception: [stack trace]. When we report bugs to this company, we want to provide as much detail as we can. We do not have access to the code. What can cause this error?

Now in whatever way you read the original version of that question, there is not a single bit of additional information in there that adds anything to that problem statement.

I opened the question because some user suddenly posted an answer five months later, giving you some debugging hints - but not a definitive answer. I successively edited the question so that only the relevant parts remained, so other users who stumbled upon it after me didn't have to wade through the same wall of text to come to the same conclusion as I, namely that the question as posted (at whichever revision!) is unanswerable.

Like I said in one of my comments:

> Stack Overflow is not *"throw debugging hints at me and I'll figure it out"*, for that you'll need to find a programming forum that allows such posts. Stack Overflow is about questions containing all relevant details needed to solve a problem, and answers giving the answer to that problem. That is because questions must also be useful to later visitors. See also the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Now to answer this question's title: no, you can't deny other users their editing privileges. Any user with over 2000 reputation points can edit whatever they want, and if you think they did wrong, open a Meta question (asking about that specific edit, not about denying their edit privileges entirely) or flag the post for moderator attention.

So all in all: was my edit a dick move and could I have spent more effort to retain the flimsiest bits of additional information that was hidden in all of that text I removed? Maybe. Was your question answerable or on-topic? No, not in any revision.

Comment: I mean, I don't necessarily think there was enough information in any version of the question to properly answer it. That said, you did remove some context which in my opinion did make it at least closer to being answerable. Specifically: *the *.aspx extension for all of the pages in the program). The backend is SQL Server 2008 R2. The program is a facility asset management planning software, so it tracks in order of hierarchy: Organization, Site, Complex, Building, System, Component, and Section.*

Comment: That aside, when someone changes your edit, by rollback or otherwise, editing another time is essentially starting an edit war. While this user seems to have looked for help elsewhere that type of behavior is very combative and can lead to negative situations.

Comment: @Travis the information about the technology used was already mentioned by the tags, which I did not touch, and the hierarchy of entities used in the application doesn't have to relate to the problem in any obvious way. I could have let those bits in, and the question might have been marginally better, but still off-topic. Also, the edit by the OP after that added a complaint about my edit, which did not add anything to the question. I'm not happy with what happened altogether, but I definitely didn't remove anything of value.

Comment: anyways, the question should have been closed for `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.` and that would be the end of story my friends....

Comment: I agree on both sides here, You didn't really remove anything of direct importance but you did remove some information about what the op has tried so far to resolve their issue. So yes, most of the background should have been removed and No your edit wasn't a dick move - if it wasn't for this meta question, I wouldn't have bothered reading it