# Someone edited my answer seemingly to promote their own; what action should I take?

Tags: support, edits, answers

If someone edits my answer, and rather than improving it (from my perspective), only appears to purposely promote their own answer, what action should I take?

Comment: How does someone editing your answer result in him upvoting his own answer?

Comment: Members can not upvote their own answers

Comment: I think what he means there is that someone defaced his answer to get more upvotes on their own. (EDIT: that was not defacing, he turned a fiddle into a SO snippet)

Comment: the person was not making your code "worse" but just using the stackoverflow snippets instead of an external viewer. How is that "misuse"?

Comment: That makes quite a bit more sense, @LucasTrzesniewski

Comment: Side note: you answer contains unrelated thank you notes like "Plz" (which  is neither word nor useful to the post). If you are not sure if you post provides the answer - post it as comment, otherwise avoid text not related to the question as well as using incomplete/non-English text. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it for more discussion.

Answer (score 17):

If a person defaces your answer, you can rollback the edit. If it happens multiple times, flag your post for moderator attention.

---

Let's discuss [the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088875/loader-inside-a-table-td/40089344#40089344), though. The person rendered your JSFiddle link obsolete by transforming your answer into a working code snippet, a good thing! They also took the time to explain their reasoning for the edit, after you requested an explanation:

> For the same reasons StackOverflow asks people to post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples instead of linking to a website or to code offsite. By keeping everything contained on SO future visitors don't have to worry about external resources not being available in the future. Your code now runs in a snippet exclusively on StackOverflow. Your example is very simple and within the capabilities of a SO Code Snippet. Though there are times where JSFiddle/CodePen is more capable than a SO Code Snippet and would be used instead.

So nothing bad to see here, it was a good edit.

Comment: It is not *necessarily* a good thing. I've had answers that started as stack snippets that I ended up having to move to an external site due to limitations in what the snippets support. It **can** amount to defacement if an answer that worked no longer works.

Comment: @Louis Fair point. I've replaced 'a code snippet' with 'a working code snippet'.

Comment: While I agree that adding the Snippet is a good edit, there was no particular reason to edit OUT the JSFiddle link. I have done similar edits (usually to questions) but I do feel that the JSfiddle/Codepen/Whatever link would be better left untouched.