# Expressing feelings about closure of a question at the top of the post

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

What happens if I post a question on Stack Overflow and start it with stuff like,

> I'm afraid this question may be probably closed! Because the program
>   that I'm going to make is really nonsense, and I'm getting help for
>   that!

Or,

> My question may be regarded as a request for making something
>   impossible into something possible, and I need help to
>   programmatically do extraordinary things which are out of abilities of
>   Windows! But I'd like to get an answer before getting my question
>   closed. At least read it before you vote it down!

Actually, I haven't ever seen this stuff at the top of any posts. In fact, is it really disreputable or do people avoid this only to preserve their credibility?

Comment: For what it's worth, I edit meta-content like that out whenever I see it. If someone thinks what they're posting is bad, they should either improve it or not post it.

Comment: You probably haven't seen stuff like that because either it gets edited out, or questions like it get deleted. Stating things like _at least read it before you vote it down_ is plain counterproductive and assumes the people that vote usually do so without properly assessing the question.

Comment: That's just noise for your question. Always remember: when you post here, you post for posterity, for the 10000s of other users who will Google, then find your question. Does having that note make your question a better resource for them? no? Then you likely shouldn't have that note

Comment: It is a feeble attempt at creating sympathy for the question, even when the questioner already knows it is junk or not useful to anybody.  It doesn't work, significant odds it has the exact opposite effect.

Comment: Very closely related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If someone expresses these sentiments, that they know that their question is not up to site quality standards, then they shouldn't post a question until they can improve it such that it's up to standards.

But also relevant, only information relevant to the actual problem and question should be in the post. This sort of text is nothing but distracting "fluff", and text like this will only invite down-votes and close votes, and therefore is best left out. Begging to "please don't down-vote..." **will** have the opposite effect as intended, and we've seen this time and again.

As Jon Sharpe states in comments, if you see something like this, edit it out of the question since doing so will improve the quality of the question and will help the original poster in their quest for an answer.

Comment: IMO, similar rules apply for an answer beginning, `Welcome to SO! It's fantastic to see you've got this far and you've understood how to <repeat parts of question>. It's also nice of you to ask SO when you got stuck. Please give us more information so we can answer properly. Now, if I assume XYZ, you can do this....`

Answer (score 3):

A disclaimer would only be useful if presented actual evidence for the question not being closable.

Harder to do in cases of the question being "too broad" or "unclear" (the question itself should be disclaimer enough), but could be appropriate in cases to avoid duplicate closure.

But even then, the disclaimers should be clear and specific. "Answers to X question are not useful to me because of this constraint and that environment".

Otherwise, that kind of meta commentary is as useful as *"I'm new with this technology"* or *"Learning this programming language"*, and should be edited out on sight.