# General guidance on editing questions, and some specific cases I have questions about

Tags: discussion

I now have the right to review edits to questions.  I’d really like to help to improve question quality, and I want to do it **The Right Way**.  I don’t wish to provide opinion as to what edits I should reject or allow.  I’m happy to do whatever the consensus is. I want to try to gather that consensus into my own brain.

So where can I get information about specifics of what kinds of edits are good, what are bad, and what just don't matter either way?

I had put some specific questions together in my post here, but I got flamed for using backticks and the discussion got stuck there.  I just learned despite using SO to ask questions for many years that using backticks for non-code is verboten.  Ok...so I've got that now.  I edited my post.  Not a single backtick here now.

But then I was given links that I thought would answer my primary question. 
You can see them in the comments.  But I guess those were all about backticks and about not asking **this question** correctly.  From my reading, these don't answer my general question or my specific ones. I'm still as in the dark as when I started.

If someone can point me to information that shows how to properly review and accept/deny/modify edits, I would greatly appreciate it.  I LOVE S.O., and I want it to be as high quality a resource is possible.  I just want to help, and I know that I can.

Is there a forum for discussion of right and wrong regarding editing questions?  I thought this might be it, but so far, I don't see that working here.  Should I post my questions again here, without backticks?

---

UPDATE - tentatively trying again to ask more fully my original question, since nobody seems to have voiced a problem with the idea of my post...just the formatting...

So this is my attempt to get consensus on the first few head scratchers I’ve come across, and also solicit general advice, be it new information or pointers to existing SO material.  I’ve pushed through (approving as is or not) a dozen or so questions so far...just ones I was pretty sure about.

First of all, is there good information I should have reviewed before asking these questions?  I went to the SO Meta Help Center, and tried a bunch of searches like “guidance on editing questions”, “how to edit questions”, etc., and I didn’t find any generally useful posts.  I was hoping to find something that listed simple and common edit types, and suggested how to deal with them.  If I’ve just missed such available information, I’d be happy to do more reading and repost this set of questions as necessary.

In reading what I have found on editing questions, it seems that a distinction is made between making trivial edits for their own sake and making such edits as part of a larger editing task.  I get this.  Please assume that all of these issues are edits I’ve come across in a question where the editor has made other edits that I believe are valuable and should be applied.  I’m not looking to spend time on minor textual issues that won’t substantially improve the question.

Finally, I'll say that a valid response to this is, I suppose, "You're being too anal.  Just do whatever you think is best.  We're not that picky about edits around here."  I'm also fine if the questions below are only valuable in that they demonstrate what I'm trying to learn here.  If there's no one "right answer" to these, I get that.  But the, how do I learn to make my own best decisions about these sorts of calls?

**1) Three times I’ve seen introductory text like (paraphrased) "I need some help with my homework…." or "I’m working on a project for my work`or`I am new on StackOverflow and would like to get some help". removed.**

A) accept as is

B) put the text back in, improving it grammatically as necessary

C) no change

**2) The editor is mostly making a judgement call on a particular coding style or idiom.**

**Original:**

`sum= sum + num*cost;`

**Suggested Edit:**

`sum += num*cost;`

A) accept as is

B) or make very minimal formatting change:  `sum = sum + num*cost;`

C) no change

**3) Original:**

`System.out.println("all costs are "+ cost);`

**It is pretty clear that ‘cost’ is not the quantity the OP meant to be printing here, but rather ‘sum’, despite the variable name.`.  Does it make any difference if it’s a syntax error or just a logic error?**

**Suggested Edit:**

`System.out.println("all costs are "+ sum);`

A) accept

B) no change

**4) Chunks of code have been added that don’t, IMO, add much or anything to the question.**

A) accept

B) no change

**5) The OP pasted a paragraph of unformatted error output of 15-20 lines into his post.  The main issue, IMO, was just that the error got mixed up with the rest of his question.  The editor chose to put the error in a code block.  In this case, the error was all on one line, so now you had a code block with a single line containing 15-20 lines worth of stuff that scrolled off to the right. That seems to me like a step backwards.**

A) accept

B) Put error text in a quote block so that it stands out from the rest of the question but still wraps so you can read it all without scrolling.

C) no change

**6) Editor changes a visible URL into “web link text” with the URL behind it.  In some cases, they use text that existed already in the question and attach the URL to that text, and in some cases they replace the URL with new text.**

A) accept

B) accept if the URL is replaced with new summary text, but change the edit if the editor chose to put the URL behind existing text and that seems to hide the URL or obscure its purpose

C) no change

**7) Editor has in some way highlighted certain keywords, variable names, etc.  Usually, this is done with backticks.  The edits are arguably an improvement.**

A) accept

B) accept, but replace backticks with ???? (I honestly don't know what the alternative is.  Bold maybe.)

C) no change

Comment: \*Wants to know how to correctly edit posts\* \*use code formatting for non-code\* I would start by not using backticks.

Comment: Are you suggesting searches I should have done?  I have not formatted anything in this post "as code" given my understanding of what that means.

Regarding backticks...can you please elaborate?  This one isn't at all obvious to me.  Others seem to use backticks a lot, in questions, answers, and comments.  I recall seeing high-score veterans us a lot of backticks. - I assume you're critiquing my own post, so I'm looking back at it quite critically.  I don't see issues with it.  It seems very readable to me.  (I'm quite happy to use my own post as a learning tool...I AM listening)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Braiam is pointing out that backticks should be used for code, not for normal text, but he's phrased his comment as if it were a meme.

Comment: That document has exactly ONE reference to backticks under a section named "Inline Code".  It says nothing about backticks being EXCLUSIVELY for this use.  It just shows how to format Inline Code.  That's all it's saying.  I can read.  C'mon guys.  And I'm willing to learn to do things differently here.  I can take criticism.  So tell me how to improve my post.  Just saying "don't use backticks" gives me no incentive to improve, especially because I see no evidence yet that this is other than arbitrary opinion.  Show me where it says backticks are to be used ONLY for code.

Comment: Please don't flare up like that. I clicked on your question, saw Braiam's comment, saw your confusion about the comment and tried to clarify. Sure, here's a reference: [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/363946).

Comment: Also [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990)

Comment: I'm not flaring up.  I'm asking for constructive criticism.  All I was asking for was the link you just provided.  That's it.  I just want a criticism to come with some reasoning behind it.  I made it clear I a) want to do things right, b) want to learn, and c) don't want to form my own opinions.  I just wanted to know WHY what I'm being told is correct.  I also wonder why I'm just coming across this now after years of being here.  Your link gives me some of that.  Thank you!

Comment: The formatting has already an specified use according to the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/index.html). The browser is expected to behave differently according to semantics elements, and the <code> tag means something very specific to the browers (ergo to the reader). The markdown syntax is a implementation of these tags that looks good even in plain text, their semantically meaning didn't change. **Use formatting very sparingly and only when you need it to make your post easier to read.**

Comment: I'm getting all of this.  Sucking it in actually!  This is what I wanted right away.  That's all I was saying.  Thanks!   So what's the alternative?  Looking at my text above, should I do anything more than remove the backticks?  And what about the bold text...is that ok?  (BTW, I'm a back end guy.  HTML convention means nothing to me as I'm not familiar with it, and there's nothing wrong with that)

Comment: "to know WHY what I'm" the use of caps for WHY implies that you are shouting the word WHY. That's why when you shouted at me "ONE", "EXCLUSIVELY " and "ONLY", I called it flaring up, because there was no reason to shout at me. I wasn't even criticizing, I was clarifying someone else's criticism. This comment that I'm writing now is criticism, and it is constructive.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits read 10-20 of those... This will help you to improve your question so it does not look like you did not do any research prior asking. And also read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/137755/5 This is one of the post that should have been read.

Comment: Yes...I "screamed" 3 words.  I still feel very strongly that pointing me to that particular link did no good, and I wanted to make that clear.  I was a little miffed at being corrected by something that doesn't correct me.

Comment: Great!  These are the posts I wanted...the real reason for this.  I said at the beginning that I would be happy to take this whole thing down if I'd just missed links I should have read.  I'd just say that I'm pretty good at Googling and using search features on sites, and those didn't come to me from Help Center despite a bunch of trying.

Comment: btw, @DavyM, I was "shouting" at Tom, not you.  It was only that, IMO, useless link that I was upset about.

Comment: By the way, you did the right thing asking here. Knowing how to correctly review is important; I'm glad you asked before you started mindlessly reviewing and editing, despite all the discouraging downvotes.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard - Thanks!  I won't comment on any of the past business except to say that I thought my intentions were good, and that that would have counted for more. - so what about learning how to properly edit questions?  Any suggestions? - I guess one thing I definitely learned is "don't approve edits that add the wrong backticks!", LOL

Comment: @Steve, don't let the meta get you down, it can be a bit of a contact sport.  While this question is much less broad than when I voted to close, it is still somewhat  open ended.  I would suggest using the link Alexi gave for the meta search, sorted by votes and then spending some time reading. It is my impression that there is much contradictory opinion on exactly what is correct, but you will get the gist pretty quickly.  When I first started I spent a lot of time going back to my review history to see how much/little I agreed with the other reviewers.  Good Luck.

Comment: @StephenRauch - Thanks.  I'll do whatever I can to learn more by learning to review existing edits and see what others have done. Is that THE answer here?  The particular issues I raise aren't worth me trying to get feedback on?   I'm frankly much more scared of editing other people's questions incorrectly than I am about what faux pas I might make in **this post**.  So I persist...

Comment: [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Dude!  This is great!  This is a source finally that answers at least some of my questions.  I haven't had time to go through it yet, but this will definitely be helpful. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Using capital letters for inline emphasis (I [wouldn't call it shouting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing), though - it is supposed to be every letter in a sentence) may have been necessary on older antiquated systems ([typewriters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter)(?), some forum software(?), some [CRT terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals), etc.), but on Stack Exchange we have **bold** and *italics* for that, including in comments. Forum culture does not translate well to Stack Exchange - it is best to simply forget all about it.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen.  It's as you imply, I'm old school.  I've used caps in all my writing for decades just to emphasize certain words like if I was speaking the text.  That's all I was doing.  But if **bold** is better, I'm all about doing things as "the right way" as possible.  This whole was so wrong, IMO, because nobody took my intent into account.  I thought I was being so ultimately humble.  So why basically ridicule me for using the wrong form of emphasis on my words, and make not attempt to address my actual question.  Anyway...I got one good link and hope to run across a few more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HereticMonkey, I've found [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303219/215552), a place that answers some of my questions, or leads me in a direction where I have confidence to extrapolate and answer them.  So here are the questions I posed that I now think I can answer, per this post:

#1 = A, per the "Remove all noise" section

#3 = A if the change is not germane to the question, B if it is or if you're not sure, per "Don't edit code in questions unless..."

#5 = B, this one isn't discussed explicitly, but I'm confident that B makes the question more readable and clear, and so per "Make your edits as complete as possible"

#7 = Usually C, B very sparingly and carefully, per "Use emphasis sparingly"

PLEASE! Keep the suggested reading coming, as well as any specific suggestions you might want to provide.