# I have a screenshot that I think is from a software package. Would it be appropriate to post it in the hope that someone can identify it?

Tags: discussion

It's from a rules-engine I believe, so would tag it appropriately.

Comment: If you can identify it with some SO tag the chat room of those tags should be the best fit.
I don't see an use for Software Identification Tag like on SciFi

Comment: Hmm.  I've never used the chat.  I'll give it a look.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We get lots of questions like that

```
What software is this?
[screenshot]
Thanks in a dance
```

Questions like this aren't really answerable, unless you get really *really* lucky that some passerby clicks into and recognizes it. The problem is that since you don't know enough about it, it's hard to attract someone who does. That's why I vote to close questions like that.

Comment: Also note that, if someone happens to recognize it, it's still of 0 value for anyone but the OP, since the question text doesn't really identify anything about the software so people with the same question can't find it.

Comment: "Thanks in a dance." [Good grief. :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siG14.png)

Comment: @TrebledJ Oh, it's [much worse than that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385424/2370483)

Comment: "Tanks in a dance" has a nicer mental image :)

Comment: Not exactly the same, but *["Thanks since now."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435420/get-current-location-and-draw-route-with-mapbox)*