# Is starting an answer with "Welcome to Stack Overflow" discouraged?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, welcoming

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697525/discord-bot-move-channel-position/63704771#63704771) on a question asked by a new Stack Overflow user. Since the Stack Overflow user was new, I decided to start my answer with “Welcome to Stack Overflow!”.

However, my answer was later edited to remove that line. I was wondering if welcoming a user like that is generally discouraged, and if I should stop doing it.

[image: Edit in question]

Comment: It's fine in a comment, but not as much in an answer. Answers are meant to contain answers, while comments are generally allowed to contain more fluff. (within reason, of course. Thanks comments without anything else tend to get flagged as no longer needed and removed)

Comment: Also a useful Q/A to read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: Although comments that only contain fluff are generally flagged and eventually removed. The only reason some fluff can remain in comments is because thanks to their second-class citizen status they are not community editable.

Comment: Keep in mind that an answer is primarily directed at the question, not the questioner. Ideally, questions and answers are useful to more people than just the one person who happened to ask the question first.

Comment: One would also wonder why someone answered with "Welcome to Stack Overflow" if the Question author has 10K reputation 3 months later, when one reads the post :)

Comment: Thanks for all of these wonderful comments; they've been super helpful and informative.

Comment: Related: [Kate Gregory at](https://corecursive.com/056-memento-mori-with-kate-gregory/) [18 min 44 secs](https://chtbl.com/track/7D91G/traffic.libsyn.com/secure/corecursive/056-Memento_Mori_with_Kate_Gregory.mp3). *"...if they say thanks, the culture of Stack Overflow is no high ... Stack Overflow is deliberately being mean. They want you to feel hurt and they want to hurt your feelings. Then there’s another whole category of things where they don’t think they’re being mean. But they’re hurting your feelings anyway."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, well, history is replete with people who broadcast irrational rants without evidence to back them up:(

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes, welcome