# How to deal with serial minor edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently came across [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17335001/nquincampoix) in the Suggested Edits queue. The user keeps making helpful suggested edits, but they all remove a "thanks in advance" comment and don't fix any of the other issues in the post, making them all [tiny, trivial edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). I've naturally come across two of them in the queue and I choose to improve the edit, but how should <2k users like this be dealt with? Should we just improve the edit each time, start rejecting and editing after a few, or should I try to reach out to the user?

A related issue is [How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314488/13376511), but I feel that the answer there doesn't fully address the issue. Filling the queue with tiny edits like these is a disservice to those who want to suggest more helpful edits, but can't because the queue is full. Additionally, I don't think that it is clear enough to those who submit suggested edits that edits should fix all addressable issues.

Comment: Also, [an answer to the linked meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288197/2821954) on their own edit summary.

Comment: Most edit suggestions are like this, only 10-20% complete. E.g, doing inconsequential formatting changes only, leaving run-on sentences, leaving missing punctuation, leaving non-capitalised sentences, leaving meta content like *"It's pretty important I get this done by tomorrow, it will help me out big time. I appreciate your help in advance."*, not fixing spelling (say, "linux"). [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33703812). [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33701892). [Sample 3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33702699).

Comment: Try to *"Skip"* through, say, 10, [edit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) (perhaps in *"Side-by-side Markdown"* view to see more of the posts' content(?). I am not sure which view shows the most content. At least it is clearer in that view what are formatting changes only).

Comment: [Sample 4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33699802): Questions reduced to statements. It may be a question (no pun intended) of form, but "Q" in "Q&A" is "question".

Comment: [Sample 5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33702356). Probably harmful (changing indentation in Python code. The OP fixed the indentation in revision 3, and it *seems* to be correct). Do they make such changes to pass the six-character limit check?

Comment: just raise the flag and move on, theres no sense in digging through this users edits at this point, a mod will when the flag is handled.

Comment: @Kevin B: It was *random sampling* of the ***[edit suggestion queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)*** at a particular point in time, not tied to any particular user.