# The "send" button in chat is super tiny

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface

I am a new user, just got the chat privilege-

[image: Tiny-img]

And I noticed that that "send" button could use some enlarging. I tried with different screen sizes, but that button remained tiny. I tried reloading (maybe just a CSS error)- nothing. I tried ignoring it, but it was kinda frustrating clicking its margin.

Is there some way to change it? I, personally, would like it more like this:

[image: BIG-img]

Note the beautiful capital 'S'. Maybe adding a little paper plane icon would improve it, too. Or maybe a curved arrow.

Comment: You can send chats without clicking the button. Just hit enter. I think I never have clicked it.

Comment: Thanks! But the button will stil be an eyesore (at least, for me)

Comment: At least it's a very tiny sore. Really, the button is quite useless. It might as well not be there. Just hit enter.

Comment: Sore you saying it's actually clickable?

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("sayit-button").style.fontSize = "xxx-large";` ;)

Comment: thanks but- where do I input that code?

Comment: Hmmm... But I like to be nice - else it's like ordering people around.

Comment: It was meant as a joke, but open the devtool (by right-clicking -> Inspect element or Ctrl-Shift-C) and paste it into the console at the bottom, then hit enter. Make sure you are in a chat when you do it.

Comment: If you are concerned about being polite, you might consider not calling the work of someone else an "eyesore". Sure, you find it it could be improved, you can express it without resorting to something like that.

Comment: backticks (\`) are for code, the "send" button is not related to code, you're *quoting* the text (using quotes `"`) is correct.

Comment: [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) may enlighten you on the "Thanks". Also, there's a lot of help about editing in the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png) and in the [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Comment: Since you took the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you should know that "...we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." SO is not a helpdesk. Contributions should be useful to future visitors also. That's why fluff like "Thanks" should not be included in posts.

Comment: See also the third item under Expected Behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: @cigien It's not an Answer. It needs to be applied every time they enter chat :) And I made the button [exceptionally huge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBqYG.png) :D

Comment: @IanCampbell Except from the last sentence, isn't that edit fine?

Comment: @Scratte Sure, but if you approve edits which are mostly fine then the editor will never realize they're making a mistake. Better to reject/reject and edit so they can see their mistake and the post gets improved.

Answer (score 13):

No, let's not make that button occupy more space.

First of all it is kind of useless as most of us just hit the enter key on the keyboard to send a message.

On top of that, that area is also home for the upload button, the fixed font button and for a lot of custom userscripts that bring their own tiny buttons:

[image]

Let's not pretend that space is for rent. We like it tiny.