# Is it acceptable to put "if you have any questions or something wasn't right just let me know" in my answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've sort of gotten into the habit of putting something like "If you have any questions, or something wasn't what you wanted, let me know! I'm open to criticism!" at the end of my answers. I did it because a lot of the questions I answer are by people new to SO, and programming in general, and I want to make sure that they feel free to ask me about things they didn't understand, or explain why something in the answer wasn't what they wanted.

And I've had varied responses to my answers, too. With some, the OP says "Thanks" in a comment, and that's it. With others, they say that this wasn't exactly what they needed, because ______. And with some, the OP accepted the answer, and then asked 3-5 more questions about it in the comments. So it's hard to tell what effect this phrase has, if any.

But now that I've read some of the Meta posts relating to "fluff", I'm starting to doubt that this is something that I should continue doing. So would this be considered:

1. "Fluff", because users probably already know that they can talk to me about my answer and its content, and because it is too chatty for Stack Overflow.
2. Acceptable, because it encourages new programmers and users to feel confident asking for clarification, or to feel free to criticize my answer.
3. "Fluff", because it is a display of lack of confidence in my own answers, which might mean that I shouldn't be answering the question in the first place. It sounds like I'm trying to get "on their good side".
4. "Fluff" because it clutters the answer, and gets in the way.

Comment: have you considered posting this as a comment under your answer?

Comment: @gnat Would that be better, though? Is it the _placement_ of the phrase, rather than the phrase itself, that's the problem?

Comment: placement in the answer is sure a problem for folks like me - I sometimes have to read through multiple answers to get to solution to my coding problem and fluff like that is very annoying. Phrase itself - if it is placed clearly outside of the answer - seems to be okay, at least for the way how I use Stack Overflow

Comment: #1 and #4 correct

Comment: #2 is sort of correct, because in a way it does open your answer for criticism and if your answer gets improved because of that criticism it's obviously a good thing. But like gnat said it's probably better to carry out the said discussion in the comments, because the comments can later be delete.d

Comment: This does not apply to you by the looks of your answers, but for other people a possible reason is that they're prematurely answering questions that are unclear and thus they are uncertain about those answers. That would also be a trigger to want to add this kind of footnote.

Comment: It's just noise and falls in the [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) category. Just imagine the opposite (which we would have to allow then too): I don't care about anything you might want to say about this. While it might be true, we wouldn't want to read it, so no sense in reading the opposite either. Maybe some general comment on the profile page like "Ready to help" or so, would signal some virtue.

Comment: "I'm open to criticism!" No need to call this out on SO, this is a default assumption. :)

Comment: I think so.  Perhaps a more self-assured statement like "Please let me know if there are any questions or comments".

Comment: Britney Spears once put "something wasn't right" in her song and just look what happened to her!

Comment: I don't know how you can possibly think it is not fluff. It is not answering the question. (I don't know how one could possibly think it could be a comment either.) [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/266284)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You should definitely ***avoid*** such phrases in your answers.

This kind of phrases give a "help-desk" kind of feeling. As if you're addressing or opening a conversation ***with the OP***. That's not what this site is trying to be. This site is intended to be a programming encyclopedia ***for everyone***.

So you need to think about the future visitors of the page. As you said, to them this will be "fluff". They want to see an answer to their problem and if it helped them they can upvote it. If it didn't they can downvote it. If they want to *"ask for clarification or add more information"* (the actual placeholder of the comments box) they can use the comments. It is not necessary to *tell* them what they can do. This is what the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) is for.

Personally I edit out such phrases when I encounter them, so as a side note, by using such phrases in your answers you also create more work for others...

Answer (score 33):

IMO you shouldn't add such text in your answers. The answer shall focus solely on providing a solution/explanation. It shall not be an invitation to a chat.

OP can always use a comment to ask for clarification. It's pretty obvious for anyone spending more than 5 minutes on the site. If you think it's necessary to "educate" new users about that, do it in a comment - not in the answer.