# Please help me understand how to improve my question

Tags: support, specific-question

The following question which I posted was closed because it is an "opinion-based".

So, I modified it to be a question about best practice according to users experience.

It is still blocked.

How can I modify it to make it a valid question.

I am really interested about the best practice in the described situation.

[To share object models between product code and qa tests code or not to share: This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797703/to-share-object-models-between-product-code-and-qa-tests-code-or-not-to-share-t)

Comment: _"I modified it to be a question about best practice according to users experience"_ Best practices are opinion based, by their definition.

Comment: So, is there no place on stack overflow to ask questions about known best practices?

Comment: Avoid using the phrase "best practice"; it is a trigger phrase for getting your question closed. Since no programmer ever wants to know the "worst practice" or even the "kinda-but-just-barely-good-enough practice", you can just omit this phrase and expect to get answers that contain reasonable advice on how to solve your specific problem.

Comment: I kind of wonder what triggered you to put the question on SO. You state in the question that you're having an internal debate about it. That's good! The outcome of that debate will dictate what you will do. Because this is an opinionated matter, it should be a team decision and that same team is perfectly capable of creating a list of pros and cons which is tuned towards the build process that is in place.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you to understand why "best practice" is (mostly) opinion if you read this: [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).  And to answer your question: No there isn't such a place on StackOverflow. (Try some other forum ...)

Comment: You know guys, one may argue that using design patterns are the hell of a best practice for solving some kind of problems. I am sure the discussions about the gang of four patterns are not banned from SO... All I wanted is to learn for other experience. Kill me if I understand what is so wrong about that...

Comment: “discussions about the gang of four patterns are not banned from SO.” - I would hope they are since discussions are not allowed since SO isn’t a discussion forum

Comment: *Not allowing me to hear about how people handle professional dilemmas and situation is at it most a very strange principle...* @dushkin That's because these are Q&A sites that (mostly) focus on questions that can have an objectively correct answer. There are a few that allow more subjectivity but even those have limits. (I suspect it is also because reputation is how users get moderation privileges.)

Comment: "Does GOF pattern X apply to this case?" would be a good question if backed up with enough details. "What is the rational behind GOF pattern X?" could also be a good question, but will be covered better in a good book on GOF patterns than we typically can on SO.  "Why should I observe GOF patterns?" simplifies down to something along the lines of "Because they're right a lot of the time. And the rest of the time they are not." That's not a very useful answer. Try to stick to specifics.

Answer (score 19):

First, the question is asking for "best practices", which is in considered "opinion based" for most intents and purposes, and thus off-topic on this site.

So no matter how you "improve it", it will continue being off-topic and would not be reopened.

If it were a how-to question ("how to deal with object-models shared between "product" code and "QA" test code?"), it would probably be still be opinion based. How to solve this kind of thing is very opinionated, and usually shop-specific. Since you do not even want to constrain the question to a specific language, the scope is much too broad.

With that out of the way, let's consider some things that I believe could be improved upon, that could come handy for future questions of yours:

#### Punny title

> To share object models between product code and qa tests code or not to share: This is the question

I get the pun, but it does no favours to the clarity of the title. Better to write a good, descriptive title that clearly communicates what you are asking. E.g. something similar to:

*Should object models be shared in "product" and "test" code?*

(The question is still opinion based, but at least it's much easier to parse)

#### Too much noise

You start the question with:

> I would be grateful to learn what is the best-practice for this situation:

> We have a debate here in our team whether we should share a common project of all object models between the product code and the QA tests code or not.

Of course you'd be grateful. You wouldn't be posting the question otherwise. Get the noise out of the way and get to the point.

It's not important that you have a "debate", or with whom. Simply **ask the question**:

*Should I share a common project of all object models between the product code and the QA tests code?*

The question then ends with these phrases:

> What are the pros and cons of this method?

Instead of posing a "yes/no" question and then convert it into a "list of pros/cons" at the end, have a single question in your post that invites more interesting answers.

E.g by rephrasing the title to *"Why should I share or not share object models between "product" and "test" code?*, we continue to have a clearer title, and we no longer need this coda.

> Thanks!

[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1426539)

> P.S. This question is of course not restricted to Java, so I added also c++ and python tags to it.

This is not a hand-written letter. If you "forgot" to add something or just have a post afterthought, just edit your post, no need to add a post-script.

#### Irrelevant tags

And please do not add multiple irrelevant post just because you think it applies to multiple languages. "Best practices" can surely change across ecosystems, so asking the same question to a C++ or Python developer can end up in multiple, incompatible answers. If you really are posting an on-topic question that does not refer to a specific language, just use [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) in the future. Browse the tag to see some examples.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed answer. 
As you wrote - even if I applied the changes you suggested, probably that the question was still be tagged as a forbidden opinon-based question.
I understand that the desire for the forum leaders are to brand the forum as professional, but although I do not have any choice but to comply with that in order to get a professional assistance, I must note that these managers are rigid at almost unbelievable levels.

Comment: It is forbidden to say "please," it is forbidden to say "Thank you," it is forbidden to express something with slightly less than severe seriousness, it is forbidden to ask for opinions of experienced proffesionals as if it was a crime. 

There is just a really almost military regime and I absorb not few downvotes and closings of questions because of that. Just as being a suspect of a crime.

Comment: I can understand a requirement of examples that the writer will try alone before he asks a question, although it is not always an feasable to the question. 
But discriminating a question about a request to learn from the experience of others, or worse - for saying "thank you" (I know that I do not discrete but was deleted from Post). 

But this is just my opinion ...

Comment: @dushkin - Having guidelines that indicate that unnecessary pose like “Thank You”, “Please Help”, and other unnecessary tag lines are unnecessary isn’t accusing you of a crime.  Just stop adding them or add them but expect someone will remove it for you. We have high standards doesn’t make SO a military regime

Comment: Part of the confusion may be that you are expecting SO to act like a forum, [when it is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums). SO is a knowledge base. [The tour even states](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that, "This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." Fellow community members editing your posts is not a critique of you and it is not akin to a military regime. You are not being persecuted for your question. The site is being curated as a knowledge base so that it is useful to all.

Comment: SO is a forum-on-rails which says it is not a forum. What SO says it is and what it is are not the same thing. If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck. I'm going to guess that you state that SO isn't a forum because you've been told that many times. But, ignoring what you've been told for a second, take a clear look at the platform you're currently participating on. Are you sure it isn't a forum?

Comment: Yes, we are sure, @Rounin. It is not a forum. So please do not use it as a forum and only post comments if you are actually addressing the post, at least on mine.

Comment: I'm going to conclude that we understand different things by the word _forum_. I'm happy to accept that insofar as you comprehend forums on the web, SO is not a forum.

Comment: @DM Maybe I really fail to understand the SO is no a forum... Maybe since my mother tongue is not English I even fail to understand what is a "Forum". What I do understand is that each question results (if being allowed) to be followed by human beings chatting with each other. Professionally of course. I am not seeking for friendship here. Only for assistance. Not allowing me to hear about how people handle professional dilemmas and situation is at it most a very strange principle of this forum (or whatever it defines itself)

Comment: "Chatting" is what we do not do, @dushkin. Comments exist to address a post. Extended conversation like this, is generally not welcome here. Since you are now "chatting" about what a forum is or is not, and not really addressing the content of my answer, which was meant to help you see what could be improved in your question, the comments are no longer necessary, and are simply a distraction that pushes unwanted notifications in my inbox

Comment: @dushkin: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: @yivi Thanks, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4):

Oft-quoted best practices:

1. Always clean up all resources before terminating your program.
2. You must join() all explicitly-created threads before terminating your program.
3. Always complete unit testing before starting system integration.

I strongly disagree with this set of 'best practices'.  So, these best practices are fluid and, some would say 'opinion-based', (I would say 'hopelessly wrong':).

So, if you want fights on SO, allow opinion-based and best-practice questions.

If you want questions and relevant, useful answers, ban them.

Comment: All three are good ideas that I generally recommend observing. And I've also recommended using a `goto` once or twice to simplify some messy code. There are no hard laws.

Comment: @user4581301 lol:)