# Does this edit improve or add something to the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I submitted an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358273/cant-install-nuget-packages).

Then, another user made another edit on top of mine (I am completely cool with that, obviously).

But I have checked the edit to see what I had missed, and I found myself with this:

[image: The edit in question]

The user in question does not have the privileges to make an edit without going through the review process, as far as I can tell, so this got approved. (As Cody pointed out, they have over 7k rep, my memory completely failed me here, so they DO have the privilege.)

Do this kind of edits really serve any purpose? Maybe I don't see the difference and there is something.

Comment: *"The user in question does not have the privileges to make an edit without going through the review process, as far as I can tell"* The user did not need to go through the review queue; they have >=2k rep and so have the [2,000 edit questions and answers Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege.

Comment: @CodyGray - Oh yeah, I don't know why I thought he had much less rep, my memory failed me there. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Yeah well, also confusing is that when *we* submit an Edit, we get a Msg that some "Trusted User(s) with 20k-Rep will have to approve the Edit" (Quote is approx, from memory...)... (=> 20,000-Rep, not 2,000-Rep, has been like that for years...)

Comment: I have been known to make an utterly trivial "improvement" to push through a good suggested edit that cleaned up a question that desperately needed the cleaning.

Comment: Related: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)* (and perhaps *[No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/)*).

Comment: Is the thanks/hi an official thing or a community opinion? @PeterMortensen I personally don't mind those, I think it makes some posts less *robotic*.

Comment: Yes, it is [*official*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), @S.Dre. There is nothing robotic about posts without salutations, greetings, etc - those are just useless noise.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Then I'll follow even if I don't agree with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72358273/revisions), the user who made the edit following yours was [janw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528014/janw), who, at the time of submitting the edit, had >7k reputation, which means he had [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), with no review necessary.

In fact, janw didn't just submit his edit after yours. As you can see in [the history of your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31849356), he chose to *improve* your edit (note "Edit", in bold, as the action taken by janw). This caused your edit to be implicitly approved (actually via a binding vote from the Community robot), and then his edit was put into place on top of yours.

Comment: Great, didn't fully understand how to tell when it was an improvement, now I get why the edit message was the same (simple edit). Thanks. I didn't saw much of a point in making a whole new edit JUST for that, but now I know.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the edit improved quality of the question. It removed personal expression of gratitude that has no place in any question. It also made it clear that the sentence pointing to "this error" means the error in the code block.

Your edit should have removed the "appreciate any help" completely. That's very obvious and completely redundant.

Comment: I see he made the right call since he improved my edit, and I see why thanks to your answer Dharman, although I thought at the beggining it was a new edit. I have been told in the past to avoid making such small new edits and that was really where I was heading with this question.