# Some comments don't get deleted automatically/immediately on flagging

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comment-flags, automatic-deletion

Some comments *like* "@username, thankyou" don't get deleted immediately on flagging them as NLN. Is it because it's "thankyou" and not "thank you"?

Can such comments be deleted automatically, at least if the one who's flagging is the user mentioned (using `@`) in the comment?

Some other comments like these are:

- "Glad to help" and "Glad I can/could help"
- "You're welcome"
- "I know this is almost two years later, but this worked great for me. Thanks."
- "welcome"
- "Fair point" (in [Hmm fair point @Lino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419765/suggested-edits-take-way-too-long-to-be-reviewed-due-to-a-change-to-the-top-bar?cb=1#comment922400_419787) on MS)
- "This clears/cleared (all) my/the doubts" and "This/it was/is helpful" (in "Thank you so much for clearing all the doubts and it was helpful")
- ["can we meet in (a) person?", "Can we (please) meet in person?", "Can you meet (me) in person(?)", "Can I meet (you) in person?" and "Can you (please) help (me) in person?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419822/should-comments-asking-people-to-meet-in-person-be-flagged-for-deletion/419823#419823)
- "(Thank you so much) I've been looking for (the) documentation on/for/of/like this/it (for/from/since the last hour) (and you fixed my/the issue in minutes/so/this less time!)" (in "Thank you so much I've been looking for documentation on this for the last hour and you fixed my issue in minutes!")
- "np. Always happy to help... when I can."

Can these be added to the auto-delete-on-flag list?

Comment: This almost reads like you're saying that *any* comment that pings a user can be automatically deleted by the user that was pinged; I don't agree with that. What should be the criteria for automatic removed here (other than the user being pinged)?

Comment: I kind of wonder why you specifically highlight ping comments. What is so special about them that they need to disappear as quickly as possible instead of in due time (read: after having been flagged a couple of times or when a moderator reviews it)?

Comment: I mean all comments that the system detects but that are slightly modified, like without spaces etc.

Comment: It's regex-based, so it doesn't take a lot to break it. Doesn't really matter though, I churn through those comments regularly and independently of flags, because the system doesn't help us even slightly with reducing noise

Comment: That being said, adding "thankyou" to the list seems like a worthwhile thing to do in this mobile phone driven world we live in.

Comment: I mean, if a comment is directed at me with an @, and i've read it, i'm uniquely in a position to indicate i've read it and reacted to it by 1 vote deleting it with a NLN

Comment: I would much more prefer to give mods tools to automatically bulk delete many of them.

Comment: How about something like `'thank(?!.{10})'`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel We leave it up to the site designers to come up with fixes, we just moan about what is wrong :) But still many thaanks.

Comment: I thought a numbered list would be better as you can refer to them easily.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder since you are the OP, if you like the ordered list more stylistically, I won't object. I based the edit on both the order being irrelevant in the case of providing examples and your comment that you wanted to add a "bulleted" (commonly meaning "unordered" list). I think an unordered one fits better here, but won't insist :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, this looks like another bug. I edited the revision edit again to edit the 'edit summary', but it apparently didn't save the changes. I'd changed the 'Ctrl + U' into 'Ctrl + O' and 'bulleted' into 'numbered' while editing, LOL. I'll leave it like this, I guess. This looks good too, and better as I don't think they'd be referred to anytime.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder huh, so it does not consider type switch as an edit? Odd, haven't encountered this before.

Comment: There are various [other variations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it/385424#comment903966_385424), incl. the result of gross carelessness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been fixed in production. The regex pattern matching has been updated to be less sensitive to white space and allow for usernames in flagging thank you comments.

Comment: I don't think this is working.  Here are a few short "thanks" comments that have not been one-flag deleted: "Thanks so much!" "That worked for me. Thanks for this answer." "Fantastic answer! Thanks" "Thanks! This was helpful :)" "works like a charm. Thanks!" "Thanks, It helps me." "This Works for me too! Thanks :)" "This worked!! Thanks so much" "thanks @Ahmed :)" "Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted." "this worked. Thanks a lot!" "This is awesome. Thanks @Akis" "Thanks, that's elegant" "Thanks a lot for help" "Thanks for the answer." "Many Thanks. It worked." "Great! Thanks a lot!!!"

Comment: @RyanM While catching all those would be fantastic, the change seems to only be for usernames and semi-arbitrary whitespace. It's working as intended the way  the regex is designed. Until we get some automatic and arguably more aggressive blocks and warnings for thanks comments, they're probably not going to be handled automatically

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I believe many of these would have previously been caught, in particular the extremely short ones like "Thanks so much!".  We have had a dramatic and noticeable increase in NLN flags requiring moderator handling right after this change.

Comment: @RyanM Ah, I see. Carry on. Mod powers have clearly spoiled me :p

Comment: @RyanM I updated the regex  to capture any short comment that includes "thank", which should cover the edge cases mentioned.