# Suggested edits take way too long to be reviewed due to a 2017 change to the top bar. Let's revert it

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, suggested-edits, top-bar

Prior to 2017, the top bar [used to show a count of pending suggested edits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia0Gk.png) to 2k+ users. Then, the top bar was completely redesigned to remove any numbers related to reviewing, and instead only show an occasional alert dot.

According to [data analysis performed at the time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349125/2157772), the removal of this count definitely had an impact on the time it took for suggested edits to get reviewed: prior to that, it was **extremely rare** for the number of pending suggested edits to grow to 100+ ([most of the time it was a single-digit number](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/2157772)). However, despite this, the team refused to revert the change at the time, instead applying some band-aid fixes to try and stem the problem: the number of required approve or reject votes for suggested edits was reduced from 3 to 2 and the queue size was increased from 200 to 500.

However, while these fixes did work for a time, the problem has come to a head yet again. Routinely we find that edits take very long to get reviewed, much longer than the time they took prior to the top bar change, and that the suggested edit queue is full, depriving most of the community of being able to participate in the site by editing and being able to fix issues in posts that may not be noticed by 2k+ users.

I remember suggesting edits here back in 2013-2014 and I *never* came across a full edit queue, and **that's *despite* the queue size being only 200 and that *three* approvals or rejections were required to review an edit**. I was also a prolific edit suggester on Meta Stack Exchange at the time the top bar change was rolled out, and I *distinctly* remember that before the change it took *minutes* for my edits to be reviewed, but after the change it [took many hours](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6546594#6546594). (The new top bar rolled out there a lot later than it did here.)

The top bar redesign has also caused other issues, such as users [not being able to earn badges for editing and answering questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250777/377214) simply because their suggested edit to the question wasn't reviewed in time for it to count for the badge, or because they were simply unable to suggest the edit at the time of posting the answer because the edit queue was full at the time. Per that post, **three quarters of all cases** where users missed out on having an edit count toward this badge family because their edit wasn't approved in time **occurred after the change to the top bar** (and also after the change to require only two approvals instead of three).

In my view, the best way to resolve these issues is to undo the change made back in 2017, and reinstate the count of pending suggested edits in the top bar.

Comment: *"...the removal of this count definitely had an impact..."* Well, probably. Definitely probably. Without putting too much thought into it, I think I'd rather have a single reject vote meet the threshold, rather than risking more bad reviewers "noticing" and "helping" by approving everything.

Comment: @CodyGray In which case one can also revert the change to reduce the required number of approvals by one. Arguably, edits under the old threshold took *less* time to be approved/rejected than under the new one due to other confounding factors.

Comment: A potentially larger problem is that people are frequently unable to suggest edits at all due to the queue being perpetually full.

Comment: Another alternative solution would be to try to reduce the number of bad suggested edits.  My not-fully-thought-out solution there would be to make it easier to hit the suggested-edit ban for suggesting edits that get rejected, and make "Improve edit" neutral with respect to the edit ban rather than good.

Comment: @RyanM I've long been an advocate for also reinstating the old "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox in the Improve form (was removed once the R&E button was introduced), which would allow the reviewer to edit the suggestion but the editor would not receive credit or reputation. This was not perfect (it would count neutrally, not negatively, toward the suggester), but definitely served a purpose that still exists today

Comment: It must be particularly bad right now. [Recent meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419743/the-edit-queue-is-full-what-can-we-do-with-it) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381132/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-edited-post-to-be-reviewed-faster) (both from yesterday).

Comment: I took five more for the team. Two were ***formatting changes only***, leaving all other problems untouched (rejected. And one was even incomplete in the formatting change), one drastic code change (rejected), one incomplete (approved and edited), and one was tag only (approved, as there was nothing more to do).

Comment: I waded through suggested edits once again, and unfortunately, it is exactly as I remembered. I want to reject most of them. Come to think of it, suggested edits is a walking contradiction. Its incentives are such that the least experienced users who can't write a good post are most attracted to it, yet we posit said users can somehow _improve upon a pre-existing post without conflicting with the author's intent_. How often does that happen other than fixing typos/formatting?

Comment: @PasserBy: "fix typos and formatting" other than tags, that's mostly what I do with edits, so that's what I expect suggested edits to look like.

Comment: @Joshua But we actively discourage those for suggested edits because someone has to review them.

Comment: Perhaps one of our elected moderators could go through the queues and start banning users who propose useless code block edits and trivial backtick "improvements".

Comment: Perhaps the threshold for edit privileges could be reduced for people that consistently suggest edits that get approved. Like if a user has only 1k rep, but they establish a track record of approved edits, then they could be allowed to directly edit without waiting for 2k rep. This would reduce the size of the queue.

Comment: @SurpriseDog: Now you are talking! However, it may not work if they are ***only*** after reputation points. Imagine the meta posts: Question: *"I don't earn reputation points from suggested edits anymore!"*. Answer: *"You should just have lowered the quality of your contributions!"*. But it could work if there was a ***reputation points bonus***: a fraction or all of the remaining reputation points that could be have been earned this way otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps the sun will rise in the morning, @IanCampbell. And then people will come to Meta and complain about it.

Comment: @IanCampbell I do those, because I'm trying to participate in burns. Often a question only needs a quick tidy up of the title, some code block editing and removing/replacing the tag in question. Should I be punished/ignored for submitting those kinds of edits?

Comment: Hot take: queue privledges should be based on flagging. 
Currently, I have 737 flagged posts on SO. Of those posts, _three_ of those flags have been declined. I know what is and isn't allowed on SO. So if the queue rep requirement was lowered a bit if you have a large number of helpful flags (and a decent amont of flags), that could help. Even lowering it to 400 if you've been good at flagging could attract a decent amount of reviewers. IDK how many, but I'd like review queue privledge threasholds to be lowered for lots of helpful flagging.

Comment: @cocomac I'm not sure how the privilege to review suggested edits should be based upon a user's flagging history. Also, there's already an incentive to have high helpful flags: you get more flags to use per day.

Comment: another approach to tame this issue would be to enhance question list pages with some special indicators shown to 2K+ users to mark questions where it or its answers has pending edit lacking a single vote to complete. Similar feature, along with reasoning in its favor, was suggested a while ago for close/reopen votes and 3K users at MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375956/165773). "I would suggest to address this from a bit different angle, namely - make it easier for users engaged in other ways help curators..."

Comment: @IanCampbell In my opinion, adding backticks and proper code block formatting does a lot to improve a post's readability. I've certainly "suggested" a good few edits like that, along with spelling/grammar fixes, and had them accepted.

Comment: @AJM I should have clarified that by code block changes I mean changing indentation code block formatting to three backtick formatting.

Comment: @PasserBy "yet we posit said users can somehow improve upon a pre-existing post without conflicting with the author's intent" and all that was because people ignores the help center. I was astonished that SE even when it knows it didn't shut that noise down.

Comment: *"In my view, the best way to resolve these issues is to undo the change made back in 2017, and reinstate the count of pending suggested edits in the top bar"* - if you assume nothing has changed since then, sure. But a lot has changed. It is not a matter of reverting changes from half a decade ago, it is about finding what works in 2022. And I think the well of ideas has run a little dry there since at this point you'd have to be able to wave a magic wand to clone good reviewers. There is kind of a shortage of both brains and their attached hands.

Comment: @GrahamReynolds: Users without edit privilege (which I assume because you are commenting on a post about suggested edit reviews) should not be participating in burns; doing so increases the work that trusted users have to do.  Breaking that rule implies some (insignificant, but still negative) punishment is warranted.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "I took five more for the team." Also took the self test. 1. reject and edit (edit would not have been useful, other edit was needed instead) on not very useful answer suggested by 11rep user, 2. approve (capitalization change only) on answer which borderlines a comment suggested by 21rep user 3. improve edit (useful tag removal of wrongly used tag, ignored other issues) on very confusing question suggested by 45rep user 4. audit (passed it and voted to close the question used for the audit as unclear) 5. improve edit (ignored other issues) on code heavy answer by 500rep usr ..

Comment: @PeterMortensen 6. approve and leave closed (the edit only improves language, content of closed question is not improved by it) on a low quality, closed question suggested by 11rep user -- My summary: People suggesting edits go mostly for cosmetics and propose them mostly on low quality content. Reviewing that is not fun. Displaying a number in the GUI likely won't change that. Another solution is needed. There might be some useful edits hidden though in the same way that there might be useful questions asked sometimes.

Comment: @Makyen I flagged this to add the review tag a while back, but it was declined. Can you please investigate why that happened?

Comment: @gparyani I didn't handle the flag, so can't tell you the actual reason the flag was declined. However, you flagged it the day after you posted it. At that time, the number of up/down-votes was a bit mixed, with somewhere between 5 to 7 downvotes, depending on when, exactly, the votes came in. Unless it's something urgent, I'd suggest waiting somewhat longer, or having an overwhelming positive response, prior to flagging to have [meta-tag:status-review] added. It being your own question may have contributed to the mod thinking you might be a bit biased as to when that tag should be added.

Comment: @SurpriseDog I've made a feature request with _some_ semblance to what you proposed: ["_For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383823/997587).

Comment: @starball  Now we will see if SO actually listens

Comment: The review system has just gone more and more broken over the years and SO's solution is to add _even more_ review queues. This is the result over the quantity over quality mindset over the past 8 years. The review-causer/reviewer ratio is completely haywire. What the users should do about it is: let it rot. Stop doing reviews entirely. It's a problem caused by the company, causing their product to lose value year after year. If they are interested in a solution, then _they_ have to show some initiative in dealing with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am marking this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) as we are not going to be able to address it at the current time. Reverting to the previous functionality is not something that we can do so simply as it would require a good deal of additional changes to the top bar.

That said, we are discussing internally different potential approaches for this and other issues with the top bar, and these concerns will be included in that discussion. So while there is not going to be an immediate resolution here, we do hope to be able to address it in the future.

Comment: I don't necessarily think that this proposed change/reversion would solve any problems relating to the suggested edit queue, so I'm not upset you aren't doing it, but I'm intrigued by the claim that you cannot do this (display the number of pending suggested edits) because "it would require a good deal of additional changes to the top bar". Why would adding a count to the top bar require such massive changes? That strikes me as odd. You already show plenty of user- and situation-specific counts on the top bar, like the inbox, achievements, etc. Why are pending suggested edits any different?

Comment: To put it quite frankly, any other fix that gets implemented will simply be another band-aid fix, just like the reduction of reviews required from 3 to 2 or the increase in queue size from 200 to 500. No matter what other band-aid fix gets implemented, it will eventually come to a head once more. It is very important that the actual root cause gets addressed, even if it means that priorities have to be diverted to get the development team to spend their full effort on making the required changes to the top bar to fix the root cause.

Comment: @CodyGray the technical aspects of adding it back to the top bar are not insurmountable. The bigger issue is space and info architecture. We have so many things there (making it hard to use even on a wide screen, and on narrow screens it is not good at all), we are making an effort not to just add more things to it if we can help it, before we are able to potentially address its usability as a whole.

Comment: Not to mention: there may be other items that could be "fixed" by giving them more prominence, but we want to be deliberate about prioritizing items based on their overall importance, and on the effect more exposure would have. This is not to say that SE isn't important. It is. But at this point, as we are trying to address it on a more macro-level, we are not going to be making this change on its own.

Comment: Additionally, just because this worked in the past for getting exposure to SE doesn't mean it is the best solution _today_ to achieve the same. There might be other ways of bringing different review queues to users' collective attention (or to the attention of users who might be the most likely to act on them) that do not involve (or are not restricted to) the top bar. Again - this is not something that is going to be achieved in the short term. Just trying to give more depth into why we are not going to "just revert the change" on this right now.

Comment: "*So while there is not going to be an immediate resolution here, we do hope to be able to address it in the future.*" Isn't that what [status-deferred] is for?

Comment: I use [status-deferred] when I can say for sure "we are going to do this, but it is going to be later". The best I can say about this is that we are going to be visiting the topic, but I dont know how the solution will manifest itself, so this request itself is declined, and I am giving the context here.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, @YaakovEllis. They are more clear and thoughtful than the impression given by your answer. (And have the unmistakable virtue of being things which I completely agree with. :-D) Would you consider editing them into your answer? I'm happy to remove my comment after you do so (or you can remove it yourself).

Comment: As far as tagging goes, there is another tag [meta-tag:status-planned] which is used for the case where something is definitely approved for implementation but the timing is unknown. But as far as the application of [meta-tag:status-declined] here, I think that's correct since [meta-tag:status-deferred] implies the suggestion has merit, which you say it doesn't since it would require fundamental changes to the top bar. (Changes which I firmly believe should be absolute first priority for the developers to complete.)

Answer (score 30):

As a user with some experience on other sites with 2k+ rep, I find this "suggested edits queue full" quite annoying, and just results in the user deciding to not edit at all until achieving the 2k+ rep, which in my opinion just downplays the overall quality of posts (leaving them to be edited by higher rep users). So in the end you have fewer users in total to make improvements to posts, especially posts by new users.

> However, despite this, the team refused to revert the change at the time, instead opting to reduce the number of required approve or reject votes for suggested edits from 3 to 2 and increase the queue size to 500 from 200

This has its advantages, but yes I agree with this reverting. A single red dot occasionally appearing to me does not seem very "urgent", a number representation is **a lot** better. Especially with SO being an extremely high-traffic site and many new users streaming in with answers that aren't up to standard, we need to maximise how efficient we can review them, especially suggested edits.

Problems with the current editing system:

- Suggested edit queue is full half the time, leaving users unable to edit and deciding not to edit much until they have 2k+ rep, where they are free to edit as they please.
- Fewer reviewers: I am not exactly sure of the cause of this problem, but it may due to the removal of the number and replacing it with a red dot. This might also be due to the **[incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/393786)** where many users left causing fewer reviewers to be present (unlikely).
- More people coming to Meta SO, [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and complaining about the full suggested edits queue.

Possible solutions:

- Revert the change for SO
- Reduce the number of required reject votes to 1 ([suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419765/suggested-edits-take-way-too-long-to-be-reviewed-due-to-a-change-to-the-top-bar/419787#comment922090_419765) by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)), as most users who want to spam the queue by clicking "Looks OK" all the time don't usually spam click "Reject edit", as the moderators may find a unnatural trend in rejection of edits. The number of required accept votes can remain at 2.

However at the moment, we have to wait and see how the situation unfolds.

Comment: Personally, I'm not in favor of only requiring a single reject vote because of how rejected suggested edits feed into the automated ban system, and I wouldn't want a griefing user to go through a user's activity and reject all a user's pending edits. My personal choice is to require three approvals and two rejections to review an edit, as well as reinstating the old "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox in the Improve form.

Comment: That sort of malicious behavior could be easily handled by moderators, far more easily than the current problem where bad edits waste everyone's time and far too often get approved when they should be rejected.

Comment: Agreed with reject votes, sometimes reviewer reject suggested edit. But then OP approve bad edits. WCYD

Comment: The cause of fewer reviewers mostly coincides with the [**incident**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/393786), where many people striked and / or left the network completely

Comment: @Lino but the incident wasn't that recent so it might not be the cause

Comment: @DialFrost It might have not been the initial cause. But it is the current reality. We may not be in this situation today if it didn't happen.

Comment: Another possible "solution" (mitigation?) that I wrote a feature-request on MSE: ["_For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383823/997587).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that prior to the change, *three* reviews were required to review an edit, not two.

Answer (score 2):

I came here by chance and was looking to see if someone had asked about this topic before me and I'm glad someone brought up a discussion of this topic.

Unfortunately, I suffered a lot before I reached 2K reputations because of this message **"Suggested edit queue is full"**,  maybe I'm new here or I missed the above-mentioned old top bar, but as I see from the image, this is not the only the reason, by looking at something else there are a lot of members who reached more than 2k reputation, but they are not interested in reviewing these edits, either because of other the study/work, etc., daily commitments or any other reasons.

And this topic brings us back to this discussion
**[Why don't you continue to gain 2 rep for edits once you've reached 2k rep?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268479/why-dont-you-continue-to-gain-2-rep-for-edits-once-youve-reached-2k-rep)**

Therefore, I would like to suggest the idea of ​​rewarding the members who review the edits with a gain of 1 reputation for each edit or a certain number of reputations that the moderator or staff can decide (eg. if every member has daily 40 reviews they can gain till 40 reputations per day for completing all reviews). this will encourage them to complete all pending edits reviews

We all have commitments, so if the reviewers give the community (e.g. from 30 minutes to 60 minutes per day for review edits)
it will be a fair reward to respect their time and effort in editing

Of course, reviewing edits will still not be mandatory for members depending on if the members are available and free, it is just a small idea and a suggestion and I would love to hear more from some of the more experienced people here than me.

Comment: The reason that I do not review many edits is not because I don't get rep for it, it is because of the large number of minor edits that ignore other obvious problems with a post. If I see suggested edits in the questions I'm looking at anyway, I'll be more likely to improve, if necessary, and approve/reject the suggested edits. Added rep is not going to entice me to review more.

Comment: We don't want more reviews to happen. We want more **good** reviews to happen. We have plenty of people clicking "Looks okay" without reading anything.

Comment: @beaker This is just a suggestion to encourage more users to review, of course, there are some other exceptions that make them not interested in this process at all

Comment: @heretic-monkey 
What if I personally **" read all reviews/edits carefully "** you can't generalize!

Comment: I didn't say anything about you. Whenever an incentive is offered for something, it bring more people in. It emphasizes quantity, not quality. If there was an incentive for doing good reviews, I'd be all for it, but I don't think there can be an incentive for that since we can't tell (without human intervention, which won't scale to a site of this size), whether a review completed successfully because enough people took the requisite amount of time to actually do the review, or just clicked through to get past the review. Add points to the mix and people will have more reason to click through.

Comment: The incentive needs to be more sophisticated. We don't need more users who ***only*** do it for reputation points, for the absolute ***[minimum amount of work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChQK8j6so8&list=RD_ChQK8j6so8)*** (the likely reason for the average very incomplete edit suggestions).

Comment: @DrMido One of the reasons that we have so many low-quality edit suggestions is precisely because users get a reputation bonus for doing so. I fear that a reputation bonus would similarly attract lower-quality reviews. If I were confident that a good number (I know, arbitrary and subjective) of suggested edits did not require someone else to go back and fix the remaining problems with the post, I would be far more likely to spend time in the review queue.

Comment: Just remove the 2 reputation for an accepted suggested edit. This would at least clear this queue. But on the other hand it would then just flood the other queues, because we would probably get an influx of bad answers now.