# Should comments asking people to 'meet in person' be flagged for deletion?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags

I recently saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934091/attributeerror-tkinter-tkapp-object-has-no-attribute-text-in-tkinter#comment102285263_57934438):

> can we meet in a person?

I guess the author of the comment means 'Can we meet in person?'.

Should such comments asking people to 'meet in person' be automatically deleted?

I don't think anyone would *mutually* discuss about meeting *in person on SO*. I mean, they can discuss such things elsewhere, like exchange socials and discuss these there, but not on SO.

Also, I don't see any sign of anyone agreeing to meet in person in the posts/comments either.

Comment: Yes, you should flag these comments so that they can be deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes, I guess I had flagged it, but IIRC, as NLN (I didn't realize there are other options, sorry :P).

Comment: NLN is an appropriate choice for these types of comments, unless they're actually attacking/harassing someone.

Comment: " like exchange socials and discuss these there" - except that this would be an even worse thing to do on Stack Overflow where nothing is private :)

Comment: "was never needed" is a special case of "no longer needed", hmm? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can flag them as "It's no longer needed". It's noise, that could devolve into chit-chat and discussions on whether or not the user wants to meetup and how. Comments are meant for clarifying the posted question or answer. That's it.

If a user wants to contact some other user for a meetup, they can visit that user's profile and check if that user mentioned any preferred ways of being contacted, and ask for a meetup that way. If a user doesn't list any contact information there, you can assume they aren't interested in being contacted off-site. Please respect that. Remember that Stack Overflow isn't designed as a social platform, so there is no place for this kind of comments.